# Working of indexes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, primary-key

I have a couple of questions regarding working of indexes in PostgreSQL.
I have a `Friends` table with the following index:

```
   Friends ( user_id1 ,user_id2)
```

`user_id1` and `user_id2` are foreign keys to `user` table

1. Are these equivalent? If not then why?

   ```
   Index(user_id1,user_id2) and Index(user_id2,user_id1)
   ```
2. If I create Primary Key(user_id1,user_id2), does it automatically create indexes for it and

   If the indexes in the first question are not equivalent, then which index is created on above primary key command?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

This answer is about (default) **B-tree** indexes. See this later, related answer about GiST, GIN etc.:

- [Why is a GiST index used for filtering on non-leading column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270814/why-is-a-gist-index-used-for-filtering-on-non-leading-column/270818#270818)

---

Here are the results of querying a table on the **second column of a multicolumn index**.
The effects are easy to reproduce for anybody. Try it at home.

I tested with PostgreSQL **9.0.5** on Debian using a medium sized table of a real-life database with 23322 rows. It implements the n:m relationship between the tables `adr` (address) and `att` (attribute), but that's not relevant here. Simplified schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE adratt (
  adratt_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, adr_id    integer NOT NULL
, att_id    integer NOT NULL
, log_up    timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT (now()::timestamp)
, CONSTRAINT adratt_uni UNIQUE (adr_id, att_id)
);
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint effectively implements a unique index. I repeated the test with a plain index to be sure and got identical results as expected.

```
CREATE INDEX adratt_idx ON adratt(adr_id, att_id);
```

The table is clustered on the `adratt_uni` index and before the test I ran:

```
CLUSTER adratt;
ANALYZE adratt;
```

Sequential scans for queries on `(adr_id, att_id)` are as fast as they can possibly be. The multicolumn index can still be used for a query condition on the second index column alone.

I ran the queries a couple of times to populate the cache and the picked the best of ten runs to get comparable results.

### 1. Query using both columns

```
SELECT *
FROM   adratt
WHERE  att_id = 90
AND    adr_id = 10;
```

```
 adratt_id | adr_id | att_id |       log_up
-----------+--------+--------+---------------------
       123 |     10 |     90 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
(1 row)
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Index Scan using adratt_uni on adratt  (cost=0.00..3.48 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.022..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: ((adr_id = 10) AND (att_id = 90))
Total runtime: 0.067 ms
```

### 2. Query using first column

```
SELECT * FROM adratt WHERE adr_id = 10;
```

```
 adratt_id | adr_id | att_id |       log_up
-----------+--------+--------+---------------------
       126 |     10 |     10 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
       125 |     10 |     13 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
      4711 |     10 |     21 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
     29322 |     10 |     22 | 2011-06-06 15:50:38
     29321 |     10 |     30 | 2011-06-06 15:47:17
       124 |     10 |     62 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
     21913 |     10 |     78 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
       123 |     10 |     90 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
     28352 |     10 |    106 | 2010-11-22 12:37:50
(9 rows)
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Index Scan using adratt_uni on adratt  (cost=0.00..8.23 rows=9 width=20) (actual time=0.007..0.023 rows=9 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (adr_id = 10)
Total runtime: 0.058 ms
```

### 3. Query using second column

```
SELECT * FROM adratt WHERE att_id = 90;
```

```
 adratt_id | adr_id | att_id |       log_up
-----------+--------+--------+---------------------
       123 |     10 |     90 | 2008-07-29 09:35:54
       180 |     39 |     90 | 2008-08-29 15:46:07
...
(83 rows)
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Index Scan using adratt_uni on adratt  (cost=0.00..818.51 rows=83 width=20) (actual time=0.014..0.694 rows=83 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (att_id = 90)
Total runtime: 0.849 ms
```

### 4. Disable indexscan & bitmapscan

```
SET enable_indexscan = off;
SELECT * FROM adratt WHERE att_id = 90;
```

Output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on adratt  (cost=779.94..854.74 rows=83 width=20) (actual time=0.558..0.743 rows=83 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (att_id = 90)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on adratt_uni  (cost=0.00..779.86 rows=83 width=0) (actual time=0.544..0.544 rows=83 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (att_id = 90)
Total runtime: 0.894 ms
```

```
SET enable_bitmapscan = off;
SELECT * FROM adratt WHERE att_id = 90;
```

Output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
Seq Scan on adratt  (cost=0.00..1323.10 rows=83 width=20) (actual time=0.009..2.429 rows=83 loops=1)
  Filter: (att_id = 90)
Total runtime: 2.680 ms
```

### Conclusion

As expected, the multi-column index is used for a query on the second column alone.
As expected, it is less efficient, but the query is still **3x faster** than without the index.
After disabling index scans, the query planner chooses a bitmap heap scan, which performs almost as fast. Only after disabling that, too, it falls back to a sequential scan.

See [other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6426/3684) for the original quote from the manual.

#### Updates since Postgres 9.0

Everything still basically true in Postgres 13. Most notable changes:

- [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) in Postgres 9.2
- True [covering indexes with the `INCLUDE` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html) in Postgres 11
- [Multiple performance and space improvements (especially for multicolumn indexes)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.8.5.3.3) in Postgres 12
- [Deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION) in Postgres 13.

All in favor of index performance. (Sequential scans got faster, too, though.)

Comment: clustering *will* make a difference if the number of matches in the index is high enough (see [here](https://gist.github.com/1333757) for proof - note the double runs to get the data cached)

Comment: @JackDouglas: I have given this some more thought. Clustering *may* help generally, because it is effectively also a `vacuum full` and a `reindex`. Other than that it will help index scans on the first or both leading columns *a lot*, but **hurt** queries on the second column. In a freshly clustered table, rows with the same value in the second column are spread out, so that a maximum of blocks will have to be read.

Answer (score 33):

re 1) Yes and no.

For a query that uses both columns e.g. `where (user_id1, user_id2) = (1,2)` it doesn't matter which index is created.

For a query that has a condition on only one of the columns e.g. `where user_id1 = 1` it does matter because usually only the "leading" columns can be used for a comparison by the optimizer. So `where user_id1 = 1` would be able to use the index (user_id1, user_id2) but it would not be able to an index (user_id2, user_id1) for all cases.

After playing around with this (after Erwin so kindly showed us a setup where it works), it seems that this depends highly on the data distribution of the second column although I haven't yet found out which situation enables the optimizer to use trailing columns for a WHERE condition.

Oracle 11 which can also (sometimes) use columns that are not at the beginning of the index definition.

re 2) Yes it will create an index

[Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2493)

> Adding a primary key will automatically create a unique btree index on the column or group of columns used in the primary key.

re 2a) `Primary Key (user_id1,user_id2)` will create an index on (user_id1,user_id2) (which you can find out by yourself *very* easily by simply creating such a primary key)

I highly recommend that you read the [chapter about indexes in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes.html), it basically answers all the questions above.

Additionally, [What index to create?](https://www.depesz.com/2011/09/28/what-index-to-create/) by depesz does a good job explaining order on index columns and other index related topics.

Answer (score 13):

Ad 1)
There are limitations in PostgreSQL [like @a_horse_with_no_name describes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6116/3684). Up until [version 8.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) multicolumn indexes could only be used for queries on the leading column(s). This has been improved in version 8.1. The [current manual for Postgres 14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) (updated) explains:

> A multicolumn B-tree index can be used with query conditions that
> involve any subset of the index's columns, but the index is most
> efficient when there are constraints on the leading (leftmost)
> columns. The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading
> columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does
> not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of
> the index that is scanned. Constraints on columns to the right of
> these columns are checked in the index, so they save visits to the
> table proper, but they do not reduce the portion of the index that has
> to be scanned. For example, given an index on `(a, b, c)` and a query
> condition `WHERE a = 5 AND b >= 42 AND c < 77`, the index would have
> to be scanned from the first entry with `a` = 5 and `b` = 42 up
> through the last entry with `a` = 5. Index entries with `c` >= 77
> would be skipped, but they'd still have to be scanned through. **This
> index could in principle be used for queries that have constraints on
> `b` and/or `c` with no constraint on `a`** — but the entire index
> would have to be scanned, so in most cases the planner would prefer a
> sequential table scan over using the index.

Emphasis mine. I can confirm that from experience.
Also see the test case added [my later answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7484/3684).

Answer (score 12):

This is in reply to [Jack's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7500/3684), a comment wouldn't do.

There were **no covering indexes in PostgreSQL** before version 9.2. Due to the MVCC model, every tuple in the result set has to be visited to check visibility. You may be be thinking of Oracle.

PostgreSQL developers talk about **"index-only scans"**. In fact, the feature has been released with Postgres 9.2. [Read the commit message](https://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-committers/2011-10/msg00039.php).
Depesz wrote a [very informative Blog post](https://www.depesz.com/2011/10/08/waiting-for-9-2-index-only-scans/).

**True covering indexes** (update) are introduced with the `INCLUDE` clause with Postgres 11. Related:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)

This is a bit off, too:

> it relies on the fact that a 'full scan' of an index is often quicker
> than a 'full scan' of the indexed table due to the extra columns in
> the table that don't appear in the index.

As reported in comments on my other answer I have also run tests with a table of two integers and nothing else. The index holds the same columns as the table. The size of a btree index is around 2/3 that of the table. Not enough to explain a speedup of factor 3. I ran more test, based on your setup, simplified to two columns and with a 100000 rows. On my PostgreSQL 9.0 installation the results were consistent.

*If* the table has additional columns, the speedup with index becomes more substantial, but **that is certainly not the only factor here**.

### Summary

- Multi-column indexes can be used for selective criteria with queries on non-leading columns, but the speedup is only a low factor depending on table and index tuple size and visibility. Higher for wider rows, lower for larger portions of the table in the result set.
- Create an additional index with those columns first if performance is important.
- If all involved columns are included in an index (covering index) and all involved rows (per block) are visible to all transactions, you can get an ["index-only scan"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) in Postgres 9.2 or later.

Comment: Three separate answers on one question. That's a first for me haha. Very helpful info though!

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Are these equivalent? If not then why?
>
>    Index(user_id1,user_id2) and Index(user_id2,user_id1)

These are not equivalent and generally speaking index(bar,baz) will not be efficient for queries of the form `select * from foo where baz=?`

Erwin [has demonstrated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484) that such indexes can indeed speed up a query but this effect is limited and not of the same order as you generally expect an index to improve a lookup - it relies on the fact that a 'full scan' of an index is often quicker than a 'full scan' of the indexed table due to the extra columns in the table that don't appear in the index.

**Summary: indexes can help queries even on non-leading columns, but in one of two secondary and relatively minor ways and not in the dramatic way you normally expect an index to help due to it's btree structure**

<sub>nb the two ways the index can help are if a full scan of the index is significantly cheaper than a full scan of the table and either:
  1. the table lookups are cheap (because there are few of them or they are clustered), <s>or
  2. the index is [covering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)#Covering_Index) so there are no table lookups at all</s> oops, see Erwins comments [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7541#7541)</sub>

testbed:

```
create table foo(bar integer not null, baz integer not null, qux text not null);

insert into foo(bar, baz, qux)
select random()*100, random()*100, 'some random text '||g from generate_series(1,10000) g;
```

query 1 (no index, hitting **74 buffers**):

```
explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select max(qux) from foo where baz=0;
                                                  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=181.41..181.42 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=3.301..3.302 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: max(qux)
   Buffers: shared hit=74
   ->  Seq Scan on stack.foo  (cost=0.00..181.30 rows=43 width=32) (actual time=0.043..3.228 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: bar, baz, qux
         Filter: (foo.baz = 0)
         Buffers: shared hit=74
 Total runtime: 3.335 ms
```

query 2 (with index - the optimizer ignores the index - hitting **74 buffers** again):

```
create index bar_baz on foo(bar, baz);

explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select max(qux) from foo where baz=0;
                                                  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=199.12..199.13 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=3.277..3.277 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: max(qux)
   Buffers: shared hit=74
   ->  Seq Scan on stack.foo  (cost=0.00..199.00 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.043..3.210 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: bar, baz, qux
         Filter: (foo.baz = 0)
         Buffers: shared hit=74
 Total runtime: 3.311 ms
```

query 2 (with index - and we trick the optimizer to use it):

```
explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select max(qux) from foo where bar>-1000 and baz=0;
                                                       QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=115.56..115.57 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=1.495..1.495 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: max(qux)
   Buffers: shared hit=36 read=30
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stack.foo  (cost=73.59..115.52 rows=17 width=32) (actual time=1.370..1.428 rows=52 loops=1)
         Output: bar, baz, qux
         Recheck Cond: ((foo.bar > (-1000)) AND (foo.baz = 0))
         Buffers: shared hit=36 read=30
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bar_baz  (cost=0.00..73.58 rows=17 width=0) (actual time=1.356..1.356 rows=52 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((foo.bar > (-1000)) AND (foo.baz = 0))
               Buffers: shared read=30
 Total runtime: 1.535 ms
```

So access via the index is twice as fast in this case hitting **30 buffers** - which in terms of indexing is 'slightly faster'!, and YMMV depending on the relative size of table and index, along with the number of filtered rows and clustering characteristics of the data in the table

By contrast, queries on the leading column make use of the btree structure of the index - in this case hitting **2 buffers**:

```
explain (buffers, analyze, verbose) select max(qux) from foo where bar=0;
                                                       QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=75.70..75.71 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.172..0.173 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: max(qux)
   Buffers: shared hit=38
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stack.foo  (cost=4.64..75.57 rows=50 width=32) (actual time=0.036..0.097 rows=59 loops=1)
         Output: bar, baz, qux
         Recheck Cond: (foo.bar = 0)
         Buffers: shared hit=38
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on bar_baz  (cost=0.00..4.63 rows=50 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=59 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (foo.bar = 0)
               Buffers: shared hit=2
 Total runtime: 0.209 ms
```