# Slow index scans in large table

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

Update 2020-08-04:

Since this answer is apparently still being viewed regularly I wanted to provide an update on the situation. We're currently using PG 11 with table partitioning on `timestamp` and are easily handling a few billion rows in the table(s). The index-only scans are a life saver and it wouldn't be possible without.

---

Using PostgreSQL 9.2, I have troubles with slow queries on a relatively large table (200+ million rows). I'm not trying anything crazy, just adding historic values. Below is the query and the query plan output.

My table layout:

```
                                   Table "public.energy_energyentry"
  Column   |           Type           |                            Modifiers
-----------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  | not null default nextval('energy_energyentry_id_seq'::regclass)
 prop_id   | integer                  | not null
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone | not null
 value     | double precision         | not null
Indexes:
    "energy_energyentry_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "energy_energyentry_prop_id" btree (prop_id)
    "energy_energyentry_prop_id_timestamp_idx" btree (prop_id, "timestamp")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "energy_energyentry_prop_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (prop_id) REFERENCES gateway_peripheralproperty(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

The data ranges from 2012-01-01 till now, with new data constantly being added. There are about 2.2k distinct values in the `prop_id` foreign key, distributed evenly.

I notice that the row estimates aren't far off, but the cost estimates seem larger by factor 4x. This probably isn't an issue, but is there anything I could do about it?

I expect that disk access might be the issue, since the table isn't in memory all the time.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT SUM("value") 
FROM "energy_energyentry" 
WHERE 
  "prop_id"=82411 
  AND "timestamp">'2014-06-11' 
  AND "timestamp"<'2014-11-11'
;
```

> ```
>  Aggregate  (cost=214481.45..214481.46 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=51504.814..51504.814 rows=1 loops=1)
>    ->  Index Scan using energy_energyentry_prop_id_timestamp_idx on  energy_energyentry (cost=0.00..214434.08 rows=18947 width=8) (actual time=136.030..51488.321 rows=13578 loops=1)
>          Index Cond: ((prop_id = 82411) AND ("timestamp" > '2014-06-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND ("timestamp" < '2014-11-11 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
>  Total runtime: 51504.841 ms
> ```

Any suggestions how to make this faster?
I'm also fine with just hearing I didn't do anything weird.

Comment: Please tell us what your table looks like, what indexes it has and the spread of data.

Comment: I added the additional informatie you asked. Dunno whether I missed anything.

Comment: Strange: Your explain analyze shows `prop_time_idx`, yet the table definition shows `entry_prop_id_timestamp_idx`. Is this the same index? Please fix.

Comment: If you refer by 'the cost estimates seem to be a factor 4x larger' to the fact that the _cost_ numbers are about 4 times those of the _actual time_, then please notice that the two has nothing to do with each other. The cost is only an estimate, helping the query optimizer to choose the best looking plan.  Outside of this context, it is usually a meaningless value.

Comment: How many percent of the table does your date range represent (without taking into consideration the values for `prop`)? If just a small percentage, maybe an index on `("timestamp", prop)` would be better. Multiple indexes with the same leading column(s) (`prop` in your case) is also often redundant.

Comment: Finally: if you are often querying only for one particular value of `prop`, you could create a partial index. But I suspect this is a generic query.

Comment: This is indeed a generic query, every value of "prop_id" is about as likely to be queried. The date range has a uniform amount of data for each time slice, about 1 entry per 15 minutes. So I expect that handling indexing on "timestamp" first will lead to an increase of about 2200x in data (the amount of properties), which I doubt will speedup the query.

Comment: I also copied my query plan again from the actual query. I ran it through an internal explain-analyze tool which changed some of the values...

Comment: We do often query for a specific amount of time, like an entire month. But I don't know if you can create a partial index for that?

Comment: A partial index is one created with a `where` clause: it needs to match exactly the where clause being used in the query for the index to be considered. The classic use case for this is an index on a status column in a queue-like table where only a few records are active.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your table is *big*, and so is any index spanning the whole table. Assuming that:

- only new data (with `timestamp = now()`) is entered
- existing rows are neither changed nor deleted.
- you have data since 2012-01-01 but queries are predominantly on the current year (?)

I would suggest a [partial, multi-column (covering!) index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX ON energy_energyentry (prop_id, "timestamp", value)
WHERE "timestamp" >= '2014-01-01 0:0';  -- adapt to your needs
```

In Postgres 11 or later use a "covering" index instead:

```
CREATE INDEX ON energy_energyentry (prop_id, "timestamp") INCLUDE (value)
WHERE "timestamp" >= '2014-01-01 0:0';
```

See:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns/190151#190151)

Only include the time range that is queried regularly. Only makes sense if you cut off most of the big table this way. Effectiveness deteriorates over time with new entries. Recreate the index from time to time. (You may need to adapt your queries.) See linked answer below.

The last column value is only included to get [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) out of this. Aggressive autovacuum setting may help by keeping the visibility map up to date, [like @jjanes already mentioned](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81498/3684).

The partial index should fit into RAM more easily and stay there longer.

You may need to include this `WHERE` condition in queries to make the planner understand the index is applicable to the query, like:

```
SELECT sum(value) AS sum_value
FROM   energy_energyentry
WHERE  prop_id = 82411 
AND   "timestamp" > '2014-06-11 0:0' 
AND   "timestamp" < '2014-11-11 0:0'
AND   "timestamp" >= '2014-01-01 0:0'; -- seems redundant, but may be needed
```

Since your query is summing a lot of rows (`rows=13578`), this is going to take some time, even with an index-only scan. It shouldn't be anywhere near 50 seconds, though. Less than a second on any halfway decent hardware.

Related <sub>(but ignore `CLUSTER` and `FILLFACTOR`, both are irrelevant if you can get index-only scans out of this)</sub>:

- [Index optimization with dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/postgresql-index-optimization-with-dates/27929#27929)

*Aside:*
Since you *currently* have an index on `(prop_id, "timestamp")`, the additional index on just `(prop_id)` may cost more than it's worth:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Comment: Now that Postgres supports BRIN indexes, would that be useful here? I plan on storing about 140 million rows on data on postgres, is BRIN the right index to use for table that large?

Comment: @Arya: How to tell whether the table is right for a BRIN index: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/312327/3684

Answer (score 6):

If you make the index on  (prop_id, "timestamp","value"), then it could use an index-only scan to compute the value without ever visiting the table.  This could save a lot of random disk access.

To get the most benefit, you need to be aggressive about vacuuming the table.  The default autovac settings are not aggressive enough for insert-only tables on which you wish to efficiently support index-only scans.

Comment: Adding the value might be interesting indeed, I'll take a look whether that'll speed things up. Do you have any suggestions for vacuum settings or documentation I can look at?