# How to use index to speed up sorting in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, postgresql-performance, sorting

I have a table `messages` in a Postgres 9.4 database. Messages belong to `feed_id`, and have `posted_at`. Also, messages can have a parent message (in case of replies).

```
                    Table "public.messages"
            Column            |            Type             | Modifiers
------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 message_id                   | character varying(255)      | not null
 feed_id                      | integer                     |
 parent_id                    | character varying(255)      |
 posted_at                    | timestamp without time zone |
 share_count                  | integer                     |
Indexes:
 "messages_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (message_id)
 "index_messages_on_feed_id_posted_at" btree (feed_id, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST)
```

I want to return all messages ordered by `share_count`, but for each `parent_id`, I only want to return one message. ie, if multiple messages have the same `parent_id`, then only the latest one (`posted_at`) is returned. The `parent_id` can be null, messages with null `parent_id` should all return.

The query I used is:

```
WITH filtered_messages AS (SELECT * 
                           FROM messages
                           WHERE feed_id IN (7) 
                           AND (posted_at >= '2015-01-01 04:00:00.000000') 
                           AND (posted_at < '2015-04-28 04:00:00.000000'))
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON(COALESCE(parent_id, message_id)) parent_id,
                      message_id, 
                      posted_at, 
                      share_count
      FROM filtered_messages
      ORDER BY COALESCE(parent_id, message_id), posted_at DESC NULLS LAST
     ) messages
ORDER BY share_count DESC NULLS LAST, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/588e5/1/0) with schema, exact query, and expected result.

The performance of the query is slow once the `messages` table gets big. I tried add multiple sorting indexes, but it does not seem to use the index.

Here's the [`EXPLAIN` output](http://explain.depesz.com/s/Sv2).

How can I create a correct index?

Comment: At a first glance, the `ORDER BY` in the subquery is totally useless.  Furthermore, the linked plan cannot be a result of the posted query - there is no mention of `metadata`, for example.

Comment: Your description does not cover the role of `feed_id` and `posted_at` and you did not mention `metadata` at all, which seems to be a JSON type? Please repair your question to make it consistent. You select > 500k rows in the CTE ... How many rows are in the table? What percentage of rows do you typically select in the CTE? What percentage of rows has `parent_id IS NULL`? Consider the info in the [\[postgresql-performance\]](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) tag for performance questions.

Comment: Also important: How many rows for each `parent_id`? (min / avg / max)

Comment: sorry, I was trying to make the question more clear by reducing some of the columns, share_count was actually in hstore `metadata`. Currently the messages table has 10 mil data, but increasing fast. I am think to separate into partition tables for each feed_id. Since I am only fetching per feed id. the percentage of parent_id null vs not null is about 60% / 40%. a typical fetch is around 1-2% of the table. ( around 100K messages) The performance for 100K is around 1s, but once gets to 500K+ it uses bitmap index and normally takes 10s.

Answer (score 14):

#### Query

This query should be substantially faster in any case:

```
SELECT parent_id, message_id, posted_at, share_count
FROM   messages
WHERE  feed_id = 7
AND    posted_at >= '2015-01-01 4:0:0'
AND    posted_at <  '2015-04-28 4:0:0'
AND    parent_id IS NULL  -- match index condition
UNION ALL
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON(parent_id)
       parent_id, message_id, posted_at, share_count
FROM   messages
WHERE  feed_id = 7
AND    posted_at >= '2015-01-01 4:0:0'
AND    posted_at <  '2015-04-28 4:0:0'
AND    parent_id IS NOT NULL  -- match index condition
ORDER  BY parent_id, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST
)
ORDER  BY share_count DESC NULLS LAST, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST;
```

The CTE does nothing here that a plain subquery could not deliver also. And a CTE introduces an optimization barrier since it is executed separately and its result is materialized.
Update: that changes in Postgres 12. See:

- [How to prevent PostgreSQL from rewriting OUTER JOIN queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131384/how-to-prevent-postgresql-from-rewriting-outer-join-queries/131436#131436)

You had one more subquery-level than you actually need.

The expression `(COALESCE(parent_id, message_id)` is not compatible with a plain index. You would need an index on that *expression*. But that may not be very useful either, depending on data distribution. See links below.

Splitting the simple case of `parent_id IS NULL` into a separate `SELECT` may or may not deliver the optimum. Especially not, if that's a rare case anyway, in which case a combined query with an index on `(COALESCE(parent_id, message_id)` may perform better. Other considerations apply ...

#### Indices

Especially when supported with these indices:

```
CREATE INDEX messages_idx_null ON messages (feed_id, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST, share_count DESC NULLS LAST)
INCLUDE (parent_id, message_id)
WHERE parent_id IS NULL;

CREATE INDEX messages_idx_notnull ON messages (feed_id, posted_at DESC NULLS LAST, share_count DESC NULLS LAST)
INCLUDE (parent_id, message_id)
WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```

The two partial indices cover the whole table *together* and are about the same size together as a single total index.

[Covering indexes (with the `INCLUDE` clause)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) were added with Postgres 11. See:

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns/190151#190151)

The `INCLUDE` part only make sense if you get [index-only scans](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81554/3684) out of it. Else remove it from both indices.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d4adc3f1815ae9ce31b7baefd64d3ef)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/823d78/1)</sub>

Depending on missing details, `DISTINCT ON` may or may not be the best query technique for the purpose. Details here:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Possibly faster alternatives here:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Comment: So far, for PostgreSQL, my understanding is that the only clauses that will trigger the index being used are `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `JOIN` query clauses (helpful [article](https://pganalyze.com/blog/how-postgres-chooses-index)). Does that sound right?

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Basically, yes. But there are additional use cases. Like, for a full count. Or a small selection of columns from a covering index in an index-only scan. Or checking FK costraints for any writes ...

Comment: Thanks. 1) Full count - do you have a link to more info? couldn't find anything on this. 2) Covering index - so in this case, an index could just be used from a bare `SELECT`. And 3) FK constraints - it seems all RDBMSs using SQL should auto-create indices for FKs so that shouldn't be something a dev has to actually worry about then.

Comment: @Akaisteph7: 1) Try `SELECT count(*) FROM tbl;` on any big table with a small PK index and its visibility map up to date (recently vacuumed). 2) Yes. 3) Postgres requires that the target of a FK constraint has a PK or UNIQUE constraint, so the target is always indexed. Indexing the source is up to the user, and I had plenty of cases where I didn't need an index on the source column. 4) Please ask any additional questions as *question*. Comments are not the place.