# How to prevent PostgreSQL from rewriting OUTER JOIN queries?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, explain, join

My query is:

```
SELECT  Acol1, Acol2, Bcol1, Bcol2, Ccol1, Ccol2
FROM    tableA LEFT JOIN
            (tableB FULL JOIN tableC ON (Bcol1 = Ccol1))
            ON (Acol1 = Bcol1)
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` gives me:

```
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Right Join  (cost=99.65..180.45 rows=1770 width=24) (actual time=0.043..0.103 rows=3 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (tableb.bcol1 = tablea.acol1)
   ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=49.83..104.08 rows=1770 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.062 rows=3 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (tableb.bcol1 = tablec.ccol1)
         ->  Seq Scan on tableb  (cost=0.00..27.70 rows=1770 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=27.70..27.70 rows=1770 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=3 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
               ->  Seq Scan on tablec  (cost=0.00..27.70 rows=1770 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=27.70..27.70 rows=1770 width=8) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=3 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1kB
         ->  Seq Scan on tablea  (cost=0.00..27.70 rows=1770 width=8) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=3 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 0.151 ms
```

Postgres changed the ***full*** outerjoin between `tableB` and `tableC` to a ***right*** outerjoin, since later the left outerjoin with `tableA` will eliminate null values anyway. It is equivalent to the original query.

However, I am hacking Postgres to implement my join enumeration related algorithm and to do experiments. I do not want Postgres to change the full outerjoin to a left outerjoin. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 5):

You can introduce **optimization barriers** for your purpose.

#### Preface

Plain `EXPLAIN` (without `ANALYZE`) is enough for the purpose of this question. Parentheses around the `ON` expression are just noise. Adding table aliases to be unambiguous.

We do see **"Full Join"** for the full join by itself:

```
SELECT * FROM tableB b FULL JOIN tableC c ON b.Bcol1 = c.Ccol1;
```

We could rewrite the full join with a subquery:

```
SELECT a.Acol1, a.Acol2, d.Bcol1, d.Bcol2, d.Ccol1, d.Ccol2
FROM   tableA a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT *  -- sort out conflicting names with aliases
   FROM   tableB b FULL JOIN tableC c ON b.Bcol1 = c.Ccol1
   ) d ON a.Acol1 = d.Bcol1;
```

You have to sort out conflicting names with aliases in the subquery - but then again, you would need to do this in any case in the outer `SELECT` for multiple columns of the same name in the underlying tables.

The query is still optimized as a whole since subqueries do not impose optimization barriers. You'll still see a **"Left Join"** or **"Right Join"**. However, we can expand on this form to arrive at a solution:

#### Solution 1. `OFFSET 0` hack (undocumented)

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT a.Acol1, a.Acol2, d.Bcol1, d.Bcol2, d.Ccol1, d.Ccol2
FROM   tableA a
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT *  -- you'll have to sort out conflicting names with aliases
   FROM   tableB b FULL JOIN tableC c ON b.Bcol1 = c.Ccol1
   OFFSET 0  -- undocumented hack
   ) d ON a.Acol1 = d.Bcol1;
```

You'll see a **"Full Join"**.

**Why?** As soon as a subquery uses an `OFFSET` clause, the query planner / optimiser plans the subquery separately. `OFFSET 0` is logical noise, but Postgres still considers the clause which makes this a query hint to materialize the subquery, effectively. (Even though Postgres does not otherwise support query hints.) It's a much debated issue. Related:

- [How can I prevent Postgres from inlining a subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14897816/939860)
- http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

#### Solution 2. Use a CTE (documented)

```
EXPLAIN
WITH cte AS MATERIALIZED ( -- requires "MATERIALIZED" in Postgres 12 or later!
   SELECT *  -- you'll have to sort out conflicting names with aliases
   FROM   tableB b FULL JOIN tableC c ON b.Bcol1 = c.Ccol1
   ) 
SELECT a.Acol1, a.Acol2, d.Bcol1, d.Bcol2, d.Ccol1, d.Ccol2
FROM   tableA a
LEFT   JOIN cte d ON a.Acol1 = d.Bcol1;
```

You'll see a **"Full Join"** as well.

[The manual for Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-with.html) (before `AS MATERIALIZED` was added):

> A useful property of `WITH` queries is that they are evaluated only once
> per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more
> than once by the parent query or sibling `WITH` queries. Thus, expensive
> calculations that are needed in multiple places can be placed within a
> WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible application is to
> prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions with side-effects.
> However, the other side of this coin is that the optimizer is less
> able to push restrictions from the parent query down into a WITH query
> than an ordinary subquery. **The `WITH` query will generally be evaluated
> as written, without suppression of rows that the parent query might
> discard afterwards.** (But, as mentioned above, evaluation might stop
> early if the reference(s) to the query demand only a limited number of rows.)

Since **Postgres 12**, [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#id-1.5.6.12.7) adds:

> However, if a `WITH` query is non-recursive and side-effect-free (that
> is, it is a `SELECT` containing no volatile functions) then it can be
> folded into the parent query, allowing joint optimization of the two
> query levels. By default, this happens if the parent query references
> the `WITH` query just once, but not if it references the `WITH` query
> more than once. You can override that decision by specifying
> **`MATERIALIZED`** to force separate calculation of the `WITH` query, or by specifying **`NOT MATERIALIZED`** to force it to be merged into
> the parent query. The latter choice risks duplicate computation of the
> `WITH` query, but it can still give a net savings if each usage of the
> `WITH` query needs only a small part of the `WITH` query's full
> output.

Bold emphasis mine.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=192038185fc318f1758ecc16502e21ce)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8276b8/1)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing the code

```
SELECT  Acol1, Acol2, K.D.Bcol1, K.D.Bcol2, K.D.Ccol1, K.D.Ccol2  
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN  
( SELECT  D.Bcol1, D.Bcol2, D.Ccol1, D.Ccol2  
  FROM (tableB FULL JOIN   
 tableC ON  
Bcol1 = Ccol1 ) D ) K  
ON Acol1 = K.D.Bcol1
```

I'm using K.D. to indicate the data flow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I get the following error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "d"
LINE 8: ON Acol1 = K.D.Bcol1;