# Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, index-tuning

This is a follow-up to: [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns)

Consider the inverse of the schema in the other question where you filter in the joined-on table:

```
CREATE TABLE thing_types(
   id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
 , first_lvl_type  TEXT
 , second_lvl_type TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE things(
   id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
 , thing_type INTEGER REFERENCES thing_types(id)
 , t1c1       INTEGER
);
```

And a query like so:

```
SELECT things.t1c1
FROM   things
JOIN   thing_types ON things.thing_type = thing_types.id
WHERE  thing_types.first_lvl_type = 'Book'
AND    thing_types.second_lvl_type = 'Biography';
```

Is it madness to have an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON thing_types(first_lvl_type, second_lvl_type, id);
```

which covers the primary key for use in that join? Will the index be used as a covering index to help the `JOIN` in the above query? Should I change my indexing strategy to cover the primary key more often when I know the table is going to be `JOIN`ed on like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If additional preconditions for an **index-only scan** are met, it makes perfect sense to append the column `id` as trailing column to the index (not as leading column):

```
CREATE INDEX ON thing_types(first_lvl_type, second_lvl_type, id);
```

Postgres 11 introduces actual [covering indexes with the `INCLUDE` keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6).

```
CREATE INDEX ON thing_types(first_lvl_type, second_lvl_type) INCLUDE (id);
```

Only a small benefit for your case, but it's a great option to add columns to a UNIQUE or PK index or constraint.

About index-only scans:

- [The Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)
- [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

The most important precondition: The visibility map of table `thing_types` has to show most or all pages as "visible" to all transactions. I.e. the table is either read-only, or your autovacuum settings are aggressive enough to continuously clean up after writes to the table.

Every additional index adds costs. Mostly to write performance. But also side effects, like exhausted cache capacities. (Multiple queries using the same indexes have a better chance for them to reside in cache.) So it's also a question of *size*. `id` is typically a very small column `integer` or `bigint`. Makes it a good candidate for the use case.

In particular, adding a column to an index disables the option for H.O.T. updates involving the column. But since `id` is indexed anyway and typically not updated (being the PK) this is not a problem in this case. Related:

- [Redundant data in update statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806610/939860)

If you actually get index-only scans out of these indexes most of the time, it typically makes sense to use them. Test with [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

There were limitations for **partial indexes** in older versions. [Quoting the release notes of Postgres **9.6**:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6)

> - Allow use of an [**index-only scan**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/indexes-index-only-scans.html) on a partial index when the index's `WHERE` clause references columns that are not indexed (Tomas
>     Vondra, Kyotaro Horiguchi)
>
>   For example, an index defined by `CREATE INDEX tidx_partial ON t(b) WHERE a > 0` can now be used for an index-only scan by a query that
>     specifies `WHERE a > 0` and does not otherwise use `a`. Previously
>     this was disallowed because a is not listed as an index column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try it and see for your specific query plan. You're making a lot of blanket assumptions about the advice given and even the potential for it to be useful to your query.

- Size.
- PostgreSQL major number
- Configuration for costs.
- Staleness and accuracy of statistics.

All of those things matter.

Not to be vague here, but I could conjure a few examples to show you this.

Generally, I wouldn't index something that is already indexed in the table. If for no other reason than because for every time an index covers a specific column, you have one more index that has to be updated when you change the row.