# Return values at more/less specific time points

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-10, nearest-neighbor

In PostgreSQL 10.0, I have a big table with two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE xs (
  ts timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  x integer NOT NULL
)
```

Now, if I have 100 given time points, how do I return exactly 100 `x`-es that are right before (`<=`) these time points (**for each of those points**)?

For just a single one this would be very easy:

```
SELECT x FROM xs WHERE ts <= '2018-03-13 11:41:47.167973+00' LIMIT 1
```

But how to do this efficiently for a 100? Something like:

```
SELECT x FROM xs 
  WHERE ts FIRST_LESS_THAN_EQUAL_IN
    ('2018-03-13 11:41:47.167973+00', 
     '2018-03-13 11:41:47.198564+00', 
     '2018-03-13 11:41:47.555668+00',
      ...
     '2018-03-13 11:41:57.766888+00')
```

Obviously, there is an index on `ts`.

Comment: Do you have any unique constraints on the table?  Also, your query for a single value doesn't have `order by`, so it can return any x where `ts` is less or equal to given, not the right before.

Comment: Oops, sorry about no `ORDER BY`! `ts` is not unique, but the I can select an arbitrary value (`x`s for the same `ts` will be the same or very close).

Comment: Just remember that repeated calls may return different values if the result is not deterministic. Might cause confusion. So the safe approach is to make it deterministic to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a `LATERAL` subquery, best with a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to preserve all input rows (displaying a NULL value in case there should be *no* match at all):

```
SELECT v.reference_ts, t.most_recent_x
FROM  (
   VALUES
      (timestamptz '2018-03-13 11:41:47.167973+00') -- type cast in first row
    , ('2018-03-13 11:41:47.198564+00') 
    , ('2018-03-13 11:41:47.555668+00')
    , ('2018-03-13 11:41:57.766888+00')
   ) AS v(reference_ts)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT x AS most_recent_x
   FROM   xs
   WHERE  ts <= v.reference_ts  -- ts is unique (?!); see below
   ORDER  BY ts DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) AS t ON true;
```

A `VALUES` expression is *one* way to put your 100 timestamps into a derived table we can work with. The free-standing `VALUES` expression may require an explicit type cast in the first row. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

There are others ways to pass your values, like an array (or an array literal cast to `timestamptz[]`) and `unnest()` in the query:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539#91539)

About the `LATERAL` subquery:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Don't forget the `ORDER BY` or you get arbitrary results - [like @a1ex07 commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/200105/return-values-at-more-less-specific-time-points#comment390913_200105).

If `ts` is not unique, it's undefined which of the duplicates is returned, unless you add more `ORDER BY` items to make it deterministic. Like: `ORDER BY ts DESC, x DESC` to get the row with the biggest `x` from any set of peers. And make the index match.

An index on `(ts)` (like you mentioned) works wonders on performance.
Or, ideally, on `(ts DESC, x)` if preconditions for index-only scans are met.

- [Does PostgreSQL use an index-only scan in this JOIN?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/does-postgresql-use-an-index-only-scan-in-this-join/190158#190158)

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b722af4bb2f5a80be2508e7840f48284)*

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought this would be inefficient, but `EXPLAIN` says it’s not! Wonderful!