# Merge 2 columns and replace with specific output

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.4

The setup is a Debian 8 with Postgres 9.4 (64bit if that matters).

Given following table I want to "search" for a combination of columns `first` and column `sub` and replace their output with another string.

```
CREATE TABLE public.rawdata (
 first integer,
 sub character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
 value integer
)
```

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO rawdata VALUES
  ('1','A','5994'),('1','B','28525'),('1','C','18577'),
  ('2','A','30522'),('2','B','5238'),('2','C','18268'),
  ('3','A','982'),('3','B','13401'),('3','C','24158'),
  ('4','A','8544'),('4','B','31575'),('4','C','16661'),
  ('5','A','600'),('5','B','5242'),('5','C','8740'),
  ('6','A','2557'),('6','B','69'),('6','C','31572'),
  ('7','A','4212'),('7','B','26269'),('7','C','27918'),
  ('8','A','29821'),('8','B','22603'),('8','C','32578'),
  ('9','A','8027'),('9','B','13668'),('9','C','32000'),
  ('10','A','17673'),('10','B','11723'),('10','C','8937');
```

For example, the two column '1' and 'A' should read in the output as 'cat'.

There should be no alteration of the source data.

I have read about using `WITH` for that but I am uncertain how to join the columns so that I can convert '(1, A)' to 'cat' and '(2, A)' to 'dog'.

I only need the output where I have a defined "replacement name".

The end-result should look like that:

```
Name Value
Cat 5994
Dog 30522
```

Sadly, I am limited to providing the output that way (if possible at all).
Normally, I would write something like:

```
select * from rawdata where first < 3

1   "A" 5994
1   "B" 28525
1   "C" 18577
2   "A" 30522
2   "B" 5238
2   "C" 18268
```

But the next step is something I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a translation table, let's call it `sub1_dict`:

```
CREATE TABLE sub1_dict (
   first int NOT NULL
 , sub   varchar NOT NULL
 , name  text NOT NULL -- find a better name than "name"
 , CONSTRAINT t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (first, sub) -- INCLUDE (name) -- see below
   );
```

Enter all defined translations in this table.

Since you specified:

> I only need the output where I have a defined "replacement name"

... use an `[INNER] JOIN` in the query, excluding rows without translation:

```
SELECT s.name, r.value
FROM   rawdata r
JOIN   sub1_dict d USING (first, sub)
WHERE  r.first < 3;
```

The added PK should serve your purpose. The `INCLUDE` clause requires Postgres **11**. The intention is to allow fast index-only scans - not important with small tables.

Same for your table `rawdata`: if it's big, add an index on `(first, sub)`. Or a PK or `UNIQUE` constraint. Column `first` first to also serve your `WHERE` clause optimally. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

If you get index-only scans out of it, consider another covering index like above, with `INCLUDE (name)` in Postgres 11 or later.

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables/190158#190158)

Comment: looks good, works as intended, once again thank you for your service.
ill accept tomorrow unless there will be a better answer for whatever reason

Comment: @DennisNolte: I added some more to address performance.