# Improve Performance on GROUP BY - large table PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a Postgres table containing the following three columns:

- origin (INT, b tree index)
- destination (INT, b tree index)
- minutes (SMALLINT, b tree index)

The table has ~ 1.4 billion rows. Each row contains the information about the travel time (minutes) from one place (origin) to another (destination).

The table is read-only - we might need to change it, but that will happen once a year or so...

I need to do queries like:

```
SELECT min(minutes) 
FROM table 
WHERE origin IN([long list]) 
AND destination IN([long list]) 
GROUP BY origin
```

The performance is really bad. Depending on the number of origins and destinations, the query takes more than 10 minutes. What we need is < 3 minutes, ideally < 10 sec. DBMS is postgreSQL 9.4, 16 G RAM.

Is there a way to improve it? Partitioning the table, optimizing indexes etc.? Or another DBMS?

Edited 2018-11-28:

- Added Index on (origin, destination)

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT min(minutes),origin FROM table WHERE destination = ANY('{100225471, 100236548, 10263073, 10827564, 7435519, 100272388, 10688802, 10823750, 10853634, 10681223, 100213867, 100234761, 100113775, 100229234, 100234067, 100235418, 100229220, 1000053957, 1000059198, 1000028857, 1000057809, 1000058848, 1000059188, 1000057802}') GROUP BY(origin)
```

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=228043.99..228044.04 rows=5 width=6) (actual time=10118.146..10126.308 rows=50022 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: origin"
"  ->  Index Scan using idx_destination on table  (cost=0.60..226716.69 rows=265460 width=6) (actual time=0.022..10021.269 rows=208174 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (destination = ANY ('{100225471,100236548,10263073,10827564,7435519,100272388,10688802,10823750,10853634,10681223,100213867,100234761,100113775,100229234,100234067,100235418,100229220,1000053957,1000059198,1000028857,1000057809,1000058848,1000 (...)"
"Planning time: 0.306 ms"
"Execution time: 10127.949 ms"
```

Comment: Please consider reading [how to ask performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Did you try a composite index on `(origin, destination)`?

Comment: Do you have the chance to upgrade to Postgres 11? The ability to use parallel query execution might improve this (assuming your server has enough CPUs)

Comment: Try to use `WHERE origin = ANY(ARRAY[longlist]) ...` instead of `IN`

Comment: "origin IN([long list])"  How long is long?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Now we have it ;-)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No chance to upgrade soon.

Comment: @jjanes: From 20 to 2000.

Comment: You are fine with using a different DBMS, but not with upgrading the current one?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If another DBMS would surely provide much better performance i could argument we should use it. In case it only "might" be better, it would be difficult ;-)

Comment: Postgres 11 will be faster - how much is a different question though. If the performance really is important than migrating to 11 should be the first step.

Comment: @user2059857: A *list* of values is transformed to `= ANY()` internally automatically (like can be seen in the query plan in the question). There is an *actual* alternative, though. I added an answer.

Comment: Are the values for origin and destination really independent? Or do you actually want a condition where you have a list of origin/destination _combinations_ to compare to. e.g. `where (origin, destination) in ( (1,2), (3,4), (5,6), ... )`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, they are independent. I want to get the closest (min(minutes)) facility (destination) for each place (origin). We need to query it because the considered facilities can vary.

Comment: `... get the closest (min(minutes)) facility (destination) for each place (origin).` That's not what your query does, yet. I added solutions below.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` can take a list of values (like you have it) or a ***set***. Long lists don't scale well. See:

- [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in/91539)
- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192557/939860)

Try:

```
SELECT origin, min(minutes) -- you'll also want to show origin
FROM   tbl
JOIN   unnest($origin_array) o(origin)      USING (origin)
JOIN   unnest($dest_array)   d(destination) USING (destination)
GROUP  BY origin;
```

Where `$origin_array` can be an array of the appropriate type `int[]` or an  array literal like `'{100225471,100236548,10263073}'::int[]`

The optimal **index** for this query should be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (origin, destination, minutes);
```

Appending `minutes` only makes sense if you get **index-only scans** out of it (introduced with pg 9.2, improved in later versions). But since your table is mostly read-only, it seem like the perfect use case. See:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables/190158#190158)

You later commented:

> I want to get the closest (min(minutes)) facility (destination) for each place (origin).

The above query does not achieve that. Only returns the shortest time for *any* qualifying destination. **Use instead:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (origin)
       origin, minutes, destination
FROM   tbl
JOIN   unnest($origin_array) o(origin)      USING (origin)
JOIN   unnest($dest_array)   d(destination) USING (destination)
ORDER  BY origin, minutes;
```

Depending on cardinalities and value frequencies, this alternative may be faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM   unnest($origin_array) o(origin)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT minutes, destination
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  origin = o.origin
   AND    destination = ANY ($dest_array)  -- equivalent to IN([long list]) 
   ORDER  BY minutes
   LIMIT  1
   ) t ON true;
```

One ***subtle difference***: the last query returns origins from the input array with no match in `tbl` at all. May or may not be desirable - or even necessary. ***The last query is my favorite.***

Further reading on how to optimize queries of this kind:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Plus, urgently consider upgrading to a current version of Postgres, like a_horse already suggested. Performance for big data has been improved  substantially since Postgres 9.4.

You mentioned lists of up to 2000 items. Combining two long list like that is problematic since it results in a Cartesian product of 2000 x 2000 = 4000000 possible combinations. If that can happen - sure you need to consider that many combinations? *That* won't be fast.