# How to optimize a recursive query in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, recursive

I have a recursive query that takes too long - 30+ ms where doing the individual queries to extract the same data manually takes < 0.12 ms. So we're talking 250x as long.

I have the following database structure allowing a DAG of group membership ([db-fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tDL1xnTQYKH9C2SHV5w4o8/1)):

```sql
create table subjects
(
    subject_id bigint not null
        constraint pk_subjects
            primary key
);

create table subject_group_members
(
    subject_group_id bigint not null
        constraint fk_subject_group_members_subject_group_id_subjects_subject_id
            references subjects(subject_id)
            on delete cascade,
    subject_id       bigint not null
        constraint fk_subject_group_members_subject_id_subjects_subject_id
            references subjects(subject_id)
            on delete cascade,
    constraint pk_subject_group_members
        primary key (subject_group_id, subject_id)
);

create index idx_subject_group_members_subject_id
    on subject_group_members (subject_id);

create index idx_subject_group_members_subject_group_id
    on subject_group_members (subject_group_id);
```

Data might look like this:

| subject_group_id | subject_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 5 |

I want to know all the groups that 5 is a member of (1 by inheritance, 2 & 3 directly, not 4 or any other subject ids).

This query works as expected:

```sql
with recursive flat_members(subject_group_id, subject_id) as (
      select subject_group_id, subject_id
      from subject_group_members gm
      union
      select
          flat_members.subject_group_id as subject_group_id,
          subject_group_members.subject_id as subject_id
      from subject_group_members
      join flat_members on flat_members.subject_id = subject_group_members.subject_group_id
  )
  select * from flat_members where subject_id = 5
```

But run with real data I get this query plan:

```
CTE Scan on flat_members  (cost=36759729.47..59962757.76 rows=5156229 width=16) (actual time=26.526..55.166 rows=3 loops=1)
  Filter: (subject_id = 30459)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 48984
  CTE flat_members
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..36759729.47 rows=1031245702 width=16) (actual time=0.022..47.638 rows=48987 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on subject_group_members gm  (cost=0.00..745.82 rows=48382 width=16) (actual time=0.019..4.286 rows=48382 loops=1)
          ->  Merge Join  (cost=63629.74..1613406.96 rows=103119732 width=16) (actual time=10.897..11.038 rows=320 loops=2)
                Merge Cond: (subject_group_members.subject_group_id = flat_members_1.subject_id)
                ->  Index Scan using idx_subject_group_members_subject_group_id on subject_group_members  (cost=0.29..1651.02 rows=48382 width=16) (actual time=0.009..1.987 rows=24192 loops=2)
                ->  Materialize  (cost=63629.45..66048.55 rows=483820 width=16) (actual time=4.124..6.592 rows=24668 loops=2)
                      ->  Sort  (cost=63629.45..64839.00 rows=483820 width=16) (actual time=4.120..5.034 rows=24494 loops=2)
                            Sort Key: flat_members_1.subject_id
                            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 53kB
                            ->  WorkTable Scan on flat_members flat_members_1  (cost=0.00..9676.40 rows=483820 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.916 rows=24494 loops=2)
Planning Time: 0.296 ms
Execution Time: 56.735 ms
```

Now if I do it manually, querying `select subject_group_id from subject_group_members where subject_id = 30459` and following the tree up, it's 4 queries each taking about 0.02ms.

Is there a way where I can make the recursive query approach the speed of doing the recursion manually?

Comment: I feel like the problem is that I merge join the whole lot up front, _then_ filter by the `subject_id` I actually care about. Instead of finding the two rows that actually contain my desired `subject_id`, then using their `subject_group_id` as the `subject_id` in subsequent recursions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you inverted the join condition by accident.

```
WITH RECURSIVE flat_members AS (
   SELECT subject_group_id
   FROM   subject_group_members gm
   WHERE  subject_id = 5

   UNION
   SELECT gm.subject_group_id
   FROM   flat_members          fm
   JOIN   subject_group_members gm ON gm.subject_id = fm.subject_group_id
   )
TABLE flat_members;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zz9XRedT)

Plus, move the filter `WHERE  subject_id = 5` up to the initial `SELECT` to filter irrelevant rows early - and allow for an optimized query plan, typically using an **index**. Speaking of which, this multicolumn index would serve much better, allowing index-only scans:

```
CREATE INDEX subject_group_members_subject_id_subject_group_id
    ON subject_group_members (subject_id, subject_group_id);
```

(Might as well be `UNIQUE`.) In addition to your PK on `(subject_group_id, subject_id)`. Or invert the columns in the PK definition, either might be useful.

About index-only scans:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables/190158#190158)

It's typically best to just have a PK on `(subject_id, subject_group_id)`, another multicolumn index on `(subject_group_id, subject_id)`, and drop the two indexes on only `(subject_id)` and `(subject_group_id)`. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Comment: Thanks! I assumed the PK on subject_group_members would provide that index, was I wrong?

Comment: @RobertElliot: Note the update. Wasn't all right, yet. An, no, the PK has column in the opposite order. Also added notes on that.

Comment: If you do all that, what's the new execution time? (Do you see index-only scans?)

Comment: It's massively faster, but oddly it was faster still without the additional index. Details here: https://gist.github.com/Mahoney/0482757addcd40928923fd726ae0493e

Comment: Though I may not have been as rigorous in that testing as I could have been... will try again.

Comment: I see "Heap Fetches" in your query plan. Try `VACUUM subject_group_members;` before your next test. Or even `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE subject_group_members;` if you can afford a brief exclusive lock.

Comment: Updated - yup, you're right, cheaper with the index.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this - I was in big trouble unless I could sort out this performance problem.