# Testing efficiency of a BRIN index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning

I have found many use cases in our OLAP queries for BRIN indexes, as they are much much smaller and have comparable speed in the same order of magnitude as BTREE indexes.

Typically I use BRIN indexes for monotonically (or close to that) increasing timestamp columns. In our OLTP databases they are closely placed on the disk since naturally they get sequentially written as time goes.

In our warehousing Postgres instance some parts of the tables are loaded in big batches not necessarily ordered by time.

Is there some analytical query which would tell me if the data is placed too randomly to use BRINs even if seemingly the column value distribution should follow all the prerequisites for creating a BRIN index?

Answer (score 5):

BRIN indexes only make sense for **big** tables (thousands of data pages or much more). (You already know that, just to guide the general public.) But how to tell whether rows are physically sorted enough?

[The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html#INDEXES-TYPES-BRIN) offers a hint:

> BRIN indexes (a shorthand for Block Range INdexes) store summaries
> about the values stored in consecutive physical block ranges of a
> table. Thus, they are most effective for columns whose values are
> **well-correlated** with the physical order of the table rows.

Bold emphasis mine.

[`ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) gathers a corresponding statistic stored in [`pg_statistic`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-statistic.html). Best accessed via the column `correlation` in the system view [`pg_stats`](https://pg_stats) by humans:

> `correlation` `float4`
>
> Statistical correlation between physical row ordering and logical
> ordering of the column values. This ranges from -1 to +1. When the
> value is near -1 or +1, an index scan on the column will be estimated
> to be cheaper than when it is near zero, due to reduction of random
> access to the disk. (This column is null if the column data type does
> not have a `<` operator.)

All statistics are based on a sample of rows and as such just estimates, even when up to date. You can increase validity by increasing the sample size, i.e. setting a higher "statistics target" - thereby also increasing the cost of `ANALYZE`, of course. The default [`default_statistics_target`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET) is just 100, which is OK for most purposes, but typically too low for columns of big tables with non-trivial data distribution (that are used for sorting and filtering). See:

- [Check statistics targets in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15034896/939860)

You might even increase the statistics target temporarily, run `ANALYZE`, and reset the value, to get a one-time correlation with increased validity.

So, once the table is analyzed (manually, or by `autovacuum`) inspect:

```
SELECT schemaname, tablename, attname, n_distinct, correlation
FROM   pg_stats
WHERE  schemaname = 'public'
AND    tablename  = 'tbl'
AND    attname    = 'my_index_col';
```

- A `correlation` close to **0** means a BRIN index will be useless.
- A `correlation` close to **1** (or **-1**) means a BRIN index will be excellent.

  - With a low count in [`n_distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) (relative to the total count) or a negative ratio close to 0, you might increase the setting for [`pages_per_range`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) (default 128) accordingly.
  - With a high count of `n_distinct` (relative to the total count) or a negative ratio close to -1, you might decrease the setting for `pages_per_range` accordingly.
- Everything in between is a grey area. Many factors at play. Also depends a lot on the avg row size and typical queries. In my experience, values close to 0 or to 1 / -1 are common, which makes the decision easy.

That said, if the table is not sorted enough, you might *make* it so with [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) or one of the less blocking community tools [pg_squeeze](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze) or [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack). Rewriting the whole table in sort order is expensive for big tables, and deteriorates over time if there are `UPDATE` (or `DELETE` + `INSERT`) operations. But can pay for certain use cases. See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Note that even one outlier value will wreck the minimum or maximum for a block range. So I am not sure if a `correlation` of 1 is good enough, given that these are statistical data.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Yes, important to keep in mind. I added some pointers concerning sample size and validity. With a reasonably high statistics target, a correlation of 1 (or -1) should be a good indicator, though, as it's unlikely to get a perfectly sorted sample in an otherwise unsorted table.

Comment: Why didn't you recommend or suggest that the OP try using CLUSTER after a batch update - then a BRIN index have a perfect 1 for the correlation, and for every record, not just a sample?

Comment: @Vérace: Didn't think to mention it, since it's about *testing* (and felt too obvious). But you're right, a pointer can't hurt.