# High cost in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-12

I have a table that has more than 10.000.000 records, and I'm creating a query that returns about 4436 records.

It just so happens that it gives me the impression that the query cost to get to the last record is very high.

```
Index Scan using idx_name on task  (cost=0.28..142102.57 rows=3470 width=34) (actual time=14.690..22.894 rows=4436 loops=1)
"  Index Cond: ((situation = ANY ('{0,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}'::integer[])) AND (deadline < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))"
Planning Time: 1.335 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 5
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 1.654 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.214 ms, Emission 13.163 ms, Total 16.030 ms
Execution Time: 24.758 ms
```

Is this level of cost acceptable or does this index need improvement?

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON task (situation, deadline, approved)
WHERE
deadline IS NOT NULL AND
situation <> ALL ('{4,5}'::integer[]) AND
approved = 'N';
```

My Query:

```
SELECT
        task.deadline,
        task.id
    FROM
        task
    WHERE
        task.deadline IS NOT NULL
        AND task.situation IN ('0', '1', '2', '3', '6' ,'7' ,'8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20')
        AND task.situation NOT IN ('4', '5')
        AND task.deadline < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        AND task.approved = 'N';
```

Comment: The query runs in 24 **milli**seconds - how fast  do you need that to be?

Comment: If you are running with default settings of the various cost params, that does seem rather high of an estimate for this query.  Are you using the defaults?  What is the size of both table and index?  If you freshly VACUUM ANALYZE the table, does anything change?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has asked this but can you give the DDL for the task table? From [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/better-postgresql-performance-on-ssds/): It has turned out to be very beneficial to adjust random_page_cost in postgresql.conf to a value close to 1 (instead of 4 which has been the default for many years) when running PostgreSQL on SSDs.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has asked this but can you give the DDL for the task table? From [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/better-postgresql-performance-on-ssds/): "It has turned out to be very beneficial to adjust random_page_cost in postgresql.conf to a value close to 1 (instead of 4 which has been the default for many years) when running PostgreSQL on SSDs". Finally, why have `situation <> ALL ('{4,5}'::integer[])` and not the more traditional `situation NOT IN (4, 5)`?

Comment: @Vérace  The planner rewrites `situation NOT IN (4, 5)` to be `situation <> ALL ('{4,5}'::integer[])`  so he might have just written the index WHERE to match what was showing up in the pre-index explain output.

Comment: @jjanes - it was the `CREATE INDEX` statement that I was talking about  - the planner doesn't have a role to [play there](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=21ae6e7f8fc5c80f0f79f2ed34123d83) - or does it? I've been playing around with ARRAYs in PostgreSQL recently and I've seen stuff being converted to ARRAYs by the optimiser - but why specify one in the index creation? I'm just curious!

Comment: @Vérace I too was talking about the CREATE INDEX.  I am unlike to type it's where clause from scratch, but would assemble it from text copied from my scrollback buffer. And why not copy that text from the relevant EXPLAIN output? That way i know it will match the planners expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The index is good, the query is fast.

But the index can be better and the query faster. The index column `approved` is just dead freight with the condition `approved = 'N'`. Remove it.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON task (situation, deadline)
WHERE  deadline IS NOT NULL
AND    situation <> ALL ('{4,5}'::integer[])
AND    approved = 'N';
```

Matters for index size, even if `approved` is `varchar(1)` (and probably should be `boolean` instead). Since `deadline` is an (aligned) `timestamp` (`with time zone`) type, the added index column `approved` wastes at least 8 bytes per index tuple - makes it grow by 1/3.

Better yet, if the example with `SELECT deadline, id ...` is any indication, it should pay to append `id` as "included" column to allow  [**index-only scans**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON task (situation, deadline) INCLUDE (id)
WHERE  deadline IS NOT NULL
AND    situation <> ALL ('{4,5}'::integer[])
AND    approved = 'N';
```

Requires Postgres 11 or later. Brings the size back to what it was before.

See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)
- [Slow index scans in large table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81456/slow-index-scans-in-large-table/81554#81554)

Comment: In the example I have reduced the number of columns (task.deadline, task.id), but in the real environment I have about four more columns from the task table.

In this case, do I create the index to have all these other columns or just the ID?

Comment: @Tom: That depends on the complete situation. Most importantly, it those additional columns are small and rarely updated (and the table row is much wider), it might be a good idea.

Comment: A question that may seem a little silly.
This database is almost 10 years old, that is, strange or not-so-functional indexes were created. Poorly crafted queries were also created.
Is there any good method to be able to track these poorly constructed indexes, or queries that can have improved?
As I learned today with @Laurenz-albe, even the order of columns in the index is something that affects performance. That's why I think we'll have to review all our queries and indexes.
I'm not a DBA, just a dev, so unfortunately I don't have that deep knowledge to have created everything correctly.

Comment: You say: `The index column approved is just dead freight with the condition approved = 'N'. Remove it.` - what if approved was 50% `Y` and 50% `N`? Or maybe very few are `N` (as appears to be the case - at least with the other conditions) - it would be very discriminating?

Answer (score 7):

As hinted at in a comment, you shouldn't be looking at the query cost, but rather at its actual run time (or you shouldn't be bothered by any of it at all if the run time is acceptable). The estimated plan cost is not an indication of anything except the *relative* amount of various resources Postgres estimates it might need to spend to execute this particular plan *compared to other possible plans*.

Looking at the absolute cost value tells you absolutely nothing; comparing it with other plans' costs tells you which of them Postgres thinks is more efficient, based on the information the optimizer has.

See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154780/how-reliable-is-the-cost-measurement-in-postgresql-explain-plan).

---

Looking into the [horse's mouth](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/optimizer/path/costsize.c) one might see this:

```
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * costsize.c
 *    Routines to compute (and set) relation sizes and path costs
 *
 * Path costs are measured in arbitrary units established by these basic
 * parameters:
 *
 *  seq_page_cost       Cost of a sequential page fetch
 *  random_page_cost    Cost of a non-sequential page fetch
 *  cpu_tuple_cost      Cost of typical CPU time to process a tuple
 *  cpu_index_tuple_cost  Cost of typical CPU time to process an index tuple
 *  cpu_operator_cost   Cost of CPU time to execute an operator or function
 *  parallel_tuple_cost Cost of CPU time to pass a tuple from worker to leader backend
 *  parallel_setup_cost Cost of setting up shared memory for parallelism
...
```

and [further](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample) down that path:

```
# - Planner Cost Constants -

#seq_page_cost = 1.0            # measured on an arbitrary scale
#random_page_cost = 4.0         # same scale as above
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01          # same scale as above
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005       # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025     # same scale as above
```

You'll notice that they emphasize "arbitrary units" on an "arbitrary scale"; all they want to establish is that reading N pages at random  is four times as resource-intensive ("expensive") as reading that many pages sequentially, or that evaluating a predicate against an index entry is half as expensive as doing that against a table row. When the cost of the entire plan tree is added up, you get a value that can only be compared to another tree cost; it can only be high*er* or low*er*, not high or low.

---

HT to [jjanes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34857/jjanes) for mentioning [JIT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/jit-reason.html) in a comment. The estimated query cost in your case happens to just exceed the JIT trigger threshold, which defaults to 100000, and, as jjanes astutely pointed out, "2/3 of [your query] time seems to be spent on JIT", which is probably counterproductive. You might want to evaluate if having JIT enabled in your environment is useful.

Comment: The absolute value of the cost estimate is what gets compared to the various jit_*above_cost settings, so this does give them some weak meaning on an absolute scale.  And note that 2/3 of his time seems to be spent on JIT, so the absolute value being higher than jit_above_cost is not something of no consequence.  Besides, while someone could go in and double every setting (including the JIT ones), few actually do such silly things.

Comment: @jjanes: I usually disable JIT completely. In typical OLTP environments I have never seen this improve things, but always make things slower. DWH environments might be different though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I think turning JIT on by default in v12 was a mistake, and think it still is in v14.

Answer (score 3):

Both the other answers are very good, let me add one detail:

Both of your conditions are not simple equality comparisons, so the second column in the index will only be used to filter out rows (before the table is accessed).  So the order of index columns will influence how many index entries have to be read to find the answer.

To find the best index for the query, first try with an index on `(situation, deadline)`, then drop that index and try with one on `(deadline, situation)`, and see which one of them touches fewer blocks with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but does the order that the table's columns are placed in the index affect its performance?

Comment: Yes, very much so. But in this case I am not certain which order is better.

Comment: @Tom: It depends on the number of values in the `IN` list filtering `situation`. For only a view values the current order of columns `(situation, deadline)` is typically best, as columns for *range* filter should come *after* equality filters. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33220/3684

Comment: I never knew that this column order affected the performance, I just did a test and really, there is a change in behavior.
Using the deadline at the start, the situation is used as a filter and not an index cond.

Comment: Then the original order must have been the better one.

Comment: @Tom Order of columns is fundamentally important in btree indexes. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684 Also matters for GiST indexes (in a different way). Currently unimportant for other index types. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  It will have no problem doing 19 little index scans, one for each value of situation in the in list, and stopping each one as soon as deadline goes out of range.  In my hands the cost estimate is much lower than he reports, and is just 19 times higher than if just one situation was specified with `=`.  I don't know what is going on with his estimates, but I don't think it is this.

Comment: @jjanes I don't know either. In some other comment, you hinted that something has changed with index scans and `IN` lists in v14. Do you know thich commit that was? 50e17ad28?