# PostgreSQL triggered update function lock mechanism

Tags: postgresql, trigger, locking, functions, concurrency

I'm fairly new to database administration and PostgreSQL, and there's some things I'm not familiar with, even tho I've read a lot of the PostgreSQL documentation.

Here is a simplified version of the tables in my problem :

USERS_PRODUCTS table

| user_id (PK, FK) | product_id (PK, FK) | ownership |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | owned |
| 1 | 2 | owned |
| 1 | 3 | wished |
| 2 | 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | owned |

PRODUCTS table

| id (PK) | owned_count | wished_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

On each UPDATE of USER_PRODUCT row, a function is triggered, sending an UPDATE on the corresponding PRODUCT row (+/- 1 in owned_count or wished_count column).

I was expecting the triggered functions to introduce some issues regarding concurrency when multiple users set ownership on the same product id (lost updates), but after some load testing, it appears that there's no issue, without any explicit locks.

So my problem is that **I don't understand what concurrency mechanisms are at work in order to avoid these lost updates.** It looks like magic to me and I'm not ok to push that in production without understanding it.

I didn't find anything in the documentation regarding triggered updates and lock mechanisms, all help is welcome (link to doc, facts, thoughts).

EDIT : Here is a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e3b5632d95381963353d68be6b50096b) with all the necessary data

Comment: Not an answer (because it would just be retelling the entire [concurrency control section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html) from the docs), but, generally speaking, you shouldn't store something that can be computed at runtime.

Comment: Let's say I have 100 000 users with at least 5 products owned, I would perform 500 000 rows read in order to have the counts for a product, and do that for every product I select ? That seems unoptimised. Also I've read concurrency control section and nothing is specified regarding updates inside triggered functions, using the default transaction isolation there should be aborted updates, or lost updates, but there's none when I test with heavy loads.

Comment: Is "unoptimised" your opinion, or did you measure the performance and, after tuning, still found it unacceptable? By the way, there's nothing special about "updates inside triggered functions" -- they are just regular updates.

Comment: I did test for a 100 products : doing a select with already computed counts has a cost of 0.00..5.01, and doing a select with join on the sum of counts has a cost of 286.48..291.76. Given that accessing products is the main feature of the app, I think doing it on each select is not optimised. Plus I must be able to select and order by these counts. For the update part I had a feeling that there's nothing special, in that case, shouldn't default transaction isolation (read committed) have some concurrency issues without explicit locking ? I'm thinking about lost updates

Comment: Looking at the query cost is [meaningless](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301847/high-cost-in-postgresql-query/301849#301849). Since you're not showing any code, it's impossible to say anything about the possibility of lost updates.

Comment: I've added a dbfiddle to my question, all the necessary db code is there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magic is called "row lock". The updates on the counter column are serialized by row locks, so there cannot be any race condition. A lost update can never happen if you read and write the data in a single `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thank you fot he answer, indeed after looking at pg_locks there's some RowExclusiveLock. So from what I understand that kind of lock is a table lock, but it locks only a single row based on an id just like we do when using an advisory lock ?

Comment: There must have been an additional row lock, but row locks are not stored in the lock table for very long. You could use the `pgrowlocks` extension to find out more.

Comment: When I inspect that table it’s not always there, but during a load testing (thousands of requests per second) I can see some locks every few tries. Thanks for the help I’ll take a look at that extension.