# Row with latest timestamp

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, index-tuning, query-performance

How to get the row with the latest value in a [`TIMESTAMPZ`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) column? Is an index needed? Does an index change the strategy? Would behavior vary by database (I'm using Postgres 9.4)?

My app records data from a data feed. Another process endlessly queries to get the latest freshest entry. Older data may appear on occasion from secondary sources. So the most recently inserted rows are usually, but not necessarily, the freshest data.

I am using this kind of SQL where `when_` is a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table_ 
ORDER BY when_ DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

This code works (if no NULL values in data!). But with a possible couple million rows, and a query every 10 seconds, I'm concerned about performance.

Without any index on `when_` column, does this statement require a full scan of all rows?

Does adding an index change the performance? Will Postgres automatically scan the index to locate the most recent row, or must I do something to make an index scan happen?

With an index on `when_` column, should I change this SQL to use some other approach/strategy of query?

Is there some other way to gather freshly inserted rows? I'm using [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) rather than [SERIAL types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for my primary key, and may federate data amongst multiple database instances, so that rules out checking for ever-increasing integer numbers.

Comment: `SELECT *`? Do you really need all columns from the row? Or just a small subset? The table definition would be relevant to see width of the row and constraints and types of involved columns.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The table has a few TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE fields, a couple UUID, and a couple of TEXT fields with 1K to 20K of HTML, CSV, or XML text. I don’t think the other columns are relevant to my question asking how to get the latest row based on a single timestamp column. Primary key is a UUID. There might be a triple-column UNIQUE constraint but not involving the column in question. My real SQL code selects a few of these columns. I am using `SELECT *` here to keep things simple.

Comment: I was thinking of a partial, covering index. But if your `real SQL code selects a few of these columns.` (being 1k - 20k in size) that option is out. A basic table definition is practically *always* relevant for performance questions like this. Either way, the additional info from your comment should be in the question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am purposely trying to not get specific; I'm *not* trying to solve a specific performance problem. I thought a general question about **how to find latest record in general** would be educational for me and many others.

Comment: The devil is always in the details with performance optimization. I do have general advice in the answer I am working on, too, but the best answer depends on the complete picture.

Comment: _how to find latest record in general_: the method is trivially the SELECT query you showed with a normal btree index on `_when`. If you don't try that first, you're doing premature optimization.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I went with a simple index on the `when_` column. That server had plenty of RAM and storage space, so no pressing need to conserve. Your function-as-global-constant approach is interesting and educational. Thank you for your excellent Answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Basic answers

Since you select a couple of big columns an [index-only scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) is probably ***not*** a viable option.

> This code works (if no NULL values in data!)

While the column isn't defined `NOT NULL`, add `NULLS LAST` to the sort order to make it work ***in any case***, even with `NULL` values. Ideally, use the clause in the corresponding index as well:

```
SELECT <some big columns>
FROM   my_table_ 
ORDER  BY when_ DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

> Without any index on `when_` column, does this statement require a full
>   scan of all rows?

Yes. Without index, there is no other option left. (Well, there is also [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) where an index on key columns(s) is not strictly required, and it could assist with partition pruning. But you would typically have an index on key columns there, too.)

> With an index on `when_` column, should I change this SQL to use some
>   other approach/strategy of query?

**Basically, this is the perfect query.** There are options in combination with advanced indexing:

---

#### Advanced technique

Assuming a `NOT NULL` column. Else, add `NULLS LAST` to index and queries as suggested above.

You have a constant influx of rows with later `when_`. Assuming the latest `_when` ***constantly increases*** and never (or rarely) *decreases* (latest rows deleted / updated), you can use a very small **partial index**.

**Basic implementation**:

1. Run your query once to retrieve the latest `when_`, **subtract a safe margin** (to be safe against losing the latest rows) and create an `IMMUTABLE` function based on it. Basically a "fake global constant":

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_when_cutoff()
     RETURNS timestamptz LANGUAGE sql COST 1 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
   $$SELECT timestamptz '2015-07-25 01:00+02'$$;
   ```

   `PARALLEL SAFE` only in Postgres 9.6 or later.
2. Create a partial index excluding older rows:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX my_table_when_idx ON my_table_ (when_ DESC)
   WHERE when_ > f_when_cutoff();
   ```

   With millions of rows, the difference in size can be dramatic. And this  only makes sense with a much smaller index. Just half the size or something would not cut it. Index access itself is not slowed much by a bigger index. It's **mostly the sheer size** of the index, which needs to be read and cached. (And possibly avoiding additional index writes, but hardly in your case.)
3. Use the function in all related queries. Include the same `WHERE` condition (even if logically redundant) to convince the query planner the index is applicable. For the simple query:

   ```
   SELECT <some big columns>
   FROM   my_table_ 
   WHERE  when_ > f_when_cutoff()
   ORDER  BY when_ DESC
   LIMIT  1;
   ```

The size of the index grows with new (later) entries. Recreate the function with a later timestamp and `REINDEX` from time to time with no or little concurrent access. Only reindex after a relevant number of rows has been added. A couple of thousand entries won't matter much. We are doing this to cut off *millions*.
The beauty of it: **queries don't change**.

Implementation with function to update the partial index automatically:

- [Get latest child per parent from big table - query is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8088075/939860)

More general advice:

- [Index optimization with dates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27928/index-optimization-with-dates/27929#27929)

Comment: Since we are hard-coding a date-time string in this approach, why create the function `f_latest_when`? Why not use that hard-coded string directly in the index definition?

Comment: @BasilBourque: Because you can use `f_latest_when()` in queries and the index definition alike and don't have to change either after changing `f_latest_when()`. (But you *must* reindex.)