# CONCAT used in INDEX causes ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4, functions, datatypes

I am facing the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
> ```

When trying to create index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX full_phone_number ON orders_clientphone (concat(area_code, phone));
```

On the other hand, when using alternative syntax for concatenation:

```
CREATE INDEX full_phone_number ON orders_clientphone ((area_code || phone));
```

Postgres is pretty much ok with that.
Both columns are defined as `character varying(256)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deciding factor for Postgres is that the function `concat()` is defined *stable* and **not *immutable*** in the system catalog `pg_proc`:

```
SELECT proname, provolatile, proargtypes, proargtypes[0]::regtype AS argtype, prosrc
FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'concat';

proname | provolatile | proargtypes| argtype | prosrc
--------+-------------+------------+---------+-----------
concat  | s           | 2276       | "any"   | text_concat
```

[The manual on `pg_proc.provolatile`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html)

> `provolatile` tells whether the function's result depends only on its
>   input arguments, or is affected by outside factors. It is `i` for
>   "immutable" functions, which always deliver the same result for the
>   same inputs. It is `s` for "stable" functions, whose results (for fixed
>   inputs) do not change within a scan.

I also added the argument types of the function (`"any"`) to connect to the answers of @dezso and @jjanes, which deliver the rationale behind the decision to make this function only stable. And the name of the internal function (`text_concat`).

Here is a related question to illustrate why immutability of index expressions is a sine qua non condition:

- [Intentionally corrupting an index in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108393/intentionally-corrupting-an-index-in-postgresql)

As for using the operator `||`:

```
    SELECT o.oprname, o.oprleft::regtype, o.oprright::regtype, o.oprcode, p.provolatile
    FROM   pg_operator o
    JOIN   pg_proc     p ON p.oid = o.oprcode
    WHERE  oprname = '||';


 oprname |   oprleft   |  oprright   |     oprcode     | provolatile
---------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------
 ||      | anyarray    | anyelement  | array_append    | i
 ||      | anyelement  | anyarray    | array_prepend   | i
 ||      | anyarray    | anyarray    | array_cat       | i
 ||      | text        | text        | textcat         | i
 ||      | bit varying | bit varying | bitcat          | i
 ||      | bytea       | bytea       | byteacat        | i
 ||      | text        | anynonarray | textanycat      | s
 ||      | anynonarray | text        | anytextcat      | s
 ||      | tsvector    | tsvector    | tsvector_concat | i
 ||      | tsquery     | tsquery     | tsquery_or      | i
 ||      | jsonb       | jsonb       | jsonb_concat    | i
```

The function to use internally depends on actual data type of operands. The definition of an operator includes the operands' data types in Postgres. 
All of the functions are different and also different from `text_concat` above. `||` is just stable as well, when one of the operators is `anynonarray`. Things are not so trivial behind the curtains.

`character varying(256)` (like any `varchar` variant) is *binary-coercible* to `text` so [function type resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html) defaults to `text`.

Comment: So, what's the solution if one needs to index the result of text concatenation?

Comment: @AlexR: Depends on involved data types and NULL values. For 2 non-null text columns, just use `||` ...

Comment: The solution, use || (as in the ops question), or wrap the call to concat  into an function declared immutable.

Answer (score 4):

To fill out dezso's answer, here is an example of the same input yielding different outputs depending on database state:

```
select concat(1.0000000000003::float8,56);

1.000000000000356

set extra_float_digits TO 3;

select concat(1.0000000000003::float8,56);

1.0000000000002999856
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe concat, [defined in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) as follows:

```
FUNCTION                                  RETURN TYPE  DESCRIPTION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
concat(str "any" [, str "any" [, ...] ])  text         Concatenate the text repre-
                                                       sentations of all the arguments. 
                                                       NULL arguments are ignored.
```

is not immutable because the text representation might depend on database settings, [like that of a date or timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19681/6219).