# How to speed up SELECT from not-unique column?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, select

I have a simple query in a Postgres 15 database. No joins or other fancy stuff:

select * from my_table where col='val'

The goal is to speed up the query. I'd say I need an index, but the values of the `col` are not unique. Is there any way to specify something like non-unique index, or any other way to speed it up **using table structure only**?

I assume all mem/cache/hardware tuning was done already.

Comment: Indexes don't have to be unique, but it doesn't mean any of them will be used. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To optimize:

#### Specifics

The column `col` is not `UNIQUE`. But as long as cardinality in the column isn't extremely low (meaning your filter is selective enough), a basic B-tree index helps (a lot):

```
CREATE INDEX my_table_col_idx ON my_table (col);
```

If performance of that `SELECT` is your paramount objective, [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) the table using said index. See:

- [Impact of CLUSTER on performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144931/impact-of-cluster-on-performance)
- [Alternative to CLUSTER without table lock](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174659/alternative-to-cluster-without-table-lock/174674#174674)

Do you really need to select the whole row (`SELECT *`), or would a selection of columns suffice?

#### Basics

- Storage: faster is obviously better.
- RAM: more is obviously better - until you have enough so that the whole table can reside in cache all the time. Then storage loses its relevance for your `SELECT` query.
- CPU: faster is obviously better - but mostly only when your system is near capacity, as CPU is typically not the bottleneck for a simple `SELECT` query.
- Concurrent load: less on the same table / database / server is obviously better. (Writers don't block readers in Postgres. Still, write activity can impede read performance in various ways.)
- Server configuration: RAM has to be allocated properly, cost settings and column statistics must about valid.
- Table definition: choose the right data types in optimized sequence. See:

  - [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)