# In Postgres, can I CLUSTER by multiple indexes?

Tags: postgresql, table, clustered-index

I want to order the records in my `tasks` table according to `completed` and then according to `workOrderID`, just like I can to with the `ORDER BY` clause of a `SELECT` query, so that this

| taskID | workOrderID | completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | t |
| 2 | 1 | f |
| 3 | 3 | t |
| 4 | 2 | t |
| 5 | 9 | t |
| 6 | 4 | f |
| 7 | 5 | f |
| 8 | 4 | t |
| 9 | 1 | f |

is stored like this

| taskID | workOrderID | completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | t |
| 4 | 2 | t |
| 3 | 3 | t |
| 8 | 4 | t |
| 5 | 9 | t |
| 2 | 1 | f |
| 9 | 1 | f |
| 6 | 4 | f |
| 7 | 5 | f |

When I try, I get a syntax error, and I don't see that functionality mentioned in the docs.  I think this could speed up some queries.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a compound index for that? And why do you think clustering the table the way you want is useful? This sounds suspiciously like an X-Y Problem™.

Comment: Why can't you just do an index `(completed DESC, workOrderID, taskID)`

Comment: `When I try` - when you try what, exactly? There's no reason why you can't create an index on (completed, workOrderID) and `CLUSTER` on that? I'm VtC but will vote to Reopen if you provide the answers to the questions you've been asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) physically rewrites a table (and consequently all its indexes) according to the sort order in **one** given (or saved) index. Not multiple.
Consider a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) for your use case.

The rewritten table is in pristine condition, all bloat is removed, and wiggle room per page according to the `FILLFACTOR` setting is restored. So, after re-populating the cache, you'll see a performance improvement if the table (and/or indexes) had been bloated, independent of the sort order. Keep this side-effect in mind.

The sort order itself helps queries for which data locality has been improved (and/or which need that exact sort order), but not others (which may suffer). The effect deteriorates over time with writes to the table. See:

- [Impact of CLUSTER on performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144931/impact-of-cluster-on-performance/145176#145176)