# Looking for a possible multi-column index

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, query-performance

I have a table `highscore` containing the columns:

- `game` (text)
- `date` (timestamp)
- `score` (integer)
- more irrelevant ones...

The query most often run on it is:

```
SELECT *
FROM highscore
WHERE game = :gamename
AND date BETWEEN :start AND :end
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I currently have three B-tree indexes on this table, one for each column above.

I'm thinking that I could further optimize performance by adding some sort of multi-column index, which starts with `game`. However, when thinking through the various options for the next column(s), I get stuck.

Can I use a multi-column index for further optimization here?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1

Comment: I'd try an index on `(game, date, score)`. Although the `score` column probably doesn't help very much to speed up the ordering though (if it's used at all). Probably an index on `(game, date)` will be just as good. Btw: it's a bad habit to use column names that are also reserved words like `date` - and it actually doesn't tell anyone what the column contains. Something like `happened_on` or `scheduled_for` is much more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

No wonder you get stuck. You are facing contradictory requirements, which a b-tree index cannot easily reconcile. You can hardly optimize the search for date *and* score at the same time. If you order by date, the scores are spread out arbitrarily - or vice versa.

There is a way though. You can make use of a set of **partial indexes**.
Consider the [high-end solutions under this closely related question.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684)

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it some more, I found these two options:

- (`game`, `date`) for when I'm selecting the scores of a certain time period (usually a week). The conditions on `game` and `date` should select a relatively small set of records, which can then easily be sorted on `score`.
- (`game`, `score`) for selecting all-time highscores. Here the index should work 100%.

Shouldn't be a problem to just add both.

Comment: This doesn't really look like an answer, given the question at the end. You can edit your question (there's a link right under the tags for that) to put additional information.