# OFFSET and LIMIT on complex query

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.3, performance, postgresql-performance

I am doing a pretty complex query in Postgres 9.3.4:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT  100
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT  100;
```

See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/optimize-a-query-with-small-limit-predicate-on-one-column-and-order-by-another) for more details on my Postgres db, and settings, etc.

Which is great, unless I try to do some pagination.
To see what I mean. When I do a count, with no limit set:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC;
```

I get `(107 rows)`, which is the correct number of results.

If I want to paginate, I'd use `OFFSET` on the subquery. If the first page has 100 posts, the second page should have 7 posts.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT  100
   OFFSET 100
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT  100;
```

but instead it returns `(0 rows)`.

If I do the pagination on the outer query:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
LIMIT  100
OFFSET 100;
```

I get `(7 rows)` which is correct, but then the query is insanely slow (see this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/optimize-a-query-with-small-limit-predicate-on-one-column-and-order-by-another))

Is there a way to paginate this query properly, not slow it down, and get the correct results back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For just the two pages, a compromise could be:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   unnest('{19082, 19075, 20705, 18328, 19110, 24965, 18329, 27600
              , 17804, 20717, 27598, 27599}'::int[]) s(source_id)
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   posts
   WHERE  source_id = s.source_id
   AND    deleted_at IS NULL
   ORDER  BY external_created_at DESC
   LIMIT  200   -- 100 + 100 (outer limit + offset) per source_id
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.external_created_at DESC
OFFSET 100
LIMIT  100;
```

Which will be considerably slower than the first 100 rows, but still *much* faster than your [original query in your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124790/optimize-a-query-with-small-limit-predicate-on-one-column-and-order-by-another).

For just 107 rows total in your example, performance will be almost identical.

Performance decreases with every later page, obviously. `OFFSET` is a pain for performance, generally. But it becomes a PITA when combined with your difficult query.

I would consider a materialized view with pre-calculated row numbers or the more complex (but also more potent) solution here:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query)

Also related:

- [Improve performance for order by with columns from many tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/improve-performance-for-order-by-with-columns-from-many-tables/112680#112680)

Comment: For this line `LIMIT  200   -- 100 + 100 per source_id to cover all cases.` wouldn't it be `100 * page_number,` so a limit of 200 for page 2, a limit of 300 for page 3, etc? Otherwise, in this example wouldn't it be a `LIMIT` of 1200 since there are 12 `source_ids` in the query?

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: I clarified a bit. The inner `LIMIT` is *per `source_id`*, that's the nature of a `LATERAL` subquery.

Comment: By `per source_id` you don't mean multiply by the number of source id's, but rather the limit is on the source_id query, correct? Sorry!

Comment: @goddamnyouryan: Read this to understand `LATERAL`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860