# Speed up count queries on a couple million rows

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, count, postgresql-performance

Assuming a db full of products. A product can belong to exactly 1 collection and is created by a user. Rough scale of the db:

- Products: 52.000.000
- Collections: 9.000.000
- Users: roughly 9.000.000 as well

I am trying to retrieve the amount of products+collections a user has, and the amount of products inside each collection (this information is supposed to get generated all x days and indexed in ElasticSearch) .

For the user query, I am currently doing something like this:

```
      SELECT
        users.*,
        (SELECT
          count(*)
        FROM
          products product
        WHERE
          product.user_id = user.id
        ) AS product_count,
        (SELECT
          count(*)
        FROM
          collections collection
        WHERE
          collection.user_id = user.id
        ) AS collection_count
      FROM
        users user
```

all *_id fields are indexed. Using explain(analyze, verbose) (sensitive information removed):

```
 Limit  (cost=0.00..156500.97 rows=100 width=41) (actual time=0.064..28345.363 rows=100 loops=1)
   Output: (...), ((SubPlan 1)), ((SubPlan 2))
   ->  Seq Scan on public.users user  (cost=0.00..14549429167.11 rows=9296702 width=41) (actual time=0.064..28345.241 rows=100 loops=1)
         Output: (...), (SubPlan 1), (SubPlan 2)
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=1415.84..1415.85 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=261.101..261.102 rows=1 loops=100)
                 Output: count(*)
                 ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products product  (cost=7.32..1414.95 rows=355 width=0) (actual time=0.282..260.767 rows=382 loops=100)
                       Output: (...)
                       Recheck Cond: (product.user_id = user.id)
                       Heap Blocks: exact=32882
                       ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_user_id_index  (cost=0.00..7.23 rows=355 width=0) (actual time=0.165..0.165 rows=382 loops=100)
                             Index Cond: (product.user_id = user.id)
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=149.13..149.14 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=22.333..22.333 rows=1 loops=100)
                 Output: count(*)
                 ->  Index Only Scan using collections_user_id_index on public.collections collection  (cost=0.43..149.02 rows=44 width=0) (actual time=0.610..22.300 rows=28 loops=100)
                       Output: collection.user_id
                       Index Cond: (collection.user_id = user.id)
                       Heap Fetches: 2850
 Planning time: 0.214 ms
 Execution time: 28345.508 ms
```

When timing the read queries:

- LIMIT 1: 0.695ms
- LIMIT 10: 10434ms
- LIMIT 100: 150471ms

As the query times become unusably slow when retrieving more than a couple of rows, I am wondering if it is possible to speed this up a bit.

If I were to beef up the DB machine, would adding more CPUs help? AFAIK postgres doesn't execute queries on multiple cores so I am not sure how much that would help.

(Also slightly related, but how come the `count()` for collections uses a index only scan, while products uses a bitmap heap scan instead?)

Answer (score 5):

While computing numbers for all or most users, it's *much* more efficient to use plain subqueries to aggregate counts per user before joining instead of correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT u.*, p.product_count, c.collection_count
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id AS id, count(*) AS product_count
   FROM   products
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) p USING (id)
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT user_id  As id, count(*) AS collection_count
   FROM   collections
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) c USING (id);
```

The index-only scan and bitmap index we see in the `EXPLAIN` output only benefit queries for a small subset of rows (`LIMIT 100`). Your test is misleading in this respect. While computing numbers for all (or most) users, indexes won't help. Sequential scans will be faster.

The `Bitmap Heap Scan` you see is only the second step needed for the bitmap index scan - which comes as a surprise for just 100 rows. Either your table statistics are out of date or those 100 users have *a lot* of related products or rows in `products` are highly clustered (physically, meaning multiple rows for one user reside on the same or few data pages). Postgres only switches to a bitmap index scan if it expects to find multiple rows per data page, which comes as a surprise for 100 users and 52.000.000 products (`rows=355` expected and `rows=382` found).

Related:

- [Index usage on a temporary table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153404/index-usage-on-a-temporary-table/153439#153439)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Interesting, I see! Given memory and resource limitations I have to `LIMIT` the query to a sane size. However even with a small size like `LIMIT 10` and a offset of 1.000.000, the query becomes unusably slow. Would you happen to have any advise for this particular case?

Comment: @dvcrn: A large `OFFSET` is typically almost as expensive as if you would increase `LIMIT` by the same amount. It depends on details of your query, tables and indexes. Related answers [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/112680/3684) or [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125959/3684). But this is hardly related to your original question any more. Please ask a ***new question*** if you still need it.