# Database engine with counting b-trees for efficient paging support

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, oracle, db2

Today I realized another fascinating thing about sql databases: They don't do paging well at all.

By paging I mean selecting a slice of data defined by a starting record number and a record count according to an order one has an index on - this operation is used by user interface grids with pagers or scrollbars with lazy loading.

In my case, I noticed how the beginning of the data in my grid the ui was very responsive, but lower down the data it became sluggish. That was with Sql Server.

I checked the execution plan, and it was reading the data through an index in the correct order, but for the data lower down it would still need to scan through all the previous data to get the correct starting row.

Now that I think about it, it's fairly obvious: Efficient seeking is usually supported by a search key, not by record number.

However, it doesn't have to be that way. It very much depends on how the underlying data structure of the respective database engine is implemented. Traditional b-trees can not efficiently find a record by number, but a variant of it can: The tree would have to store the number of all records in the whole respective subtree for each node. That way, even a lookup by row number can be served in logarithmic time.

With such an implementation, paging could always be efficient.

I'm wondering which database engines have that feature, if any - which is why the question is tagged with various different sql database engine tags.

Do you know what your favorite database does on paging? Does it do a scan or can it indeed seek by record number?

Comment: In SQL databases records do not have "numbers", because they do not have any intrinsic order.

Comment: @Einstein But indexes and result sets have an order.

Comment: There are ways to make pagination more efficient. In your code, you didn't show it but I'm guessing, you are probably reading in all of the wide rows from row 1 right through to the last page, and then lopping the first 99%. See http://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch - of course if your filters don't have supporting indexes (or can't use indexes anyway, such as lastname like '%s%'), the pagination part is just a small part of the problem.

Comment: Few comments - pagination is sick by definition, unless to use serializable  isolation level, it does not guarantee consistent output between executions. Some b-tree indexes even do not support delete, nothing in the world is for free, and storing additional information in branch block would pop-up somewhere else as un-necessary burder to the database. Except for web pages you practically never need pagination queries. Pagination queries are not a must, we use them only because application servers can not keep ResultSet open between page clicks.

Comment: @ibre5041 Web pages and lob applications. In those two scenarios, pagination is ubiquitous. I don't get your concern regarding consistency: It's obvious that a page is a snapshot that could be different the next time. I do understand that there will be trade-offs though.

Comment: @ibre5041 "...we use them only because application servers can not keep ResultSet open between page clicks..." And probably also because ORMs don't support cursors and databases lock everything during a read - so you need to do individual queries when scrolling around on data. Also databases don't tell you when data changed, so re-querying is basically the way they want it to be anyway.

Comment: @John imagine you display records 1-5, then 6-10, meantime somebody deletes or inserts rows on position 1-10. Then application requests rows 11-15, what user will see? You can hardly build any deterministic businesses logic based on pagination. Pagination belongs into presentation layer, and should not be handled by databases if possible. Unfortunately the reality is different.  Databases are inert, it will take a lot of time, till special index type is introduced, if it ever happens.

Comment: @ibre5041 The second query obviously needs to re-query all rows that are visible in the scrolling window in one query to provide a consistent presentation. Also, the problem can hardly be put into the presentation layer if the data is a million rows plus.

Comment: No, it has no way to "seek".

Comment: See http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results and http://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Comment: Also: "*result sets have an order*" - not unless you use an `ORDER BY`

Comment: Contrary to what Luke says, MySQL does have optimal index usage for the "seek method".  Perhaps that was fixed after Luke waved his magic wand.

Comment: @John -- By "remembering where you left off", one can avoid the duplicated / skipped item that can happen with `OFFSET`.

Answer (score 4):

> SQL Databases ... don't do paging well at all.

Actually, databases (or RDBMS to be precise) don't *do paging* at all. That's up to client programs. But there are smart ways to query DBs involving indexes with varying support from different RDBMS.

"Paging" hardly defines a task. That's why your question is hard to answer. You have to specify *how* you define pages first.

Read-only tables are trivial. Just add a row number in a materialized view and a plain btree index on it. Every RDBMS can do that. The true art is in handling concurrent write load. You have to define exact requirements first. And that's where your question is leaving out ...

> for the data lower down it would still need to scan through all the previous data to get the correct starting row.

Your description indicates that you are using a lowly [`OFFSET` - `FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) in SQL Server - [other RDBMS use different syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29#Result_limits). A large offset is bound to be slow this way.
***Instead***, remember unique (!) index column value(s) of first and last row for the current page and you can retrieve the next or previous n rows very quickly using a matching btree index - in *logarithmic time*.

In particular, **Postgres** also supports this technique for multicolumn keys (row values). Details in these related answers:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)
- [Improve performance for order by with columns from many tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/improve-performance-for-order-by-with-columns-from-many-tables/112680#112680)

Comment: What if the the user directly scrolls to the middle of the data in grid? We don't need the next page, we need random pages.

Comment: @John: Define "middle". Also, if the users "scrolls", you have to start somewhere. And if a user can scroll from the start to the middle, we are talking about about a trivial number of rows, which should be uncritical for performance even with `LIMIT` / `OFFSET`.

Comment: The middle of a billion rows is half a billion. If you have a scrollbar on a data grid, you can easily skim over millions of rows in milliseconds of a mouse move by yanking down the scrollbar thumb. That's the whole point of scroll bars.

Comment: @John: Again, it depends on requirements. In a read-only table, this is well-defined and simple and cheap (add a row number). With concurrent writes, it gets tricky because "half a billion" is a moving target, and the best solution depends on exact requirements. You did ask for *paging*, not for scrolling.

Comment: It's true I should have mentioned the scrolling case right away. I thought it was obvious as basically all middleware data layers have classical pagers and virtual scrolling basically call down to the same thing: "take" and "skip" operations in the respective sql dialect. Whenever you see a grid with a pager somewhere, be assured it's probably not going to do what you're suggesting in your answer - except it was hand-crafted. The fact remains that data grids, middleware and databases don't play well together in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Pagination via `OFFSET` is both slow, and error prone.  [*This*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) discusses how to "remember where you left off" as a better way.

Comment: When the user yanks down the scrollbar thumb to the somewhere in the middle of a zillion records of a result set, that won't help. And that's the kind of paging that's actually important. I don't expect a user to click "next page" a hundred thousand times on a classical pager.

Comment: Search for "infinite scroll"; it became popular a couple of years ago, and probably involves Javascript and AJAX, more than MySQL.

Comment: Or take a Toolkit from Telerik or DevExpress and bind their data grids to a Sql Server table through linq. Same thing. I doubt it came after ajax.