# What is the recommended way to join junction tables for efficient ordering/pagination?

Tags: postgresql, join, performance, pagination, postgresql-performance

**Summary**: I have a simple database schema but even with just a few 10's of thousands of records the performance on basic queries is already becoming a problem.

**Database**: PostgreSQL 9.6

**Simplified schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  title text NOT NULL,
  score int NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE tag (
  id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
  name text NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE article_tag (
  article_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES article (id),
  tag_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES tag (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (article_id, tag_id)
);
CREATE INDEX ON article (score);
```

**Production data info**:

All tables are read/write. Low write volume, only a new record every couple minutes or so.

Approximate record counts:

- ~66K articles
- ~63K tags
- ~147K article_tags

Average of 5 tags per article.

**Question**: I want to create a view `article_tags` which includes an array of tags for every article record, can be ordered by `article.score` and paginated with or without additional filtering.

In my first attempt I was surprised to see that the query took ~350 ms to execute and wasn't using the indexes. In subsequent attempts I was able to get it down to ~5 ms but I don't understand what is going on. I would expect all these queries to take the same amount of time. **What crucial concept am I missing here?**

Attempts (SQL Fiddles):

1. [multi-table joins (~350 ms), (~5 ms if ordered by article.id!) -- seemed like the most natural solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/390a7/16)
2. [subquery join (~300 ms) -- also seemed like a natural solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/390a7/14)
3. [limited subquery join (~5 ms) -- super awkward, can't be used for view](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/390a7/13)
4. [lateral join (~5 ms) -- is this really what I should be using? seems like a misuse of lateral](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/390a7/15)
5. ...something else?

Comment: In your fiddle they all take around the same time (~4ms). Same result if I execute them locally (all around ~12ms). Did you really get such significantly different results with the same test data you provided?

Comment: @stickybit No the test data is there just to run the queries and show the execution plan. The benchmark numbers are from my actual data set which consists of about ~66K articles, ~63K tags and ~147K article_tags.

Comment: The plan might change with different data, so the sample data provided might not show the right thing.

Comment: You provided good information, but still forgot your version of Postgres. Also: is the table read only? Or how much concurrent write activity? And how up-to-date do results have to be? How many distinct tags and how many tags per article? Are the numbers in your comment typical? If so, [edit] the question to provide this essential information *there*. Is this for retrieving *all* rows from table `article` (paginated), or a few selected rows - filtered how exactly?

Comment: @stickybit Good point. I just compared and the plans are similar for each query but with a larger data set a couple of the seq scans are replaced with index scans.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Just updated the question to provide the additional info. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Pagination

For **pagination**, `LIMIT` (and `OFFSET`) are simple, but typically inefficient tools for bigger tables. Your tests with **`LIMIT 10` only show the tip of the iceberg**. Performance is going to **degrade with a growing `OFFSET`**, no matter which query you choose.

If you have no or little concurrent write access, the superior solution is a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` with an added row number, plus index on that. And all your queries select rows by row numbers.

Under concurrent write load, such a MV is outdated quickly (But a compromise like refreshing the MV `CONCURRENTLY` every N minutes may be acceptable).
`LIMIT` / `OFFSET` is not going to work properly at all since "the next page" is a moving target there, and `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` cannot cope with that. The best technique depends on undisclosed information.

Related:

- [Database engine with counting b-trees for efficient paging support](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148312/database-engine-with-counting-b-trees-for-efficient-paging-support/148381#148381)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)

#### Index

Your indexes generally look good. But your comment indicates that table `tag` has *many* rows. Typically, there is very little write load on a table like `tag`, which is perfect for index-only support. So add a multicolumn ("covering") index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tag(id, name);
```

Related:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/does-postgresql-use-an-index-only-scan-in-this-join/190158#190158)

#### Just the top N rows

If you don't actually need more pages (which isn't strictly "paging"), then any query style is good that reduces qualifying rows from `article` *before* retrieving details from the related tables (expensively). Your "limited subquery" (3.) and "lateral join" (4.) solutions are good. But you can do better:

Use an **`ARRAY` constructor** for the `LATERAL` variant:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.score, tags.names
FROM   article a
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT t.name
      FROM   article_tag a_t 
      JOIN   tag t ON t.id = a_t.tag_id
      WHERE  a_t.article_id = a.id
   -- ORDER  BY t.id  -- optionally sort array elements
      )
  ) AS tags(names) ON true
ORDER  BY a.score DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

The `LATERAL` subquery assembles tags for a *single* `article_id` at a time, so `GROUP BY article_id` is redundant, as well as the join condition `ON tags.article_id = article.id`, and a basic `ARRAY` constructor is cheaper than `array_agg(tag.name)` for the remaining simple case.

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Or use a lowly **correlated subquery**, typically even faster, yet:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.score
     , ARRAY (
         SELECT t.name
         FROM   article_tag a_t 
         JOIN   tag t ON t.id = a_t.tag_id
         WHERE  a_t.article_id = a.id
      -- ORDER  BY t.id  -- optionally sort array elements
      ) AS names
FROM   article a
ORDER  BY a.score DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=19a30bdccb5c05192444b6cee236804c)*
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/390a7/18)

Comment: Thank you so much for this exceptional answer! The "ah ha" moment for me is realizing that `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` are NOT filtering the result set in the same way that `WHERE` does even if the column that I am ordering by has an index. Everything makes a whole lot more sense now including the alternative query methods you provided.

Comment: Also, perhaps this is suited for another question but why is there such a discrepancy between `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` execution times when ordering by `id` and `score` in my first attempt? Even if I update all the scores to equal the ids, paginating by the `id` column is faster by at least a factor of two despite the fact that both columns are indexed integers with identical values. Is there something special about primary key columns that makes `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` paging more efficient when ordering by them?

Comment: @LuciferSam: If you `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `JOIN` using the same column (`id`), Postgres can typically use a simpler, cheaper query plan. Even more so for a small `LIMIT`. The `LATERAL` variants should not exhibit much of the same difference. Related question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18300/3684 `EXPLAIN` (with various options) exposes plan and performance details for each query. (And yes, this is stuff for another question. Comments are not the place.)