# How to prevent seek pagination from doing sequential scan over entire table

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, pagination

I have 3 tables and a materialized view:

**resource_categories** contains all category names and metadata

```
create table if not exists resource_categories (
    category_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    content TEXT,
    icon VARCHAR(50)
);
```

**resources** contains all resources under each category

```
create table if not exists resources (
    resource_id INT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    content TEXT,
    link VARCHAR(1000),
    category_id INT REFERENCES resource_categories(resource_id),
    icon VARCHAR(255),
    created_at DATE,
    updated_at DATE
);
```

**resource_votes** contains user liking a resource or disliking it

```
create table if not exists resource_votes (
    resource_id INT REFERENCES resources(resource_id),
    user_id INT,
    vote BOOLEAN
);
```

**resource_votes_aggregate** a materialized view with likes per resource_id

```
CREATE materialized view resource_votes_aggregate AS 
SELECT
   resource_id,
   COUNT(
   CASE
      WHEN
         vote = TRUE 
      THEN
         1 
   END
) AS likes 
FROM
   resource_votes 
GROUP BY
   resource_id;
```

- I want to execute the following queries
- Find all resources sorted in descending order of likes (find most liked resources)
- Find all resources sorted in descending alphabetical order of their titles
- I want to use SEEK / KEYSET pagination for efficiency

**Query to find resources in descending order of their likes page 1**

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes 
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
ORDER BY
   likes DESC,
   resource_id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

**Execution Plan**

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit (cost=74.50..74.52 rows=5 width=157) (actual time=0.058..0.060 rows=5 loops=1)
-> Sort (cost=74.50..76.80 rows=918 width=157) (actual time=0.058..0.058 rows=5 loops=1)
Sort Key: (COALESCE(a.likes, '0'::bigint)) DESC, r.resource_id DESC
Sort Method: top-N heapsort Memory: 25kB
-> Hash Right Join (cost=12.03..59.25 rows=918 width=157) (actual time=0.032..0.046 rows=50 loops=1)
Hash Cond: (a.resource_id = r.resource_id)
-> Seq Scan on resource_votes_aggregate a (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=12) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=38 loops=1)
-> Hash (cost=10.90..10.90 rows=90 width=149) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=50 loops=1)
Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 11kB
-> Seq Scan on resources r (cost=0.00..10.90 rows=90 width=149) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=50 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.050 ms
Execution Time: 0.075 ms
```

This and all the other queries generate a sequential scan which beats the entire purpose of seek pagination

- How do I fix this. Help is super appreciated

[LINK TO DB FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dNnrjBRei15oLUFBd6y1mV/14)

Answer (score 3):

There may be more potential for improvement. But the obvious **big issue** is this:

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   title,
   COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
ORDER BY
   likes DESC,               -- refers to output column!
   resource_id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> If an `ORDER BY` expression is a simple name that matches both an output
>   column name and an input column name, `ORDER BY` will interpret it as
>   the output column name. This is the opposite of the choice that `GROUP BY`
>   will make in the same situation. This inconsistency is made to be
>   compatible with the SQL standard.

So even if there is an applicable index including `resource_votes_aggregate.likes`, it cannot be used as the column is hidden behind the expression `COALESCE(likes, 0) AS likes` - reflected in the query plan as:

> Sort Key: (COALESCE(a.likes, '0'::bigint)) DESC

**Fix** with:

```
SELECT
   r.resource_id,
   r.title,
   COALESCE(a.likes, 0) AS likes
FROM
   resources r 
   LEFT JOIN
      resource_votes_aggregate a 
      ON r.resource_id = a.resource_id 
ORDER BY
   a.likes DESC NULLS LAST,  -- refers to input column!
   r.resource_id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This refers to the **input** column now and qualifies for index usage. It's substantially cheaper to evaluate in any case, even without index, so you can't go wrong with this.

Since `likes` obviously can be `NULL`, be sure to add `NULLS LAST`. See:

- [Sort NULL values to the end of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622046/939860)

Table-qualification for *all* input columns (like I added) is a good way to avoid confusion - not only for the problem at hand.

#### `MATERIALIZED VIEW`

The MV in your fiddle would be more efficient like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW resource_votes_aggregate AS
SELECT resource_id
     ,(count(*) FILTER (WHERE vote))::int AS likes  -- faster
FROM   resource_votes
GROUP  BY resource_id;
```

The aggregate `FILTER` is typically faster.
`count()` returns `bigint` (8 bytes). Cast to `integer` (4 bytes).

This is the all-important **index** (missing in your fiddle):

```
CREATE INDEX ON resource_votes_aggregate (likes DESC, resource_id DESC);
```

With two `integer` columns, index tuples fit the minimum size of 8 bytes. (With `bigint` for `likes`, it would be 16 bytes (12 + 4 padding). See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Obviously, you also need an index on `resources(resources_id)`. If that's the PK, then it's there.

**If** you use this query a lot, and preconditions for index-only scans are given, a multicolumn index on `(resources_id) INCLUDE (title)` may pay. See:

- [Can Postgres use an index-only scan for this query with joined tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/can-postgres-use-an-index-only-scan-for-this-query-with-joined-tables/190158#190158)

#### Optimized query

If Postgres is not smart enough to give you the best query plan, this equivalent query will:

```
(
SELECT r.resource_id, r.title, a.likes -- COALESCE not needed
FROM   resource_votes_aggregate a
JOIN   resources r USING (resource_id)
ORDER  BY a.likes DESC                 -- NULLS LAST not needed
        , a.resource_id DESC           -- perfect for above index
LIMIT  5  -- logically redundant, but may help with best plan
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT resource_id, title, 0 AS likes 
FROM   resources r
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (  -- only rows without likes
   SELECT FROM resource_votes_aggregate a
   WHERE  a.resource_id = r.resource_id
   )
ORDER  BY r.resource_id DESC
LIMIT  5  -- logically redundant, but may help with best plan
)
LIMIT 5
```

The second `SELECT` will typically be ***never executed***, if there are at least 5 resources with likes. See:

- [Way to try multiple SELECTs till a result is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365613/939860)
- [Select first record if none match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30813090/939860)

#### Aside

You mentioned pagination. Be sure to avoid `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` for big tables. See:

- [What is the recommended way to join junction tables for efficient ordering/pagination?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205268/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-join-junction-tables-for-efficient-ordering-pagin/205286#205286)

Comment: thank you for the fantastically detailed answer! i edited the question to add the materialized view, before editing i had a mention of the keyset pagination, the problem with your query though is that it ll take only resources that have a like on them, if a user never liked a resource, it wont show up in the final result with 0 likes

Comment: @PirateApp: `it ll take only resources that have a like on them` No, both of my queries will include resurces without `likes`. (Even though I doubt there will ever be fewer than 5 resources with `likes`.) There was a corner case bug with repeating liked resources that I fixed now. Also, I added a cast to `integer`. See above.

Comment: apologies my bad the first query does a sequential scan but the second query definitely works, the only problem is how would you navigate to page 2 using keyset pagination on this :) So I tried to modify it and came up with this https://pastebin.com/2bhp989k if it isnt too much to ask, i was wondering if that is what you meant by not using offset pagination, i put the 5th row's resource_id and likes to arrive at the next 5 rows, suggestions? :)

Comment: tried the second query with a category_id it goes back to sequential scan ( SELECT r.resource_id, r.title, a.likes FROM   resource_votes_aggregate a JOIN   resources r USING (resource_id) WHERE category_id=1 ORDER  BY a.likes DESC  , a.resource_id DESC LIMIT  5 ) UNION ALL ( SELECT resource_id, title, 0 AS likes  FROM   resources r WHERE category_id=1 AND  NOT EXISTS (  SELECT FROM resource_votes_aggregate a  WHERE  a.resource_id = r.resource_id  ) ORDER  BY r.resource_id DESC LIMIT  5 ) LIMIT 5;

Comment: Please ask new questions in new questions. Comments are not the place. If you need assistance building a whole application, consider paid consulting.

Comment: apologies @Erwin my bad, thank you for all your help!