# Can you make Postgres execute ORDER BY after OFFSET and LIMIT?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, pagination

Consider this pagination scenario

| id | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mickey | Mouse |
| 2 | Donald | Duck |
| 3 | Scrooge | McDuck |
| 4 | Minerva | Mouse |
| 5 | Goofus | Dawg |
| 6 | Daisy | Duck |

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

The result set is going to be

| id | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Daisy | Duck |
| 5 | Goofus | Dawg |
| 4 | Minerva | Mouse |

It may make sense from SQL's standpoint, but it makes little sense from the human standpoint. After all, the query was meant as "give me the first page of three in reversed order". "The first page" is clearly the *first* three rows of the table, not the *last* three rows so the human way of executing that query would result in

| id | name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Scrooge | McDuck |
| 2 | Donald | Duck |
| 1 | Mickey | Mouse |

The original result set, on the other hand, would be a better fit for this query, "give me the *second* page of three in reversed order"

```sql
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3
OFFSET 3;
```

Can you make Postgres execute `ORDER BY` after `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`?

Comment: The first result does not match the first query. Guess you wanted to add `DESC` to the sort order there.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I did, indeed, thank you. I was tired so I forgot to include it

Comment: "The first page is clearly the first three rows of the table" there is no first in a table in SQL, it is an unordered set. Unless you use `ORDER BY` you may get the rows in any order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would wrap that into a subquery to display results with a different sort order:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   users
   ORDER  BY id
   LIMIT  3
   OFFSET 3
   ) sub
ORDER  BY id DESC;
```

That said, `LIMIT` & `OFFSET` do not scale well for pagination. If your table isn't trivially small, consider a smarter approach. See:

- [What is the recommended way to join junction tables for efficient ordering/pagination?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205268/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-join-junction-tables-for-efficient-ordering-pagin/205286#205286)
- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)

Comment: Also, `LIMIT` before `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense, because the rows in a PostgreSQL table have no fixed ordering.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, know which `Query` method would translate into something better than `OFFSET` (if there's one)? `setFirstResult()` translates into `OFFSET`, see. I'm talking JPA

Comment: @Sergey I can't speak for JPA, sorry.