# Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?

Tags: postgresql, order-by, union

As per standard SQL `UNION` / `UNION ALL` do not guarantee any particular sort order without an outer `ORDER BY` clause - like there is hardly any place in SQL where sort order is guaranteed without `ORDER BY`.

However, Postgres uses an "Append" step for plain cases of `UNION ALL`, hence results from the first leg (even if unsorted among their partition) always come before the next leg, etc. Postgres simply *appends* results from each leg in the given order. This is particularly relevant with a `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT 1 FROM tbl  -- or any complex query
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
LIMIT  1
```

Obviously this does not hold for `UNION` (without `ALL`). But other than that, I have never seen Postgres return out of order, i.e. *'2'* from the above query, while the first `SELECT` would also return row(s). Not even if the first leg is extremely expensive.

I have based queries on this behavior in the past. Now [I have met a claim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045322/return-1-if-number-exists-in-table-and-0-otherwise/27046317?noredirect=1#comment130136707_27046317) Postgres might return rows out of order here, but unsubstantiated with actual proof.

The current [Postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) has this to say on the matter:

> `UNION` effectively appends the result of ***`query2`*** to the result
> of ***`query1`*** (although there is no guarantee that this is the
> order in which the rows are actually returned). Furthermore, it
> eliminates duplicate rows from its result, in the same way as
> `DISTINCT`, unless `UNION ALL` is used.

This is pretty unclear. Does the cited order apply to the list of `SELECT` clauses, or rows within each clause, or just the returned set? Also, `UNION ALL` is only mentioned in the second sentence, so it remains unclear if the all-important first sentence is supposed to apply to `UNION ALL` ...

Can anybody show an example, where rows are returned out of order, breaking the sequence of `UNION ALL` clauses? In any version of Postgres. (Even if the latest version would be most interesting.)

If not that, is there reason to believe this might change in a future version?

`ORDER BY` is not the immediate issue here. The question is whether multiple `UNION ALL` clauses return rows in the given sequence (before `LIMIT` can kick in and stop further branches from executing).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There was a similar question recently in pgsql-docs mailing list,
[Clarify the ordering guarantees in combining queries (or lack thereof)](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/2742511.1657800108%40sss.pgh.pa.us#cddd884aa3798882067e0fa2882e77c5):

> I was trying to understand what - if any - are the guarantees with regards
> to ordering for combining queries (UNION/UNION ALL/...). From this
> message[1](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/2742511.1657800108%40sss.pgh.pa.us#cddd884aa3798882067e0fa2882e77c5), it seems that UNION ALL does preserve the ordering of the
> operand queries, whereas UNION does not (presumably neither do INTERSECT,
> INTERSECT ALL, EXCEPT and EXCEPT ALL).
>
> The documentation[2] makes no mention of this, I'd suggest adding a note
> clarifying this.

Tom Lane (and others) replied:

> Since the documentation doesn't make a guarantee there is none.  If you
> want ordered output use ORDER BY.

> No, there is no guarantee. It's just that UNION ALL works this way today
> (preserving the order of the subselects) - and I'm not even sure about
> that, it may not preserve the order in all cases, with different indexes or
> partitioning or a parallel plan, etc.
> In any case, there is no guarantee that the behaviour will not change in
> the future due to planner improvements.

> Yeah, that.  You can get a parallelized plan today for UNION ALL:
>
> ```
> =# explain analyze select * from foo union all select * from foo;
>                                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                            
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  Gather  (cost=0.00..208552.05 rows=5120008 width=244) (actual time=0.652..390.135 rows=5120000 loops=1)
>    Workers Planned: 2
>    Workers Launched: 2
>    ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..208552.05 rows=2133336 width=244) (actual time=0.021..228.848 rows=1706667 loops=3)
>          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..98942.68 rows=1066668 width=244) (actual time=0.453..78.084 rows=853333 loops=3)
>          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on foo foo_1  (cost=0.00..98942.68 rows=1066668 width=244) (actual time=0.024..125.299 rows=1280000 loops=2)
>  Planning Time: 0.094 ms
>  Execution Time: 488.352 ms
> ```
>
> **It's true that in simple non-parallelized cases we'll do the first query then the second, but SQL doesn't promise that to be true and neither does Postgres.**

Answer (score 4):

It has been established, there is no guarantee that rows from the first `UNION ALL` term would be returned before rows from the next `UNION ALL` term etc. Not in standard SQL, and not in Postgres, either.

The **clean solution** is to not rely on the order of clauses.

#### Alternatives

For simple queries as shown above (no outer `ORDER BY` or `JOIN`) the sequence is observed anyway in Postgres versions before Postgres 11 where [`Parallel Append`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-APPEND) was added. Simply because `Append` is (was) the only plan option - which is implemented that way.

It still happens to work in current **Postgres 15** as long as `Parallel Append` is not involved - which only happens for *big* sets. You can make sure of it by disabling that option. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-APPEND)

> `enable_parallel_append` can be used to disable this feature.

You might set this option locally, even just for the current transaction to patch up old code quickly with:

```
SET LOCAL enable_parallel_append = off;
```

But **don't** get hung up on such a provisional workaround. Better fix your SQL code properly.

#### Proper Alternatives

[vladich](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/260559/vladich) commented:

> [...] The thing here is if you're using `ORDER BY`, you lose the
> convenient functionality of "execute in particular order until certain
> number of rows are received". I don't see any other way of doing that
> aside from executing multiple queries sequentially (which could be
> less efficient and also requires dynamic SQL in general).

The **next best thing** I can think of is a PL/pgSQL function building up the set. You can check the number of result rows after each query with `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, modify (reduce) the `LIMIT` for the next query, and `RETURN` as soon as you found enough. Can be done without dynamic SQL (so no `EXECUTE` required) as `LIMIT` accepts a parameter. See:

- [How to limit result set with multiple RETURN QUERY in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29349971/939860)

More code and planning overhead. But the dynamically adapted `LIMIT` may produce better query plans for subsequent queries.

Another example, repeating the same query in a loop, also without dynamic SQL:

- [Improve performance for order by with columns from many tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112679/improve-performance-for-order-by-with-columns-from-many-tables/112680#112680) (chapter "PL/pgSQL function")

Code example for a dynamic `LIMIT` while also using dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in a loop:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500#22500) (chapter "Function")