# Lookup table for a one-to-many relationship

Tags: database-design, postgresql, index-tuning, clustered-index, referential-integrity

I have a `tickets` table with an `id` that I need to associate to a lookup table where the counterpart of that data is another `id` that is controlled from an outside source.

```
tickets
- id
- sutff

lookup
- outside_data_id
- ticket_id
```

I just need to know if the association exists (hence the `lookup` table) and has a one to many relationship. I know nothing else about the `outside_data_id` except the `id` itself and the related `ticket_id`.

Also I don't want to alter the `tickets` table as this will only affect a small amount of `ticket_id`'s.

#### Example

```
outside_data_id = 1234
```

Can be related to:

```
ticket_id = 321
ticket_id = 322
ticket_id = 900
```

Would the below lookup table structure work or is there a better way?

```
CREATE TABLE lookup
(
   outside_data_id integer, 
   ticket_id integer
)
```

Comment: I am not completely sure what you are looking up. Do you have an `outside_data_id` and want to look up related `ticket_id`'s? Or a `ticket_id` and want to verify it is linked to an `outside_data_id`? Or both directions? An optimal answer depends on these specifics. Also, is the combined (ticket_id, outside_data_id) unique - so no dupes in table `lookup`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table will work fine for this purpose, but you probably want to add an index. If the primary reason for using this table is to take an outside_ticket_id and get the corresponding ticket_id's I would add the following clustered index:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CL_Lookup_OD_ID] on [lookup](outside_data_id)
GO
```

If the primary lookup will be the other way around (trying to find the outside_data_id  from a ticket_id) place the clustered index on the other column.

----  Oh, sorry, just noticed this is Postgres. The above syntax is SQL Server.  For Postgres, create an index on the column, then issue the cluster command, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_outside_data_id on lookup(outside_data_id);
CLUSTER lookup using IX_outside_data_id;
```

You may also want to look at the "fillfactor" on the index depending on how heavy the insert load is here.  But that is a large topic worth exploring on it's own...

Comment: Thanks, was also looking for the INDEX but didn't know about Clusters

Comment: [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) in Postgres does **not** do the same as a clustered index in SQL server. Not sure what this is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

A structure like yours should probably be solved with:

- a **multi-column primary key** constraint on the *m*-table (`lookup`) and
- a **foreign key** constraint referencing the primary key of the *1*-table.

An *optimal* index for looking up values *in one direction* is provided automatically by the primary key of the `lookup` table.

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
   ticket_id integer PRIMARY KEY  -- possibly serial instead of integer
 , stuff text
);

CREATE TABLE lookup (
   outside_data_id integer
 , ticket_id integer REFERENCES ticket(ticket_id)
      -- ON UPDATE CASCADE  -- optional
      -- ON DELETE CASCADE  -- optional
 , CONSTRAINT lookup_pkey PRIMARY KEY (outside_data_id, ticket_id)
);
```

Using `ticket_id` as descriptive name.

If you ..

> just need to know if the association exists

... then a plain **foreign key** *might* be all you need. It takes care of that automatically and delivers the additional bonus of relational integrity being enforced no matter what. Plus more options.
It also insists on a related item for each and *every* `filter_id`, so you may not be able to use it.

Actual **indexes** needed depend on your workload, which is still unclear to me after reading your question multiple times. In particular, the **order of columns in a multi-column index** (or a primary key constraint for that matter) is relevant - as we have discussed in depth [under this related question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684).

For **optimal performance** (neglecting costs for index maintenance, assuming the table isn't updated much) and if your queries **go both ways**, you would create another index in addition to the primary key as defined above:

```
CREATE INDEX lookup_reverse_idx(ticket_id, outside_data_id);
```

While you *could* cover most additional use-cases with just a single-column index on `ticket_id`, due to data alignment in PostgreSQL storage, two integer columns in your index result in the same size on disk as just one. So, hardly any cost for some additional gain.

#### Aside

Experience gathered with different RDBMS'es is not always applicable across platforms.

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) doesn't have a [`CLUSTERED INDEX` like SQL server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).

PostgreSQL's [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) command is loosely related, but works differently. It's a one-time operation and does not *keep* the table clustered. It also completely rewrites the table with all effects of a `VACUUM FULL` (in modern versions since Postgres 9.0).

Depending on your actual workload `CLUSTER` may or may not be useful. It *can* be for looking up multiple related rows (`outside_data_id` -> `ticket_id`), especially for tables that are not updated a lot.

Advice on [`FILLFACTOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) is good, though, especially if you use `CLUSTER` - which may otherwise actually be hurting performance if you `UPDATE` a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The structure you've created seems like a perfectly reasonable lookup table.

```
CREATE TABLE lookup1
(
   outside_data_id integer NOT NULL 
   , ticket_id integer NOT NULL
);
```

I would probably add an index to this table like:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_Lookup1 
    ON Lookup1 (outside_data_id, ticket_id) 
    WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS=ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS=ON, FILLFACTOR=100);
```

(My `CREATE INDEX` sample is for SQL Server, most likely there will be some changes needed for PostgreSQL!)

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a `CLUSTERED INDEX` like in SQL server. There is the loosely related `CLUSTER` command ... I added a bit to my answer.