# When should I use Index on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, index, foreign-key, java

In my Java (Spring Boot app), I have the following entity definition  which has a relationship with Company entity via `companyUuid` property. I will also let users to search by `name` field. We do not use entity relation annotations e.g. `@OneToMany`,...

```
@Entity
public class DemoEntity {

    @Id
    private long id;

    private UUID uuid;

    private UUID companyUuid;

    private String name;

    // code omitted for brevity
}
```

**1.** As this table has a FK of `companyUuid`, should I add an index for it? If so, is the following index definition is true?

```
@Table(indexes = {
    @Index(unique = true, name = "company_uuid_key", columnList = "companyUuid")
})
```

**2.** As users search Demo entity records by `name` field, should I also add index for each search field (for this scenario, pnly `name` field)? If so, is the following index definition is true?

```
@Table(indexes = {
    @Index(unique = true, name = "name_key", columnList = "name")
})
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Show us the output of `\d table_name` for the relevant tables using your `psql` client. The text of your (most important) queries would also be useful. Not everyone here is a Java programmer - however, the experienced users know DDL and DML!

Comment: Indexes on a table only make sense in the context of a statement that you want to speed up. Please add that statement to the question.

Comment: Do you have any idea of the volumetry to be stored in those tables ? Depending on the volumetry if it's very low for example, an index will not be usefull. Thus you could prepare an index for future volumetry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know what indexes to create for a table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/how-do-i-know-what-indexes-to-create-for-a-table)

Comment: **@Closures** Why close without understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should you index fields that are foreign keys to [fields in] other tables?  **Yes**.
Does that index have to be unique?  *Probably not*.

Consider a table of Towns, each of which exists within a State.
Many different Towns will appear within one particular State.  The Primary Key on the States table will (by definition) be unique [within that table] but the same State id will appear in *many* Town records.

If you're going to allow searching by name then you ought to index that as well.  However, consider whether these names are unique [within that table].  From the above example, there are many Towns called "Birmingham", but each one is in a *different* State.

Comment: If the searched names are not unique, then should I use index that is NOT unique? Or no need to use index in that situation?

Comment: Unique names, unique index.  Non-unique names, non-unique index.  
If you put a unique index on name and then a /second/ guy called Fred comes along, the table won't let him in!