# Why is this query with WHERE, ORDER BY and LIMIT so slow?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index-tuning, performance, order-by, postgresql-performance

Given this table `posts_lists`:

```
                      Table "public.posts_lists"
   Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id         | character varying(20)  |           | not null |
 user_id    | character varying(20)  |           |          |
 tags       | jsonb                  |           |          |
 score      | integer                |           |          |
 created_at | integer                |           |          |
Indexes:
    "tmp_posts_lists_pkey1" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "tmp_posts_lists_idx_create_at1532588309" btree (created_at)
    "tmp_posts_lists_idx_score_desc1532588309" btree (score_rank(score, id::text) DESC)
    "tmp_posts_lists_idx_tags1532588309" gin (jsonb_array_lower(tags))
    "tmp_posts_lists_idx_user_id1532588309" btree (user_id)
```

Getting a list by tag is **fast**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT * FROM posts_lists
WHERE jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? lower('Qui');
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on posts_lists  (cost=1397.50..33991.24 rows=10000 width=56) (actual time=0.110..0.132 rows=2 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? 'qui'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=2
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tmp_posts_lists_idx_tags1532588309  (cost=0.00..1395.00 rows=10000 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? 'qui'::text)
Planning time: 0.297 ms
Execution time: 0.157 ms
```

Getting a list ordered by score, limit 100 - also **fast**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT *
FROM posts_lists
ORDER BY score_rank(score, id) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..12.03 rows=100 width=88) (actual time=0.074..0.559 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using tmp_posts_lists_idx_score_desc1532588309 on posts_lists  (cost=0.56..1146999.15 rows=10000473 width=88) (actual time=0.072..0.535 rows=100 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.586 ms
Execution time: 0.714 ms
```

But combining the above two queries is **very slow**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE
SELECT * FROM posts_lists
WHERE jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? lower('Qui')
ORDER BY score_rank(score, id) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.56..33724.60 rows=100 width=88) (actual time=2696.965..493476.142 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using tmp_posts_lists_idx_score_desc1532588309 on posts_lists  (cost=0.56..3372404.39 rows=10000 width=88) (actual time=2696.964..493476.139 rows=2 loops=1)
        Filter: (jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? 'qui'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 9999998
Planning time: 0.426 ms
Execution time: 493476.190 ms
```

**Why? How to improve the efficiency of the query?**

Definition of the two functions used above:

```
create or replace function score_rank(score integer, id text)
  returns text as $$
select case when score < 0
  then '0' || lpad((100000000 + score) :: text, 8, '0') || id
       else '1' || lpad(score :: text, 8, '0') || id
       end
$$
language sql immutable;


create or replace function jsonb_array_lower(arr jsonb)
  returns jsonb as $$
SELECT jsonb_agg(lower(elem))
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(arr) elem
$$
language sql immutable;
```

Comment: All i can think of is use a type that can be indexed instead of json.

Comment: @Jasen jsonb can be indexed ...

Comment: You provided *some* good information. If you need a solution provide *complete* information as instructed in the tag info for [postgresql-performance]. In particular, definition and purpose of the functions `jsonb_array_lower()` and `score_rank()` may be relevant. Show some sample rows and describe what the column `tags` can contain. Just a simple JSON array of tags? Cardinalities, value frequencies? Normalization *may* be the answer.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your function `score_rank()`? (I can see what it's doing and have serious doubts it's helpful.) What can `id` look like? Why is it `character varying(20)`? Please show some sample rows. I have various ideas, but I am stopping here until you provide enough information.

Comment: Ok, `score_rank()=±socre + id; score = ups - downs`, mainly for sorting and paging. [xid](https://github.com/rs/xid), last night I redesigned the sorting, using the auto increment id to shorten the length of the id, score_rank = base256(tag_id) + base_256(±score) + base256(post_id), advantage: score_rank probably has about 11 digits in length, when querying, i can use `<>` to shorten the range; Disadvantages: Increased rows due to `tags`. what do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Sorting and paging

Your function `score_rank()` produces a `text` from an `integer` score and the appended PK `id`. That's not helpful for sorting. Replace it completely, I suspect you do not need it at all. Instead use the two columns `score` and `id` directly for **sorting**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   posts_lists
ORDER  BY score DESC, id DESC
LIMIT  100;
```

Replace your index `tmp_posts_lists_idx_score_desc1532588309` with a smaller, faster, cheaper to maintain, more versatile index on `(score DESC, id DESC)`.

You can also base **pagination** on this multicolumn index efficiently with row value comparison. See:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34291099/939860)
- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32982895/939860)

You later mentioned a new function concatenating strings with base256 etc. All that smart trickery is not going to increase performance. Sorting on an `integer` is faster than sorting on strings in Postgres. Using `integer` (or `bigint`) instead of `varchar(20)` would actually help in multiple ways.

#### Statistics and query plan (a.k.a: Why?)

The main issue is the **lack of statistics** for values nested in the `jsonb` column. Postgres consequently *sometimes* misjudges the selectivity of the predicate `jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? lower('Qui')` and chooses a bad query plan. In your example with `LIMIT 2` the logic of the query planner can be illustrated like this - let's call this **"Plan 1"**:

*Only two rows with the highest scores? Let's scan the index `posts_lists_idx_score_desc` starting with the highest scores. With any luck we'll have the result in no time!*

It's a reasonable plan for most cases with at least moderately common tags. But the tag 'qui' turns out to be very rare, and with low scores, too. The worst case. Postgres ends up scanning close to 4 million rows, just to keep 2. A colossal waste of time:

> ```
> Rows Removed by Filter: 3847383
> ```

If the query planner had any idea how rare that tag actually is, it would start with the other index `posts_lists_idx_tags` like we see in your second example with `LIMIT 100` - let's call this **"Plan 2"**:

*Find matching rows, then sort by score and take the top N.*

**Plan 1** is more favorable the *smaller* the `LIMIT` and the more frequent the tag. (And if qualifying rows happen to sort on top.)
**Plan 2** is more favorable the *bigger* the `LIMIT` and the less frequent the tag.

Postgres has currently no statistics about nested values in document types like `jsonb`. And no *combined* frequencies at all. See:

- [SELECT very slow when no results and a LIMIT is specified](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132235/select-very-slow-when-no-results-and-a-limit-is-specified/132237#132237)
- [Inconsistent statistics on jsonb column with btree index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167525/inconsistent-statistics-on-jsonb-column-with-btree-index/167652#167652)

Update: "Combined statistics" became possible with [`CREATE STATISTICS` in Postgres 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html).

What ever else you do, be sure to run the **latest version of Postgres**. The planner gets smarter with every release.

#### Alternatives

**1.** One idea might be to use a **Postgres array** (`text[]`) and array operators instead of the `jsonb` column to have *some* statistics for most common *elements*. Columns `most_common_elems`, `most_common_elem_freqs`, and `elem_count_histogram` in the system view [`pg_stats`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html).

Helps Postgres to generate better query plans for some constellations, but it's no silver bullet. For starters, only the most common elements are stored. Postgres still doesn't know about the rarest elements.

**2.** **Normalize** your db design and move `tags` to a separate **1:n table** with a single tag per row. That increases the disk footprint because of the added row overhead per tag. (But changing tags becomes much cheaper with less table bloat.) If your tags are stable, consider a full n:m relationship between `posts_lists` and a new table `tags`. That's a bit smaller for lots of common tags, too. And it's the "clean" way. You have more detailed statistics and should see fewer bad query plans.

**3.** Since **Postgres 10** there is a variant of `to_tsvector()` that processes `json(b)` values. So it's simple to create a **text search index** and work with text search operators now.

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_lists_idx_tags_fts ON posts_lists USING gin (to_tsvector('simple', tags));
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts_lists
WHERE  to_tsvector('simple', tags) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'qui') -- text search is case insensitive
ORDER  BY score DESC, id DESC
LIMIT  2;
```

Be sure to use the **`simple`** dictionary. You don't want stemming which is built into most other dictionaries.

Text search functions produce lower case output, it all works case insensitive by design. No need for processing like in your original function `jsonb_array_lower()`.

**4.** While sticking with a `jsonb` index, try the more specialized `jsonb_path_ops` operator class:

```
CREATE INDEX ON posts_lists USING gin (jsonb_array_lower(tags) jsonb_path_ops);
```

Query with:

```
WHERE  jsonb_array_lower(tags) @> '["qui"]'
```

The manual:

> Although the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class supports only queries with
> the `@>` operator, it has notable performance advantages over the
> default operator class `jsonb_ops`. A `jsonb_path_ops` index is usually
> much smaller than a `jsonb_ops` index over the same data, and the
> specificity of searches is better, particularly when queries contain
> keys that appear frequently in the data. Therefore search operations
> typically perform better than with the default operator class.

But I do *not* expect much for your particular case.

**5.** Use a regime of "granulated" indexes, combined with a procedural solution. See:

- [Can spatial index help a "range - order by - limit" query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18300/can-spatial-index-help-a-range-order-by-limit-query/22500)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=40571fffe6e42d292dc3759f517ec770)* - with a number of tests ...

Comment: Thanks... I tested 'score DESC, id DESC', which supports sorting and pagination, but `SELECT * FROM posts_lists WHERE tags @> ARRAY ['Qui'] ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC LIMIT 100; `still very slow.

Comment: See: [How to speed up ORDER BY sorting when using GIN index in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105316/how-to-speed-up-order-by-sorting-when-using-gin-index-in-postgresql)

Comment: Wow, I moved `tags` to a separate 1:n table with a single tag per row, and then created an index `(score DESC, id DESC, tag DESC)` which solved the problem, but increased the disk space.

Comment: Disk space has increased 3x, this way is expensive. When using the `gin(tags)` index, query by `WHERE tags @> ARRAY ['x'] ORDER BY score DESC, id DESC LIMIT z` if `x` does not exist or the `z` is greater than the actual number of rows, it is very slow. why?

Comment: @robxyy: The cases you mention are those where Postgres has to scan the whole table to finally know there are not enough qualifying rows. So those are the worst case scenarios for an index scan on `posts_lists_idx_score_desc`. I added more explanation and a couple of possible alternatives above.

Comment: Thanks, this is my test result. [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a460fa10ec6b129a106088952bd8ea6b)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this statement is, that the query planner has no usable statistics for `jsonb_array_lower(tags)`.

As seen in the first explain:

```
(cost=0.00..1395.00 rows=10000 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=2 loops=1)
```

The planner expects 10.000 rows to be returned if he uses the filter `jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? lower('Qui')` but there are just two rows returned.

The same happens in the last statement. Because of this missing information, the planner assumes, that a scan on the index `tmp_posts_lists_idx_score_desc1532588309` would be more efficient.

You could try to avoid the need of `lower` and normalize the input during `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

Another method would be:

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT id FROM posts_lists
    WHERE jsonb_array_lower(tags) ? lower('Qui')
)
SELECT * FROM posts_lists l, c
WHERE l.id = c.id
ORDER BY score_rank(score, id) DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This statement uses a CTE as optimization fence, but be careful, the performance may get worse for other `WHERE` conditions or table content.

Comment: Why does this happen when the limit is greater than the actual number of rows? if so, how do I estimate the limit size?

Comment: I don't think this is caused by the limit. The query planner needs statistics about the data you are working with to decide on the best plan. The usage of functions is a little bit of a problem here, because there are no statistics for the result of a function.

Comment: You are right, when i tested the uneven distribution of tags, i found that it was not the cause of the limit.