# Nullable One To Many w/Join Table - Indexing

Tags: postgresql, database-design, orm

I have a question regarding database design, I am working with PostgreSQL using Hibernate for ORM, the design I inherited includes the following tables

## users

user_id (pk)
user_name
user_dob ...

## sessions

session_id (pk)
session_date
session_duration ...

## user_sessions

user_id (fk)
session_id (fk)

As you can guess one user can have many sessions, the reason (I believe) the join table was used is because a session can be added before the user exists (and it is linked to the user after they signup), thus avoiding a nullable field in the sessions table...fine.

But I have recently been looking at creating some multi-column indexes to speed up certain queries and have realised that I cannot include the user in this index as the column is in a different table.

As I am fairly new to DB design I am just wondering if the above design is correct? Or am I in fact better off using a nullable FK in the session table to allow me to index the user relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a session can only belong to a *single* user at any given time, the more appropriate model would be without a join table (`user_sessions`). What's the problem with column `user_id` being `NULL`?

If you *need* it to be `NOT NULL` and you don't always know the user at creation time, just insert a user "unknown" (with `user_id 0` in my example). Can serve as `DEFAULT` value, too ...

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
  session_id   serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,user_id      int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 REFERENCES users(user_id)
 ,session_date timestamp
 ...
)
```

#### Note on indexing strategy

Postgres can combine multiple indices with excellent speed. Typically, **in your original scenario**, with a [*nested loop*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/planner-optimizer.html#AEN90774):

> *nested loop join*: The right relation is scanned once for every row found in the left relation. This strategy is easy to implement but can
>   be very time consuming. (However, if the right relation can be scanned
>   with an index scan, this can be a good strategy. It is possible to use
>   values from the current row of the left relation as keys for the index
>   scan of the right.)

Say, you have these indices:

```
sesssions(session_id)
user_sessions(session_id, user_id)
```

Both should be covered by the pk constraints in your original model automatically. **However**, the second one could go either way `(user_id, session_id)` or `(session_id, user_id)` and that matters:
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field?lq=1)

For best performance in a query like:

```
SELECT u.user_name, s.session_date 
FROM   users         u
JOIN   user_sessions us USING (user_id)
JOIN   sessions      s  USING (session_id)
WHERE  u.user_name = 'foo'
```

You would need the index (or pk constraint) to be

```
user_sessions(user_id, session_id)
```

Or have an additional index with `user_id` as first column.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, yes I think a nullable FK would have been better as you stated, I was not aware of the indexing strategy info you included, I will look into this more as it could allow me to carry on with the current design