# How to index a query with `WHERE field IS NULL`?

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, null

I have a table with lots of inserts, setting one of the fields (`uploaded_at`) to `NULL`. Then a periodic task selects all the tuples `WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL`, processes them and updates, setting `uploaded_at` to current date.

How should I index the table?

I understand that I should use a partial index like:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON table (uploaded_at) WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL
```

Or smth like that. I'm a bit confused though if it is correct to index on a field that is always `NULL`. Or if it is correct to use a b-tree index. Hash looks like a better idea, but it is obsolete and is not replicated via streaming hot-standby replication. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've experimented a bit with the following indices:

```
"foo_part" btree (uploaded_at) WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL
"foo_part_id" btree (id) WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL
```

and the query planer seems to always choose the `foo_part` index. `explain analyse` also yields slightly better result for the `foo_part` index:

```
Index Scan using foo_part on t1  (cost=0.28..297.25 rows=4433 width=16) (actual time=0.025..3.649 rows=4351 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (uploaded_at IS NULL)
 Total runtime: 4.060 ms
```

vs

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on t1  (cost=79.15..6722.83 rows=4433 width=16) (actual time=1.032..4.717 rows=4351 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (uploaded_at IS NULL)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_part_id  (cost=0.00..78.04 rows=4433 width=0) (actual time=0.649..0.649 rows=4351 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 5.131 ms
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this special case the column actually indexed is irrelevant for the query at hand. You can pick any column. I would pick something else than `uploaded_at`, which is useless. Some column that may be useful for other queries and is not bigger than 8 bytes, ideally.

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON table bar (some_col) WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL;
```

If you have no use case for any other column, it's still best to stick with the useless `uploaded_at`, so not to introduce additional maintenance cost for the index and restrictions for H.O.T. updates. More:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Or use a ***constant*** as index expression if you have no use for any other index column. Like:

```
CREATE INDEX baz ON table bar ((TRUE)) WHERE uploaded_at IS NULL;
```

Parentheses required. This also keeps the index at minimum size. But while the index column is never bigger than 8 bytes (which is the case for `timestamp`) it's still at minimum size anyway.

**Update:** Storage characteristics change in Postgres 13 with [index deduplication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION) (while the rest still applies). See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Related:

- [Get count estimates from pg_class.reltuples for given conditions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115873/get-count-estimates-from-pg-class-reltuples-for-given-conditions/115918#115918)

Comment: Could it maybe be a serial `id` field for example?

Comment: @teferi: a `serial` is as good as any. The point is whether there are actually queries to make use of it.