# What indexes should one use to optimize a PostgreSQL query with a JOIN depth of 2?

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, join, performance, postgresql-performance

**Disclaimer**: I am relatively new to PostgreSQL.

I'm wondering how to optimize a query that does 2 `INNER JOIN`s. My scenario is fairly simple:

Select Posts with a photo (`Posts.photo IS NOT NULL`) and a Hashtag that has the name 'dead' (`Hashtags.name = 'dead'`).

The associations are as follows:

```
Posts <- PostHashtags -> Hashtags

Posts.id    = PostHashtags.postId (FK)
Hashtags.id = PostHashtags.hashtagId (FK)
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
  "Posts".*,
  "hashtags"."id" AS "hashtags.id",
  "hashtags"."count" AS "hashtags.count",
  "hashtags"."name" AS "hashtags.name",
  "hashtags"."createdAt" AS "hashtags.createdAt",
  "hashtags"."updatedAt" AS "hashtags.updatedAt",
  "hashtags"."objectId" AS "hashtags.objectId",
  "hashtags"."_etl" AS "hashtags._etl",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."id" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.id",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."createdAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.createdAt",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."updatedAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.updatedAt",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."postId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.postId",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."hashtagId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.hashtagId",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."objectId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.objectId",
  "hashtags.PostHashtag"."_etl" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag._etl"

FROM (
  SELECT
    "Posts"."id",
    "Posts"."note",
    "Posts"."photo",
    "Posts"."createdAt",
    "user"."id" AS "user.id",
    "user"."name" AS "user.name"
  FROM "Posts" AS "Posts"

  INNER JOIN "Users" AS "user" ON "Posts"."userId" = "user"."id"

  WHERE "Posts"."photo" IS NOT NULL
  AND (
    SELECT "PostHashtags"."id" FROM "PostHashtags" AS "PostHashtags"
    INNER JOIN "Hashtags" AS "Hashtag" ON "PostHashtags"."hashtagId" = "Hashtag"."id"
    WHERE "Posts"."id" = "PostHashtags"."postId"
    LIMIT 1
  ) IS NOT NULL

  ORDER BY "Posts"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 10
) AS "Posts"

INNER JOIN (
  "PostHashtags" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag"
  INNER JOIN "Hashtags" AS "hashtags" ON "hashtags"."id" = "hashtags.PostHashtag"."hashtagId"
)

ON "Posts"."id" = "hashtags.PostHashtag"."postId"
AND "hashtags"."name" = 'dead'

ORDER BY "Posts"."createdAt" DESC;
```

EXPLAIN results:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=886222912.89..886223769.55 rows=1 width=277)
  Join Filter: ("hashtags.PostHashtag"."postId" = "Posts".id)
  ->  Limit  (cost=886220835.39..886220835.42 rows=10 width=189)
        ->  Sort  (cost=886220835.39..886220988.88 rows=61394 width=189)
              Sort Key: "Posts"."createdAt"
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..886219508.69 rows=61394 width=189)
                    ->  Seq Scan on "Posts"  (cost=0.00..885867917.51 rows=78196 width=177)
                          Filter: ((photo IS NOT NULL) AND ((SubPlan 1) IS NOT NULL))
                          SubPlan 1
                            ->  Limit  (cost=0.42..815.70 rows=1 width=4)
                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..815.70 rows=1 width=4)
                                        ->  Seq Scan on "PostHashtags"  (cost=0.00..811.25 rows=1 width=8)
                                              Filter: ("Posts".id = "postId")
                                        ->  Index Only Scan using "Hashtags_pkey" on "Hashtags" "Hashtag"  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=4)
                                              Index Cond: (id = "PostHashtags"."hashtagId")
                    ->  Index Scan using "Users_pkey" on "Users" "user"  (cost=0.42..4.49 rows=1 width=16)
                          Index Cond: (id = "Posts"."userId")
  ->  Materialize  (cost=2077.50..2933.89 rows=1 width=88)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=2077.50..2933.89 rows=1 width=88)
              Hash Cond: ("hashtags.PostHashtag"."hashtagId" = hashtags.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on "PostHashtags" "hashtags.PostHashtag"  (cost=0.00..721.00 rows=36100 width=40)
              ->  Hash  (cost=2077.49..2077.49 rows=1 width=48)
                    ->  Seq Scan on "Hashtags" hashtags  (cost=0.00..2077.49 rows=1 width=48)
                          Filter: ((name)::text = 'dead'::text)
```

This query has been simplified slightly. It also performs `OUTER JOINS` on other data related to `Posts`, which is why the `SELECT` must be performed on `Posts` instead of, say, `PostHashtags`.

Any help in translating the `EXPLAIN` to a useful index would be greatly appreciated.

My ideas:

1. Build an index on `Posts.photo`, but should it be a partial index `WHERE "photo" IS NOT NULL`?
2. Build a `UNIQUE` index on `Hashtags.name`.

I'm not sure if those are necessarily the bottlenecks, though.

Comment: The output of `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` would be more helpful. Plus your version of Postgres. What do you get for: `SELECT count(*) AS ct, count(photo) AS pct FROM "Posts"`? **Most importantly:** Your description does not match what the query does exactly: from the latest 10 posts with photo and any tags, display only those with the tag 'dead'. Is that intented or is `LIMIT 10` in the subquery a debugging residue? Changes the nature of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Also consider the [first answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89426/3684).</sup>

### Query

This does what your current **query** currently does, just simpler and faster:

```
SELECT p.id, p.note, p.photo, p."createdAt",
  u.id           AS "user.id",
  u.name         AS "user.name",
  h.id           AS "hashtags.id",
  h.count        AS "hashtags.count",
  h.name         AS "hashtags.name",
  h."createdAt"  AS "hashtags.createdAt",
  h."updatedAt"  AS "hashtags.updatedAt",
  h."objectId"   AS "hashtags.objectId",
  h._etl         AS "hashtags._etl",
  ph.id          AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.id",
  ph."createdAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.createdAt",
  ph."updatedAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.updatedAt",
  ph."postId"    AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.postId",
  ph."hashtagId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.hashtagId",
  ph."objectId"  AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.objectId",
  ph._etl        AS "hashtags.PostHashtag._etl"
FROM (
    SELECT id, note, photo, "createdAt", "userId"
    FROM   "Posts" p
    WHERE  photo IS NOT NULL
    AND    EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   "PostHashtags" ph
        WHERE  ph."postId" = p.id
        )
    ORDER  BY p."createdAt" DESC
    LIMIT  10
   ) p
JOIN   "PostHashtags" ph ON ph."postId" = p.id
JOIN   "Hashtags"     h  ON h.id = ph."hashtagId"
JOIN   "Users"        u  ON u.id = p."userId"
WHERE  h.name = 'dead'
ORDER  BY p."createdAt" DESC;
```

The [**`EXISTS`** semi-join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) should be faster than your subquery construct. I am assuming that the column `"PostHashtags".id` is the PK and cannot be NULL by itself. Also, if referential integrity is enforced by a FK constraint, no need to join to `"Hashtags"` in this test.

#### Indexes

### Partial index on `Posts`

```
CREATE INDEX posts_foo_idx ON "Posts" ("createdAt", id)
WHERE photo IS NOT NULL;
```

Note the columns: `("createdAt", id)`. Postgres will the latest posts, I expect an *index scan* on `posts_foo_idx` from the top, followed by a test for matching entries in `PostHashtags` using `id` with the next index.

#### UNIQUE index on `PostHashtags`

This time we need the index with `"postId"` first.

The rest is mostly like in the [first answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89426/3684).

Comment: I have never seen those multiple "FROM"s - is that some kind of specialty of Postgres? Or was it meant to be a JOIN?

Comment: @cslotty: Nope, that was just a typo that went unnoticed - until now. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Also consider the [alternative answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89431/3684).</sup>

### Query

This does what your **description** says, **not** what your query currently does ([see comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89338/what-indexes-should-one-use-to-optimize-a-postgresql-query-with-a-join-depth-of/89426#comment160165_89338)):

> *Select Posts with a photo and a Hashtag that has the name 'dead'*

.. limited to the latest 10 qualifying posts:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.note,
  p.photo,
  p."createdAt",
  u.id           AS "user.id",
  u.name         AS "user.name",
  h.id           AS "hashtags.id",
  h.count        AS "hashtags.count",
  h.name         AS "hashtags.name",
  h."createdAt"  AS "hashtags.createdAt",
  h."updatedAt"  AS "hashtags.updatedAt",
  h."objectId"   AS "hashtags.objectId",
  h._etl         AS "hashtags._etl",
  ph.id          AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.id",
  ph."createdAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.createdAt",
  ph."updatedAt" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.updatedAt",
  ph."postId"    AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.postId",
  ph."hashtagId" AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.hashtagId",
  ph."objectId"  AS "hashtags.PostHashtag.objectId",
  ph._etl        AS "hashtags.PostHashtag._etl"
FROM   "Hashtags"     h
JOIN   "PostHashtags" ph ON ph."hashtagId" = h.id
JOIN   "Posts"        p  ON p.id = ph."postId"
JOIN   "Users"        u  ON u.id = p."userId"
WHERE  h.name = 'dead'
AND    p.photo IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY p."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

If you enforce referential integrity between `Posts` and `Users` with a FK constraint, make that
 **`LEFT`**`JOIN "Users"`
This way, Postgres can pick the latest ten rows before considering users.

The various subqueries and parentheses in your joins were not helpful.

### Indexes

Both your ideas are good. Plus at least one more.

#### Partial index on `Posts`

```
CREATE INDEX posts_foo_idx ON "Posts" (id, "createdAt")
WHERE photo IS NOT NULL;
```

Note the columns: `(id, "createdAt")`. My expectation is that Postgres will start with the most selective predicate on `Hashtags.name` and work its way via `PostHashtags` to `Posts`. Then the used index `posts_foo_idx` already provides `createdAt`, which is needed for `ORDER BY` / `LIMIT`.

The partial index only makes sense if a big percentage of the table has `photo IS NOT NULL`. Else, make it a full index.

#### UNIQUE index on `Hashtags.name`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX hashtags_foo_idx ON "Hashtags" (name);
```

#### UNIQUE index on `PostHashtags`

Assuming each post can only be associated with each hashtag *once*.

```
ALTER TABLE "PostHashtags" ADD CONSTRAINT ph_uni UNIQUE ("hashtagId", "postId");
```

This could be your PK. Maybe it *is* your PK already, but with reversed column order: ("postId", "hashtagId"). You probably should have *both* variants. For my query you need this one with "hashtagId" first. For your query, you'd need it the other way round. Consider:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

#### Aside

I suggest you reconsider your naming convention. Use legal, lower case identifiers to avoid the quoting mess and much potential for errors.