# Multi table GROUP BY query optimisation

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, optimization, query-performance

Currently I have a multi table/column `GROUP BY` query which is pretty slow.  Below is the tables schema used by the query:

**report Table**

```
                                                                Table "report"
       Column       |           Type           |                           Modifiers                           | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | integer                  | not null default nextval('dashboard_report_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 county             | character varying(200)   | not null                                                      | extended |              | 
 district           | character varying(200)   | not null                                                      | extended |              | 
 report_name        | character varying(500)   | not null                                                      | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "dashboard_report_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**question Table**

```
                                                       Table "question"
   Column    |          Type          |                            Modifiers                            | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('dashboard_question_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name        | character varying(255) | not null                                                        | extended |              | 
 label       | character varying(255) | not null                                                        | extended |              | 
 report_type | character varying(255) | not null                                                        | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "dashboard_question_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

**questionanswer Table**

```
                                                           Table "questionanswer"
   Column    |          Type          |                               Modifiers                               | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id          | integer                | not null default nextval('dashboard_questionanswer_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 answer      | character varying(255) | not null                                                              | extended |              | 
 question_id | integer                | not null                                                              | plain    |              | 
 report_id   | integer                | not null                                                              | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "dashboard_questionanswer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "dashboard_questionanswer_6f78b20c" btree (report_id)
    "dashboard_questionanswer_7aa0f6ee" btree (question_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "dashboard_que_report_id_4c2a87ee585b6121_fk_dashboard_report_id" FOREIGN KEY (report_id) REFERENCES dashboard_report(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "dashboard_question_id_522f82097923c241_fk_dashboard_question_id" FOREIGN KEY (question_id) REFERENCES dashboard_question(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    "report"."county", 
    "report"."district", 
    "report"."report_name", 
    "question"."report_type", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT "questionanswer"."report_id")
FROM "questionanswer" 
    INNER JOIN "question" ON ( "questionanswer"."question_id" = "question"."id" )
    INNER JOIN "report" ON ( "questionanswer"."report_id" = "report"."id" )
WHERE 
    "question"."name" = 'touch' 
GROUP BY 
    "report"."county", 
    "report"."district", 
    "report"."report_name", 
    "question"."report_type" ;
```

I'm not sure where to start with optimising this query, at the moment it is fairly slow on my system ~300 ms. I did try individually indexing all the columns referred by the `GROUP BY` clause but that didn't help the query time either.

So basically user submits reports, the data of which is stored in reports, each report has multiple QuestionAnswers, which are stored in QuestionAnswer Table. The Question meta data is in Question table. The QuestionAnswer table records will be large next comes Report table data, the Question table has a set of only 40 questions. The objective of the query is to figure out per county, district and report type for a specific question how many reports we have that have answered that question.

My Postgres Sql version is PostgreSQL 9.3.5.
Query plan is [here](http://explain.depesz.com/s/VVD).
My machine hardware spec is MacOSX 10.9.5 4-Core 8 GM RAM SSD, encrypted file system.

Would indexing all the columns referred by `GROUP BY` help?
Or should I go for a multicolumn index?

Comment: Proper table definitions are obtained with `\d tbl` in psql. We need data types, constraints (PK?), indexes etc. for an answer that's more than guesswork. Also cardinalities and *always* your version of Postgres. And explain the objective of the query! Read this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I have updated my question to match all the necessities. Apologies for the inaccurateness earlier, this is my first question in dba.stackexchange

Comment: Is it possible that you have 2 (rows in) `reports` with same `county`, `district` and `report_name`?

Comment: yes, very much so, there will be hundreds of reports with same county, district and report_name

Comment: Looking at your query plan, I see it's doing an external merge on disk ... that probably explains the 300ms time. If you can change your postgres settings and up the "work_mem" number, that may coax it into doing the merge in memory.

Comment: No `UNIQUE` constraint on `(report_id, question_id)` in `questionanswer`? Can the link between a certain question and a certain report be stored multiple times?

Comment: good point, i suppose we could add that constraint if it helps in the query timing.

Comment: @JoishiBodio thanks for pointing that out increasing work_mem to 50 MB did reduce the query time by one third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do wonder, why you have the `report_type` as attribute of the *question*?
Be that as it may, your objective:

> The objective of the query is to figure out per county, district and
>   report type for a specific question how many reports we have that have
>   answered that question.

Why would you include <strike>`report_name`</strike> in `GROUP BY` step? That conflicts with your definition. I think you should remove that:

```
SELECT r.county, r.district, q.report_type
     , count(DISTINCT r.id) AS reports
FROM   question q 
JOIN   questionanswer qa ON qa.question_id = q.id
JOIN   report         r  ON qa.report_id = r.id
WHERE  q.name = 'touch' 
GROUP  BY 1,2,3;
```

Also, as long as you restrict the query to a single question, there is only *one* `report_type` in the result per definition. Including it in the result and `GROUP BY` clause doesn't change the numbers.

As for performance: either create a **`UNIQUE` constraint** on `(question_id, report_id)` (in that order!) like I *suspect* you should have:

```
ALTER TABLE questionanswer ADD CONSTRAINT qa_uni UNIQUE (question_id, report_id);
```

Or, barring that, at least create an index on `(question_id, report_id)`.
Why is the order of columns in the index / constraint important?

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

With the `UNIQUE` constraint in place, the query gets considerably cheaper:

```
     , count(*) AS reports
```

As long as you have only `40 questions` you don't need an index on `question.name`, **but** as long as you select questions by `name`, you should still have a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column.

The PK on `report` does the rest.

---

Related query if you really want to count distinct counties and districts per question:

```
SELECT q.id, q.name, q.report_type
     , count(DISTINCT r.county)      AS distinct_counties
     , count(DISTINCT r.district)    AS distinct_districts
FROM   question q 
JOIN   questionanswer qa ON qa.question_id = q.id
JOIN   report         r  ON qa.report_id = r.id
WHERE  q.name = 'touch' 
GROUP  BY 1;  -- the PK column covers the whole table
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I appreciate the link  on complex index which was very informative. To answer your question on why i need 'report_name' in the groupBy, I want that in the select clause which is necessary in my resulting data set, so can't get rid of that. I did create the index as you suggested, but sadly have no improvement in the query time.

Comment: @noobMama: If you want to *count* reports, you cannot have the report name in the result as well. Just doesn't make sense. You can't have the cake and eat it, too.

Comment: what i want to count is the number of report IDs (aka number of report submissions). The report_name is common for may report submissions. And i would need the number of reports per report_name, hence the report_name in group by, but the count is on report_id

Comment: @noobMama: Well, then add `report_name` back to the query. The rest of my answer remains unchanged.

Comment: hmm, thanks for your effort in answering, I will mark this as accepted, although surprisingly i don't see any query time improvement.