# Select into specific array positions with array_agg()?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, pivot, array, set-returning-functions

Is there a way to set values in specific positions inside an array, based on information from other columns? (Postgres 9.3 or later.)

For example, I would like to select an item and its stock information from the following tables:

Table `item`:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
  id integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO item VALUES
 (1), (2), (3), (4);
```

Table `item_stock` (containing shop-specific information like stock and prices):

```
CREATE TABLE item_stock (
    item_id integer NOT NULL,
    shop_id integer NOT NULL,
    stock integer,
    cost numeric(19,3),
);

INSERT INTO items_stock VALUES
  (1, 1, 2, 10),
  (1, 2, 0, 9),
  (2, 2, 0, 9),
  (3, 1, 3, 22);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/047e1)

Looking for a query to produce the following results, where the array in the column `stock` contains stock info for specific shops. In the example, array position 1 is `stock` for `shop_id=1` and array position 2 is `stock` for `shop_id=2`. `0` instead of `NULL` where no data is found:

```
id | stock
---+-------
1  | {2, 0}
2  | {0, 0}
3  | {3, 0}
4  | {0, 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96075/3684) basically gets the job done:

```
SELECT b.id, array_agg(b.stock) AS stock
FROM  (
   SELECT i.id, COALESCE(i_s.stock, 0) AS stock
   FROM   item i
   CROSS  JOIN unnest('{1,2}'::int[]) n
   LEFT   JOIN item_stock i_s ON i.id = i_s.item_id AND n.n = i_s.shop_id
   ORDER  BY i.id, n.n
   ) b
GROUP  BY b.id;
```

Two notable changes:

1. Order is not guaranteed without `ORDER BY` in the subquery or as additional clause to `array_aggregate()` (typically more expensive). And that's the core element of your question.
2. `unnest('{1,2}'::int[])` instead of `generate_series(1,2)` as requested shop IDs will hardly be sequential all the time.

I also moved the set-returning function from the `SELECT` list to a separate table expression attached with `CROSS JOIN`. Standard SQL form, but that's just a matter of clarity and taste, not a necessity. At least in Postgres 10 or later. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)

Doing the same with `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` and an ARRAY constructor might be a bit faster as we don't need the outer `GROUP BY` and the ARRAY constructor is typically faster, too:

```
SELECT i.id, s.stock
FROM   item i
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT COALESCE(i_s.stock, 0)
      FROM   unnest('{1,2}'::int[]) n
      LEFT   JOIN item_stock i_s ON i_s.shop_id = n.n
                                AND i_s.item_id = i.id
      ORDER  BY n.n
      ) AS stock
   ) s;
```

Related:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)
- [How to apply ORDER BY and LIMIT in combination with an aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213592/how-to-apply-order-by-and-limit-in-combination-with-an-aggregate-function/213724#213724)

And if you have more than just the two shops, a nested `crosstab()` should provide top performance:

```
SELECT i.id, COALESCE(stock, '{0,0}') AS stock
FROM   item i
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT id, ARRAY[COALESCE(shop1, 0), COALESCE(shop2, 0)] AS stock
   FROM   crosstab(
     $$SELECT item_id, shop_id, stock
       FROM   item_stock
       WHERE  shop_id = ANY ('{1,2}'::int[])
       ORDER  BY 1,2$$

     , $$SELECT unnest('{1,2}'::int[])$$
      ) AS ct (id int, shop1 int, shop2 int)
   ) i_s USING (id);
```

Needs to be adapted in more places to cater for different shop IDs.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bc3b56e3a69f6880dc6e166786e9098d)*

#### Index

Make sure you have at least an index on `item_stock (shop_id, item_id)` - typically provided by a `PRIMARY KEY` on those columns. For the crosstab query, it also matters that `shop_id` comes first. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Adding `stock` as another index expression may allow faster index-only scans. In Postgres 11 or later consider an `INCLUDE` item to the PK like so:

```
PRIMARY KEY (shop_id, item_id) INCLUDE (stock)
```

But only if you need it a lot, as it makes the index a bit bigger and possibly more susceptible to bloat from updates.

- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190132/do-covering-indexes-in-postgresql-help-join-columns/190151#190151)
- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)

Answer (score 1):

This is the query I was able to come up (with some brute-force):

```
SELECT b.id, array_agg(b.stock) FROM (
  SELECT a.*, COALESCE(i_s.stock, 0) as stock FROM (
    SELECT id, generate_series(1, 2) as n FROM items  
  ) as a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN item_stock i_s ON a.id = i_s.item_id AND a.n = i_s.shop_id
) as b GROUP by b.id;
```