# UPDATE BIGINT[] column from a SELECT

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.2, array

I have to update a `bigint[]` column named `permissao_ver`.
Example value: `'{1,2,3,4,5,11,44,56,75,11}'`.

Pseudo code:

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa  
SET permissao_ver = '{"(SELECT cod_grupo FROM crm.usuariosgrupos
                        WHERE habilitar = 1)"}'::bigint[] 
WHERE habilitado = 1 AND permissao_ver is null
```

I need to get the codes the above select will return in a format matching the `bigint[]` column. Like: `'{XX, XX, XX, X, XX, X}'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array`:

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa  
SET permissao_ver = array(SELECT cod_grupo 
                          FROM crm.usuariosgrupos
                          WHERE habilitar = 1)
WHERE habilitado = 1 
  AND permissao_ver is null
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa  
SET permissao_ver = (SELECT array_agg(cod_grupo) 
                     FROM crm.usuariosgrupos
                     WHERE habilitar = 1)
WHERE habilitado = 1 
  AND permissao_ver is null
```

Answer (score 2):

[@a_horse provided a solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162252/3684) with an [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) that answers your immediate question.

But the demonstrated form of `UPDATE` carries several potential problems:

1. It's typically wise to add a condition excluding ***empty updates***. See:

   - [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

   Your particular query is *not affected* by this, since the ARRAY constructor never returns `NULL` and you only update NULL values.
2. The `UPDATE` happens, no matter what the (uncorrelated) subquery returns. If the subquery finds no row, you overwrite NULL with an empty array (`'{}'`). And the next call of your query will not touch these rows again as instructed by the predicate `permissao_ver is null`. (`'{}' IS NULL` evaluates to `FALSE`.)
3. If the subquery expression involves *any* volatile functions, it is evaluated repeatedly for every target row. This may or may not be desirable.
   Think of `random()` - you'd want it evaluated repeatedly. But for an actual constant this would be a (big) waste. It depends on what you want to achieve. If you wrap the computation in a subquery or CTE, it's evaluated ***once*** only.

Generally, this form is preferable:

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa p
SET    permissao_ver = u.a
FROM  (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT cod_grupo
                FROM   crm.usuariosgrupos
                WHERE  habilitar = 1)
   ) u(a)  -- a constant expression?
WHERE  p.habilitado = 1
AND    p.permissao_ver IS NULL
AND    u.a <> '{}';  -- for this particular query?
-- AND    p.permissao_ver IS DISTINCT FROM u.a;  -- more commonly this
```

Aside: It's odd, that your subquery is *uncorrelated* (effectively a constant). Typically I would expect some kind of relation to the target table `callcenter.pausa`?

Related:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717)