# How to get lexemes in original sort order from ts_vector?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, array

Postgres' full text search `to_tsvector()` function returns a sorted array of lexemes. I need exactly that, just with lexemes in original sort order. Is there any such Postgres function, or do I need to do it myself? Is so, how?

I need it for Jaro-Winkler string similarity function, for which order of strings/words is important. I need `tsvector` only because of language support for "lexemization". Actually, I just need to convert text, e.g.:

```
select array_to_string(tsvector_to_array(to_tsvector('english', 'I just want to lexemize this string and keep the original order of lexemes...')), ' ');
```

This is OK, except lexemes are ordered alphabetically instead of their original relative order in original text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`unnest(tsvector)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html#TEXTSEARCH-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is the key, like you already used in your answer. But the function can be a lot simpler - and improved for modern Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tokenize_orig(_string text, _dictionary regconfig = 'english')
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT lexeme
   FROM   unnest(to_tsvector($2, $1)) arr
   ORDER  BY positions[1]
   );
$func$;
```

`PARALLEL SAFE` in Postgres 9.6 or later. See:

- [When to mark functions as PARALLEL RESTRICTED vs PARALLEL SAFE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251274/when-to-mark-functions-as-parallel-restricted-vs-parallel-safe)

ARRAY constructor is simpler and cheaper than `array_agg()`. See:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

I added 'english' as default for the function parameter `_dictionary`, so you can skip that unless you want a different dictionary. See:

- [Default values for function parameters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319529/default-values-for-function-parameters/319864#319864)

The above function returns **each lexeme *once***, in the position of its first appearance.
To keep **all appearances**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.tokenize_orig3(_string text, _dictionary regconfig = 'english')
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT ARRAY(
   SELECT lexeme
   FROM   unnest(to_tsvector($2, $1)) arr
        , unnest(positions) pos
   ORDER  BY pos
   );
END;
```

I made it a standard SQL function this time (requires at least Postgres 14), which is totally optional, but slightly more efficient. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to work, Please, suggest if there is a better way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tokenize_orig(
    p_string text,
    p_dictionary regconfig)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$ 
/* This function turns documents into array of lexemes, keeping original order of lexemes. */ 

select array_agg(lexeme) 
from 
    (
    select (arr).lexeme as lexeme 
    from 
        (select unnest(tsv) arr 
        from to_tsvector($2, $1) as tsv) arr 
        where array_length((arr).positions, 1) > 0 
        order by (arr).positions
    ) as qry

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
```