# Multiply elements of equally sized postgresql array

Tags: postgresql, array

In Postgresql 9.6, is there a clean way to multiply corresponding elements within two equally sized arrays?

For example

```
a = [1,2,9,4,5]
b = [5,8,4,0,12]

function(a, b) would return [5, 16, 36, 0, 60].
```

I'd prefer it as a function like this, since it'd be used in multiple places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Parallel Unnest

What you want is something like this with [parallel-unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html). Here we use the [`ARRAY()` constructor rather than `array_agg()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/159710/2639)

```
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT a*b
  FROM unnest(
    ARRAY[1,2], -- ex1
    ARRAY[2,3]  -- ex2
  ) AS t(a,b)
);
```

## Creating our own function

In functional programming, we call this `zip`, and you'd use that in a language with primitive functional support like Python, or the like. In languages with more advanced functional support, like [Haskell, you'd use `zipWith`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=zipWith) or [Ramda.js `R.zipWith()`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith)

This will return an array sized to the greater of `ex1`, or `ex2`. You can put this in a function like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_zip_with_multiply( arr_q anyarray, arr_e anyarray )
RETURNS anyarray
AS $$
  SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT a*b
    FROM unnest(
      arr_q, -- ex1
      arr_e  -- ex2
    ) AS t(a,b)
  );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

SELECT array_zip_with_multiply( ARRAY[1,2,9,4,5], ARRAY[5,8,4,0,12] );
 array_zip_with_multiply 
-------------------------
 {5,16,36,0,60}
(1 row)
```

Note: this won't work if there isn't an operator `*` defined for the type.

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I wanted. I'd have said zip-like, but wasn't sure if that'd dissuade some more cunning answers.

Comment: @Noxville if yo uwant to make it faster, see the update ;)