# Find all items where the 2 latest statuses meet condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table in a PostgreSQL database like this:

```
ID|Item-FK |timestamp|status
=============================
1 | 123    | ...     | EXPIRED
2 | 123    | ...     | PENDING
...
```

I want to query all items where the last two statuses are 'EXPIRED' & 'PENDING' like displayed in the sample above - 'PENDING' latest and 'EXPIRED' immediately before that.

Comment: Is "last" defined by `timestamp` or `ID`? Is there also a table `items` with with 1 row per item of interest (like "FK" seems to suggest)? And how many rows per item on average?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this to avoid needing to hardcode row numbers into your query:

```
select * 
  from t as a 
 where status = 'pending'      -- must be pending
   and exists
  (select * 
     from t as b
    where status = 'expired'   -- must have expired
      and a.itemfk = b.itemfk
      and b.id = 
         (select max(c.id)     -- must be the previous entry before pending
            from t as c
           where c.itemfk = b.itemfk
             and c.id < a.id)  -- must have expired before pending
  );
```

This method performs a lookup to get the maximum `id` of the entry prior to it being pending and then checks that it is the row marked as `expired`.

[db<>fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=abb65874176e30bd05c2c212a0be0940).

Comment: I don't see how does this check that the latest status is 'pending'.

Answer (score 2):

CTE add a row number in descending order, that means that row (1) must be PENDING and row (2) must be EXPIRED.

Then you can use 2 EXISTS subqueries in the WHERE clause to ensure both conditions are true.

```
with ct as
(
select
    id, itemfk, dt, status,
    row_number() over (partition by itemfk order by itemfk, dt desc) rn
from
    t
order by
    itemfk, dt
)
select 
    t1.itemfk
from
    ct t1
where exists (select 1 
              from ct 
              where itemfk = t1.itemfk 
                    and rn = 1 and status = 'pending')
      and
      exists (select 1 
              from ct 
              where itemfk = t1.itemfk 
                    and rn = 2 and status = 'expired')
group by t1.itemfk;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d70d6ef0034ef9b60abc856e7648741a)*

Comment: Could u give me a generic solution? I use Hibernate in java and need a simpler query to execute

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ..

- an `item` table with exactly 1 row per item of interest (as indicated by the column name `item_fk` (= `"Item-FK"`).
- that "last" is defined by the column `ts`(= `timestamp`) - which is `NOT NULL`. (Might alternatively be `id`.)
- that `(item_fk, ts)` is defined `UNIQUE` (else you need more `ORDER BY` expressions to make it deterministic)

Then this should be fastest and simplest:

```
SELECT i.*  -- or what you need from item
FROM   item i
JOIN   LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT status
      FROM   tbl t
      WHERE  t.itemfk = i.item_id
      ORDER  BY ts DESC
      LIMIT  2
      ) AS last2_stat
   ) t ON t.last2_stat = '{PENDING, EXPIRED}'::text[];
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d42c59f78d5ed05827e69400641b3a04)*

You can return columns from table `item` directly.
It is simple to adapt to any other terminal sequence of statuses.

Have this index for best performance:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tbl (itemfk, id DESC, status);
```

`status` as last index expression only if you get index-only scans out of it.

Related, with more explanation:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)