# How to remove NULL values in multidimensional array?

Tags: postgresql, join, null, array

```
SELECT dt.name,dt.description,dt.odobj,dt.defval,dt.datatypeid
      ,array_agg(array[dtv.description::text,dtv.odobj::text,dtv.name::text,dtv.datatypevalueid::text,dtv.datatypeid::text]) as arrayofdatatypevalues
FROM datatypevalue dtv
FULL JOIN public.datatype as dt on dt.datatypeid = dtv.datatypeid
WHERE dt.name !='Integer' and dt.name !='String' and dt.name !='Boolean'
GROUP BY dt.name,dt.description,dt.odobj,dt.defval,dt.datatypeid;
```

Returns output like (example with two result rows):

```
{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}}
{{NULL,10,xxs,1,21},{NULL,9,xyz,0,21}}
```

How do I replace this `{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}}` with `{}`?

Comment: Strange. If you just omit NULLs, how do you know which array member is what?

Comment: Please remember to lead with Postgres version and table definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the **slow and verbose way**:

```
SELECT name, description, odobj, defval, datatypeid
     , CASE WHEN arrayofdatatypevalues = '{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}}'::text[]
            THEN '{}' ELSE arrayofdatatypevalues END AS arrayofdatatypevalues
FROM  (
   -- your org. query here
   ) sub;
```

My **educated guess**, though: you don't actually want `FULL [OUTER] JOIN` to begin with. Looks like a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` to me. ([Basics in the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN).)

```
...
FROM   public.datatype dt
LEFT   JOIN datatypevalue dtv USING (datatypeid)
...
```

If so, transform it into into a `LATERAL` subquery or just a **correlated subquery**:

```
SELECT dt.name, dt.description, dt.odobj, dt.defval, dt.datatypeid
     , ARRAY(
          SELECT ARRAY[dtv.description::text,dtv.odobj::text,dtv.name::text,dtv.datatypevalueid::text,dtv.datatypeid::text]
          FROM   public.datatypevalue dtv
          WHERE  dtv.datatypeid = dt.datatypeid
          ) AS arrayofdatatypevalues
FROM   public.datatype dt
WHERE  dt.name <> ALL ('{Integer,String,Boolean}'::text[]);
```

**Returns `{}`** instead of `{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}}` **out of the box** if no matching row is found in table `datatypevalue`. But still returns `{{NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL}}` for a single rows with all retrieved columns holding an actual `NULL` value, which can be a very important distinction to make. (Probably not possible with your setup - another guess in want of actual table definitions.)

The need for `GROUP BY` goes away.
While being at it, use a faster ARRAY constructor instead of `array_agg()`. See:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=86a4b0ec8b21979aeccf35a5c7887030) for **Postgres 12***.