# Postgres not returning data on array_agg query as below

Tags: postgresql, join, array, coalesce, sqlalchemy

The problem arise when there are no data for books in specific library. Consider a following working scenario.

Table `library`

```
--------------------------------
| id |    name     |    owner  |
--------------------------------
|  1 |     ABC     |     A     |
|  2 |     DEF     |     D     |
|  3 |     GHI     |     G     |
--------------------------------
```

Table `books`

```
--------------------------------
| id |    title    |  library  |
--------------------------------
|  a |     xxx     |     1     |
|  b |     yyy     |     1     |
|  c |     zzz     |     2     |
--------------------------------
```

Now when I do query like below:

```
SELECT library.name, array_agg(b.title) AS book_list FROM library, 
(SELECT title FROM books WHERE books.library = :library_no) as b 
WHERE library.id = :library_no GROUP BY library.id
```

The query generates output for library 1 & 2, but not for library 3. Why and how to solve this issue? (Generate an empty list on no library books)

Required Output:

```
----------------------
| name |    book_list |
----------------------
|  GHI |      {}      |   # or {null}
-----------------------
```

I've even tried `coalesce` as below:

```
SELECT library.name, coalesce(array_agg(b.title), ARRAY[]::VARCHAR[]) AS book_list FROM library, 
(SELECT title FROM books WHERE books.library = :library_no) as b 
WHERE library.id = :library_no GROUP BY library.id
```

Postgres version: 12

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` can solve it, like Laurenz provided.

But I suggest an ARRAY constructor in a `LATERAL` subquery instead:

```
SELECT l.name, b.book_list
FROM   library l
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT title
      FROM   books
      WHERE  library = l.id
      )
   ) b(book_list)
WHERE  l.id = :library_no;
```

This way, you don't need to aggregate in the outer query level and don't need to `GROUP BY` there.

You also don't need `COALESCE`, since the ARRAY constructor over an empty result already produces an empty array (`{}`).

And it should be faster for a small selection in `library` - obviously the query gets the result for a single given library.

Aside, you only need the variable `:library_no` in a single place like demonstrated.

About `LATERAL` joins:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

About the ARRAY constructor:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Basic about [joining tables in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM).

Comment: I dont know about LATERAL and CROSS joins. Could you provide me a good link for beginner to learn about these?

Comment: Thank you @Erwin :)

Comment: @Pax: Basics for `LATERAL` with links to more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860. And `CROSS JOIN` is the simplest way to join. It's an unconditional join: all rows on the left are combined with all rows on the right. Since there is exactly *1* row on the right in the example, that's all we need.

Answer (score 5):

You need a left join:

```
... FROM library
       LEFT JOIN books ON library.id = books.library
```

Then you will also get libraries with no books.

Comment: Yes this do solve my problem. But shouldn't `coalesce` produce an empty array when there is no data in books?

Comment: @Pax: `COALESCE` can only step in when there is a row to begin with.