# Zip array with values from JSON

Tags: postgresql, json, array

Say I have `'{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}'` (just an array with the numbers 1-5), and `{"1": 0, "2": 3, "5": 0}` (comes from a column). With only SQL, is it possible to output this? `{"1": 0, "2": 3, "3": 15, "4": 15, "5": 0}`. The `15` would be like a default value I pull from another column.

Another acceptable output would be an array with the values `'{0, 3, 15, 15, 0}'`.

Sounds too complex for pure SQL? If not possible, help with a PL/pgSQL would also be appreciated.

Comment: Does that input array just tell us the desired length of the output array, so all we actually need to know is: *5*. Or does it provide a list of indexes that can differ from a plain count?

Comment: It's a fixed input, always 1..5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Return `jsonb` object

If there are never additional keys in the JSON object, it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT jsonb '{"1": 15, "2": 15, "3": 15, "4": 15, "5": 15}' || (json->'key')
FROM   tbl;
```

Parentheses are required to overrule operator precedence!

This does not remove additional keys from the JSON object.
Returns `NULL` if the JSON object is not found.
See example in the fiddle.

Consider notes for [`jsonb` concatenation in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE):

> `jsonb || jsonb → jsonb`
>
> Concatenates two `jsonb` values. Concatenating two arrays generates an
> array containing all the elements of each input. Concatenating two
> objects generates an object containing the union of their keys, taking
> the second object's value when there are duplicate keys. All other
> cases are treated by converting a non-array input into a
> single-element array, and then proceeding as for two arrays. Does not
> operate recursively: only the top-level array or object structure is merged.

#### Return `int[]`

Expanded the JSON object to a set with `jsonb_each_text()`, `RIGHT JOIN` to the full set (generated with `generate_series()` in a CTE), and aggregate with ARRAY constructor (fastest):

```
WITH a(key) AS (SELECT generate_series(1, 5)::text)
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT COALESCE(value::int, 15)
              FROM   jsonb_each_text(t.json->'key') RIGHT JOIN a USING (key)
              ORDER  BY key) AS int_arr
FROM   tbl t;
```

This trims any additional keys from the JSON object.
Returns an array of default values if the JSON object is not found.
See example in the fiddle.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8b64785a35c02cd334e21ac74179e0ad)*

Related:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Answer (score 0):

It's amazing how posting a question helps the brain find solutions. Just occurred to me I don't need to get fancy:

```sql
SELECT
  ARRAY[
    COALESCE((json->'key'->'1')::text, other_col::text, '0')::int,
    COALESCE((json->'key'->'2')::text, other_col::text, '0')::int,
    COALESCE((json->'key'->'3')::text, other_col::text, '0')::int,
    COALESCE((json->'key'->'4')::text, other_col::text, '0')::int,
    COALESCE((json->'key'->'5')::text, other_col::text, '0')::int
  ]
...
```