# How to remove only adjacent duplicates in an array?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, duplication, gaps-and-islands, postgresql-14

While aggregating an array, I need to remove empty strings and then combine all adjacent identical values. E.g.:

```
["","product","product","","product","","product","product","","product","product","","product","","","collection","product","","","product","product","","collection","order","checkout",""]
```

Should become:

```
["product","collection","product","collection","order","checkout"]
```

I have a working query with 4 nested selects:

```
SELECT array_agg( page_type_unique_pre) FILTER (WHERE page_type_unique_pre != '')
                                        OVER   (ORDER BY event_time) AS page_type_journey_unique

FROM  (
   SELECT CASE WHEN lag(last_page_type) OVER (ORDER BY event_time) LIKE '%' || page_type || '%' THEN ''
               ELSE page_type END AS page_type_unique_pre
        , page_type
        , event_time
   FROM  (
      SELECT string_agg(page_type, ',') OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS page_type_journey
           , first_value(page_type) OVER (PARTITION BY last_page_type_partition ORDER BY event_time) AS last_page_type
           , page_type
           , event_time
      FROM  (
         SELECT
         sum(CASE WHEN page_type IS NULL OR page_type = ''  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS last_page_type_partition,
         page_type,
         event_time
         FROM (
            SELECT * FROM tes
            ) a
         ) b
      ) c
   ) d;
```

See test case in this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/5666).

I'm sure there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Your fiddle starts without arrays. Do you *have* to use arrays, or can you use normal aggregation of your rows?

Comment: I can use without arrays. but I would like to check if it's correct, by seeing the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single subquery should do:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT page_type
   FROM  (
      SELECT event_time, page_type
           , lag(page_type, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY event_time) AS last_page_type
      FROM   tes
      WHERE  page_type <> ''
      ) sub
   WHERE  page_type <> last_page_type
   ORDER  BY event_time
   )
 AS page_type_journey_unique;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xJOoKPNS)

Eliminate null and empty string with `WHERE page_type <> ''` right away. See:

- [Best way to check for "empty or null value"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/939860)

Then get the previous `page_type` with the window function [`lag()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html), placing `''` as default. This way `last_page_type` can never be `null` (and the empty string `''` does not collide with an existing value, after having just been eliminated). See:

- [Find all rows in between a set in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314630/939860)

Hence, we can use a plain `<>` (not the more expensive `IS DISTINCT FROM`) in the outer `SELECT` to identify rows with a new page type.

Feed the resulting set to an ARRAY constructor. Simplest and cheapest. See:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Comment: Thank you! You are a life-saver!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it seems you can just use a `LAG` window function, combined with array aggregation.

If you want to see both before and after combining duplicates, you can use the `ARRAY_AGG` aggregate with and without a `FILTER`

```
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(tes.page_type ORDER BY tes.event_time)
      FILTER (WHERE tes.page_type <> tes.last_page_type) AS consecutives_combined,
  ARRAY_AGG(tes.page_type ORDER BY tes.event_time) AS all_values
FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      LAG(page_type, 1, '') OVER (ORDER BY tes.event_time) AS last_page_type
    FROM tes
    WHERE tes.page_type <> ''
) tes;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/ubNqv8Va)