# How to update each value in an array with a function?

Tags: postgresql, update, array

I want to trim spaces from each value in a `text[]`.

If this was just a `text` column I could do:

```
update server set tags = rtrim(ltrim(tags));
```

However how do I do this for an array? As otherwise that same query gives an error of:

```
ERROR:  function rtrim(text[]) does not exist
LINE 1: update server set tags = ltrim(rtrim(tags));
                                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I have found the`array_replace` function however that requires a specific index to replace. I guess I could figure out some kind of iteration for each array value and use this function.

Comment: Sounds like you should be normalizing your `tags` into a separate table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you found is the [ARRAY constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) - an SQL construct, not a function, strictly speaking. It's the right tool in combination with the set-returning function [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).
Two noteworthy optimizations, though:

```
UPDATE server
SET    tags = ARRAY(SELECT trim(unnest(tags)))
WHERE  tags IS DISTINCT FROM ARRAY(SELECT trim(unnest(tags)));
```

Most importantly, the added `WHERE` clause filters rows that wouldn't change. Updating those would achieve nothing, at full cost. See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

And just use [`trim()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) instead of `rtrim(ltrim(...))`.

Related:

- [Apply `trim()` and `regexp_replace()` on text array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238603/939860)
- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Answer (score 0):

By chance I found the `array` function though I don't know exactly what it does or where it's documented (it does not seem to be listed here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html).

```
update server
set tags = array(select rtrim(ltrim(unnest(tags))));
```

The `unset` function is used to expand an array to a set of rows. Which we then use `array` to turn back into an array afterwards.