# Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-performance

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE primary_key = ?
```

vs.

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE primary_key = ? AND other_key = ?
```

Say that this is a scenario where the inclusion of `other_key` does NOT change the resultset. Is the second query faster in practice? Or do databases just use a single best key if several are provided?

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Query

```
SELECT something FROM table WHERE primary_key = ?
```

This the fastest possible form. Adding *any* other predicate can only make it slower. Theoretically.

Exotic **exceptions** apply, like when the PK index is bloated for some reason, or the PK column is relatively big, or a multi-column PK, resulting in a much larger index, while the index for the added predicate on `other_key` is smaller. Then Postgres may decide to use the index for the added predicate, access the heap and *filter* on `primary_key = ?`. Unlikely, but possible.

If the added predicate evaluates to anything but `TRUE`, you get no row - a different result, so not a fair comparison - but that's not your case as you asserted.

A `FOREIGN KEY` constraint has no direct impact on read performance. The referencing column does not even have to be indexed (as opposed to the referenced column).

#### Covering index for top read performance

With tables of non-trivial size and not too much write activity, consider adding a **multicolumn index** on `(primary_key, something)` to allow **index-only scans**. In **Postgres 10 or older** that results in at least two indexes (imposing additional write / maintenance / space costs):

1. the PK index on `(primary_key)`, obviously.
2. a plain (or, redundantly, `UNIQUE`) index on `(primary_key, something)`.

**Postgres 11** added true [**covering indexes**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) using the [**`INCLUDE`** clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html), which conveniently allows to piggyback the non-key column `something` on the `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   primary_key bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
 , other_key   integer NOT NULL REFERENCES other_tbl
 , something   text
 , PRIMARY KEY (primary_key) INCLUDE (something)  -- here's the magic
);
```

If `primary_key` happens to be a much wider column than `other_key` you mentioned (`bigint` vs. `int` like in the example would not qualify), you can also piggyback `something` onto an index on `other_key`:

```
CREATE INDEX other_idx ON tbl(other_key) INCLUDE (something);
```

While either solution can optimize read performance for the given query, other queries not retrieving `something` then have to work with a bigger index. So weigh benefits and costs (like always when creating indexes).

- [The manual on `CREATE INDEX`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html)

Related blog entry with details from Michael Paquier:

- [Postgres 11 highlight - Covering Indexes](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-11-covering-indexes/)

Answer (score 4):

First, keys are a logical concept that per se has little to do with performance. However, unique constraints (primary keys) is in every DBMS:s I know of, implemented with a UNIQUE indexes so it indirectly affects performance. Some DBMS (not sure about PostgreSQL) automatically creates an index for FOREIGN KEYS. Once again the FOREIGN KEY itself has a very small impact on a SELECT statement (it will affect insert/update/delete since it has to be verified). So FOREIGN key's may indirectly affect performance of a SELECT.

In your case, the foreign key index will normally[1] not affect performance. The row is already uniquely identified by the primary key, which is the best we can hope for.

[1] normally because if the statistics for the primary key index is inconsistent with reality a table scan may be chosen. Having a second index for the foreign key can help in this situation, but this is not something that you should take into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

No, because primary keys are unique, so a PK lookup will find a single record. So only the primary key will be used to find the record.  you should see the same access plan for both queries.

using two indexes is sub-optimal in most cases. but when the best index finds several records a bitmap scan can be done using a second index.