# How to get the oldest values over each id in a PostgreSQL table efficiently?

Tags: postgresql, performance, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-11, query-performance

How can PostgreSQL return a list of the oldest timestamp values over a table of sensor id measurements?

Let me explain the situation with a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data(
sensor_id INTEGER,
time TIMESTAMPTZ,
value NUMERIC,
PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, time)
)
```

Populated table example:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------+
| sensor_id |       time       | value |
+-----------+------------------+-------+
|         1 | 2018-01-01 00:00 |     1 |
|         1 | 2018-01-01 01:00 |     2 |
|         3 | 2018-01-01 03:00 |     4 |
|         3 | 2018-01-01 04:00 |     3 |
|         4 | 2018-01-01 03:00 |     5 |
|         4 | 2018-01-01 04:00 |     6 |
+-----------+------------------+-------+
```

While using something like sensor_id (1,3) inside the query I want it to return something like this:

```
+-----------+------------------+-------+
| sensor_id |       time       | value |
+-----------+------------------+-------+
|         1 | 2018-01-01 01:00 |     2 |
|         3 | 2018-01-01 04:00 |     3 |
+-----------+------------------+-------+
```

How can I do that in a query using the `PRIMARY KEY` index for speeding it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible query styles, most will readily use your PK index on `(sensor_id, time)` as it fits the task. (Postgres can read indexes backwards practically as fast.) This should be near perfect:

```
SELECT s.sensor_id, sd.time, sd.value
FROM   unnest ('{1,3}'::int[]) s(sensor_id)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   sensor_data sd
   WHERE  sd.sensor_id = s.sensor_id
   ORDER  BY time DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) sd ON true;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=02832c75da7b0a15a207bb067a65bf62)*

`LEFT JOIN .. ON true` keeps sensors without any data entries in the result - with NULL values in place of values.

Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)
- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Since you are on Postgres 11, a covering index *might* pay:

```
... PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id, time) INCLUDE (value)
```

**But** it makes the index bigger and writes to the table more expensive, and your names indicate a write-heavy table. And while you only query for few rows at a time, queries don't get much faster anyway. So probably best the way you have it. Related:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)

Answer (score 0):

Just for educational purposes, here is another way of solving it:

```
(
    SELECT sensor_id, time, value
    FROM sensor_data
    WHERE sensor_id = 1
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT sensor_id, time, value
    FROM sensor_data
    WHERE sensor_id = 3
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

The drawbacks of this query is the need of generating queries dinamically.

[Erwin's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251311/32828) is far more appropriate in this sense.