# Very slow query despite index being used

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

I have this table, created to hold tons of modbus measurements that comes from my devices:

```
CREATE TABLE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus (
    measurement_id serial NOT NULL,
    insert_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    data jsonb NOT NULL,
    smart_device_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_pkey PRIMARY KEY (measurement_id),
    CONSTRAINT tv_smartdevicemeasur_smart_device_id_62c12ed0_fk_tv_smartd
        FOREIGN KEY (smart_device_id)
        REFERENCES public.tv_smartdevice_modbus (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);

CREATE INDEX idxgin
    ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus USING gin (data);

CREATE INDEX tv_smartdev_insert__0ae03a_idx
    ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus USING btree (insert_time);

CREATE INDEX tv_smartdev_insert__1f0611_idx
    ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus USING btree (insert_time DESC);

CREATE INDEX tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_smart_device_id_62c12ed0
    ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus USING btree (smart_device_id);
```

Now, the table has something like 200 million rows (and it's growing every day). I need to select with a simple datetime clause like this one:

```
SELECT data
FROM tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus
WHERE (tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus.insert_time > '2019-08-01'
AND tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus.insert_time < '2019-9-25')
```

But this *simple and without hassle* query takes up 8 seconds, as [reported here with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE`](https://explain.depesz.com/s/bNlU).

The same [with the `track_io_timing` enabled.](https://explain.depesz.com/s/bGCJ)

How to resolve this problem? Is there an effective long term solution?

Comment: Turn track_io_timing on, then do EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

Comment: Hi, here is the explain report of the query with the track_io_timing enabled: https://explain.depesz.com/s/bGCJ

Comment: Your query retrieves > 1 million rows. Are you going to read all of those or what's the plan? Your version of Postgres? Avg size of `data`? How are new rows written to the table? Once per day? Can you afford to rewrite the table / lock it exclusively for some time?

Comment: Ok, there are some additional infos about my schema: 
- The average size of the jsonb column is 900/1000 bytes.
- My version of postgres is 11
- The rows are written with a simple insert from django ORM
- The inserted rows are like 1300/1500 per minute, so like 25 per seconds in different transactions
- Retrieve > 1M rows is not a good idea, i know, but sometimes (especially in grafana) the user has to do that

Comment: In addition, in my production environment, without any optimization (only one index over the insert_time column), i have the "98.31%" of cache hits: any recommendations?

Comment: With close to 1 kb, the "payload" in `data` is comparatively big. Helps to explain index scan instead of bitmap index scan. Limits the benefits of my suggested rewrite somewhat. (But still good as you verified yourself.) `data` will be typically be "toasted" (stored out of line) and/or compressed. Try to write new data in order of `insert_time ` as much as possible to keep rows physically clustered.

Comment: So, what is the main difference between a 'CLUSTER' and ordered insert?

Answer (score 2):

There are two indices on `(insert_time)` and `(insert_time DESC)`. B-tree indices can be scanned backwards at practically the same speed. And `insert_time` is `NOT NULL`, so there is no point whatsoever. Drop one of those ***in any case***.

I made some assumptions where info is missing:

- Current Postgres 12.
- You are free to redesign the table and lock the table exclusively for some time.
- The table is basically "append only".
- New rows are added in order of `insert_time`.
- The current table is physically out of order and/or bloated (leading to the index scan in your query plan instead of bitmap index scan)

I would rewrite the table like this:

```
BEGIN;
-- SET maintenance_work_mem = ???   -- set as high as you can afford temporarily

-- drop idx first to free space
DROP INDEX public.idxgin;     -- acquires exclusive lock on the table
DROP INDEX public.tv_smartdev_insert__0ae03a_idx;
DROP INDEX public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_smart_device_id_62c12ed0;
-- DROP INDEX public.tv_smartdev_insert__1f0611_idx; -- might help SELECT, drop later

ALTER TABLE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus ALTER measurement_id DROP DEFAULT;
DROP SEQUENCE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_measurement_id_seq;  -- drop owned sequence
ALTER TABLE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus
         RENAME TO tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_old;    -- free org. name

CREATE TABLE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus (
   measurement_id   serial PRIMARY KEY    -- consider IDENTITY column instead, see below
 , smart_device_id  integer NOT NULL      -- reordering saves 4-8 bytes alignment padding per row
 , insert_time      timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
 , data             jsonb NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT tv_smartdevicemeasur_smart_device_id_62c12ed0_fk_tv_smartd
      FOREIGN KEY (smart_device_id)
      REFERENCES public.tv_smartdevice_modbus (device_id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED  -- WHY deferrable / deferred? see below
);

INSERT INTO public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus
      (measurement_id, smart_device_id, insert_time, data)
SELECT measurement_id, smart_device_id, insert_time, data
FROM   public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_old
ORDER  BY insert_time DESC;   -- CLUSTER while rewriting

DROP TABLE tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_old;

CREATE INDEX tv_smartdev_insert__1f0611_idx ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus (insert_time DESC);
-- CREATE INDEX tv_smartdev_insert__0ae03a_idx ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus (insert_time);  -- nope!

CREATE INDEX idxgin ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus USING gin (data);  -- ?
CREATE INDEX tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_smart_device_id_62c12ed0 ON public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus (smart_device_id); -- ?

COMMIT;

VACUUM ANALYZE public.tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus;
```

This rewrites the table saving some space (which also helps performance). Most importantly, it clusters the table according to your main index - and removes all possible bloat while being at it. This should help locality of data and make Postgres read fewer data pages. Unless your `data` column is *big*, you should see bitmap index scan in the query plan now. And if `data` is *small*, consider a covering index  to get index-only scans. See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938#207938)

How does the changed column order save space?

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

`DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`? This is rarely necessary. And cheaper without. See:

- [SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28681238/939860)

`serial` vs. `IDENTITY`? See:

- [How to change a table ID from serial to identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59233169/939860)

Then query like this:

```
SELECT data
FROM   tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus
WHERE  insert_time >= '2019-08-01'  -- included
AND    insert_time <  '2019-09-25'; -- excluded
```

Be aware that these date literals are interpreted according to your local time zone setting. Consider true `timestamptz` input to be unambiguous. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

These two indices are orthogonal to the query at hand: `idxgin` and `tv_smartdevicemeasurement_modbus_smart_device_id_62c12ed0`. Drop unless needed for unrelated stuff.

Comment: Wow, impressive! i'll test and keep you posted about that

Comment: At this moment i've tested that and i'm able to get better performances (Explain here: https://explain.depesz.com/s/lL7E), but assuming that this table it's managed by Django ORM, what are the best approach to delivery those optimization to production? i mean: i've dropped the indexes, but it's not feasible to rewrite the table in order to cluster it, so what approach i need to follow?

Comment: I am no Django expert, but it shouldn't be too hard. Either way, before coming back with more questions, please address open questions for you first.