# Create cyclic pointers in postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

The problem is to write the "ADD-VALUE" request defined below.

For each "**cat**" value from the table below, keep only 3 records. Figure this table:

| id | cat | value | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | v1 | 06/01/2021 00:00:01 |
| 2 | cat1 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:00:02 |
| 3 | cat1 | v3 | 06/01/2021 00:00:03 *(pointer cat1 is here)* |
| 4 | cat2 | v1 | 06/01/2021 00:01:01 |
| 5 | cat2 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:01:02 *(pointer cat2 is here)* |

**INSERT case**: Calling "ADD-VALUE(cat=**cat2**, value=v3)" will produce the result in bold:

| id | cat | value | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | v1 | 06/01/2021 00:00:01 |
| 2 | cat1 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:00:02 |
| 3 | cat1 | v3 | 06/01/2021 00:00:03 *(pointer cat1 is here)* |
| 4 | cat2 | v1 | 06/01/2021 00:01:01 |
| 5 | cat2 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:01:02 |
| **6** | **cat2** | **v3** | **06/01/2021 00:01:02 *(pointer cat2 is now here)*** |

**UPDATE case**: Calling "ADD-VALUE(cat=**cat1**, value=v4)" will produce the result in bold:

| id | cat | value | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | cat1 | **v4** | **07/01/2021 00:00:04 *(pointer cat1 is now here)*** |
| 2 | cat1 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:00:02 |
| 3 | cat1 | v3 | 06/01/2021 00:00:03 |
| 4 | cat2 | v1 | 06/01/2021 00:01:01 |
| 5 | cat2 | v2 | 06/01/2021 00:01:02 *(pointer cat2 is here)* |

Any advice is welcome. UPDATE or INSERT in one request is maybe impossible? I think about using row-num to have the count per category.

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using? Please tag your question. Are you aware of the `insert ... on conflict do update` syntax? Though having 3 records rather than 1 makes this a bit trickier.

Comment: I really don't know to take the problem, any advice is appreciated

Comment: Create stored procedure with needed logic and CALL it instead of single INSERT. Or call it in a trigger.

Comment: Thank you Akina, I would like to explore the possibility of one request. Are you sure this is impossible or not encouraged, why do you suggest to avoid a request? Thanks

Comment: [Postgres 9.5 is reaching EOL as we speak.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) Can you upgrade to a current version? Also, please show your actual table definitions: `CREATE TABLE` statement with actual data types and constraints. (Even if it's just a work in progress so far.) And explain your requirements some more. Can there be `DELETE` or `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea would be a pain to enforce under concurrent load. Instead, just keep adding new rows (`INSERT` only). There are simple and fast queries to get the current row(s) for each cat.

Make sure, that `updated_at` is current. I added a column default and a trigger for that.
To rule out duplicate entries for the same cat and the same timestamp, add a UNIQUE constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE cat(
  id         serial PRIMARY KEY
, cat        text NOT NULL
, value      text
, updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
, CONSTRAINT uni_cat_updated_at UNIQUE (cat, updated_at)
);

-- trigger func & trigger
CREATE FUNCTION public.trg_cat_updated()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.updated_at = now();
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

CREATE TRIGGER cat_befupd
BEFORE UPDATE ON public.cat
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.trg_cat_updated();
```

Or, to be absolutely sure, make that:

```
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.cat
```

The default value normally takes care of inserts cheaply, but it can be overruled with explicitly inserting a value. The trigger overrules no matter what.

To get the "current" row for a given cat:

```
SELECT value
FROM   cat
WHERE  cat = 'cat1'
ORDER  BY updated_at DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

This is extremely fast while you have a matching **index**:

```
CREATE INDEX on cat (cat, updated_at DESC, value);
```

In modern Postgres versions you could use a unique covering index to replace index *and* `UNIQUE` constraint. See:

- [Does a query with a primary key and foreign keys run faster than a query with just primary keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207927/does-a-query-with-a-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-run-faster-than-a-query-with-ju/207938)?

To get the last three (live) rows, use the same query with `LIMIT 3`:

From time to time (as your db load and schedule permit/require) delete deprecated rows:

```
DELETE FROM cat c
USING (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cat ORDER BY updated_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM cat
   ) d
WHERE  d.rn > 3
AND    c.id = d.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2983373efc6b1684fec924ef40b5b4c9)*

Comment: Thank you erwin. I was looking for a query in my app that will avoid me to create scheduled job. But I will follow your advice, thank.