# Advantage of using INCLUDE as against adding the column in INDEX for covering index

Tags: postgresql, index, covering-index

Postgres docs state the following about [*Index-Only Scans and Covering-Indexes*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html):

> if you commonly run queries like
>
> `SELECT y FROM tab WHERE x = 'key';`
>
> the traditional approach to speeding up such queries would be to
> create an index on x only. However, an index defined as
>
> `CREATE INDEX tab_x_y ON tab(x) INCLUDE (y);`
>
> could handle these queries as index-only scans, because y can be
> obtained from the index without visiting the heap.
>
> Because column y is not part of the index's search key, it does not
> have to be of a data type that the index can handle; it's merely
> stored in the index and is not interpreted by the index machinery.
> Also, if the index is a unique index, that is
>
> `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tab_x_y ON tab(x) INCLUDE (y);`
>
> the uniqueness condition applies to just column x, not to the
> combination of x and y. (An INCLUDE clause can also be written in
> UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints, providing alternative syntax for
> setting up an index like this.)

**Question 1:** If the data type of `y` can be added in index and there is no uniqueness requirement then  is there any advantage of using `CREATE INDEX tab_x_y ON tab(x) INCLUDE (y)` over `CREATE INDEX tab_x_y ON tab(x, y)` for queries like `SELECT y FROM tab WHERE x = 'key';`?

> It's wise to be conservative about adding non-key payload columns to
> an index, especially wide columns. If an index tuple exceeds the
> maximum size allowed for the index type, data insertion will fail. In
> any case, non-key columns duplicate data from the index's table and
> bloat the size of the index, thus potentially slowing searches.

**Question 2:** Can someone explain with an example what `wide columns` mean?

**Question 3:** Can someone explain the below statement in context of `INCLUDE(y)`. If `INCLUDE` supports index only scans then `y` will also have to be stored in index. Then how does the below statement not hold for `INCLUDE(y)`.

> In any case, non-key columns duplicate data from the index's table and
> bloat the size of the index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule of thumb 1: If you never use an index column for filtering or sorting (or joining, or to enforce uniqueness), you might as well move it to the `INCLUDE` clause. Nothing lost, something gained.

Rule of thumb 2: `INCLUDE` columns only ever make sense if you actually get index-only scans from them. And in some cases not even then.

**Answer 1:** The `INCLUDE` feature is predominantly useful for the two excluded cases: uniqueness, or not allowed in the index otherwise. But there are still minor benefits for other cases. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) explains further down:

> *Suffix* truncation always removes non-key columns from upper B-Tree levels. As payload columns, they are never used to guide index scans.
> The truncation process also removes one or more trailing key column(s)
> when the remaining prefix of key column(s) happens to be sufficient to
> describe tuples on the lowest B-Tree level. In practice, covering
> indexes without an `INCLUDE` clause often avoid storing columns that
> are effectively payload in the upper levels. However, explicitly
> defining payload columns as non-key columns reliably keeps the tuples
> in upper levels small.

Now, B-tree indexes are only few levels deep. But the upper levels are the ones that have to be read *all the time*. Keeping those small helps the most. Even a small effect is enhanced by that. The benefit is biggest for large cardinalities (multiple index levels), and little duplication (suffix truncation can't make up for *not* moving a payload column to the `INCLUDE` part).

Plus, there is a case with **expression indexes**. Postgres is currently (Postgres 15) not smart enough to chose an index-only scan unless the involved column itself is included in the index. [The manual again:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

> If an index-only scan seems sufficiently worthwhile, this can be
> worked around by adding `x` as an included column, for example
>
> `CREATE INDEX tab_f_x ON tab (f(x)) INCLUDE (x);`

(Unless plain `x` is also involved in the query,) `INCLUDE (x)` only serves as awkward hint for the query planner, while only `f(x)` is actually used.

**Answer 2:** "Wide" columns are big columns, columns that occupy a lot of storage "on disk" (often not a "disk" nowadays) or in RAM. On-disk storage governs how many data pages have to be visited to satisfy a query, which is commonly the most important factor for performance. What counts is the internal representation, not the text representation you *see*. Test with [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) - but be aware that the size of data in "packed" format ("on disk") can be more compact than in RAM. And there are various overheads. See:

- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)
- [Why *not* ERROR: index row size xxxx exceeds maximum 2712 for index "foo"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217087/why-not-error-index-row-size-xxxx-exceeds-maximum-2712-for-index-foo/217088#217088)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

**Answer 3:** Write costs and bloated size applies for `INCLUDE(y)` as well as for regular index columns. The question is whether to *add* `INCLUDE` columns at all, which are always logically optional. (Regular index columns are often not optional.) Also, see *answer 1*.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Erwin's great answer, there is an additional advantage to using the `INCLUDE` syntax: documentation.

Imagine that you decide that you need an index on columns `(a, b)` of table `tab`. Now you find that there is already an index on `(a, c)`. In this situation you have two options:

- simply go ahead and create another index
- if you know for sure that column `c` was only added to the index to support an index-only scan **and is never used as a search condition**, you can drop the old index and create a new one on `(a, b, c)`, thus saving an index

Now it is usually difficult to determine that an index column is never used as a search condition, unless – well, unless it appears in the `INCLUDE` clause. In that case, you don't have to think twice and can replace the index on `(a) INCLUDE (c)` with one on `(a, b) INCLUDE (c)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference between covering and including isn't when selecting, it is when inserting and updating. The INCLUDEd columns do not have to be kept in a stable order so if you update those columns (without changing their size if variable, or updating the others covered by the index) things do not need to be reordered. This can reduce page splits or other extra writes, making the operation more efficient and reducing internal fragmentation.
2. I assume wide columns means strings of any significant size or variable size. Other column types are generally smaller and of fixed size.
3. Just what it says: the value is copied into the index so the index is larger, and if there is an index scan or partial scan more pages will probably need to be accessed.

Note: I'm an MS SQL Server person mainly, there may the postgres specific edges around this.

Comment: Since Postgres writes a new index tuple either way when any involved column is changed, and suffix truncation typically cancels most additional sort cost, the effect of point 1 is small. H.O.T. updates are prevented either way - see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/96241/3684