# Is there a possible reason for having index on (a) and on (a,b) at the same time

Tags: postgresql, index

Suppose I have a table with several column, among them - columns a and b.

Is there any use case for which having both multi-column index on (a,b) and a single-column index on (a) is beneficial?

AFAIU for simple equality check using first column of multi-column index is equally good as using the single-column index.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field - closely related question

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate..

Comment: I think it's a textbook duplicate.

Comment: Can you please point me to the book?

Comment: @Ivan: There is no actual book involved. ["textbook" is an adjective here meaning "exemplary".](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/textbook%5Badjective%5D)

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The index on `(a)` is not necessary if there is another one on `(a,b)`.

The only situation where this *might* (!) be helpful is, if a lot of index only scans are done on the indexes (something like `select count(*) from foo where a = 42`) and `b` is e.g. a large text column.

The index on `(a)` will obviously be a lot smaller, so an index only scan on that index will be faster (whether or not that "faster" is actually measurable depends on the data in the column `b`)

But I would consider this is an edge case with a very specific workload.

Comment: The smaller indexes might be useful when your queries often use index merges, but thats only another edge case.

Comment: How large should be the second column? I tried 332 length varchars (9 concatenated UUIDs separated with '-') but have not seen any difference.

Comment: @IvanSopov if entire index is already loaded in the memory then it probably does not matter much.