# PostgreSQL Recursive Descendant Depth

Tags: postgresql, update, cte, recursive

I need to calculate the depth of a descendant from it's ancestor.  When a record has `object_id = parent_id = ancestor_id`, it is considered a root node (the ancestor). I have been trying to get a `WITH RECURSIVE` query running with PostgreSQL **9.4**.

I do not control the data or the columns. The data and table schema comes from an external source. The table is **growing continuously**. Right now by about 30k records per day. **Any node in the tree can be missing** and they will be pulled from an external source at some point. They are usually pulled in `created_at DESC` order but the data is pulled with asynchronous background jobs.

We initially had a code solution to this problem, but now having 5M+ rows, it takes almost 30 minutes to complete.

Example table definition and test data:

```
CREATE TABLE objects (
  id          serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_id integer NOT NULL,
  object_id   integer NOT NULL,
  parent_id   integer,
  ancestor_id integer,
  generation  integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO objects(id, customer_id , object_id, parent_id, ancestor_id, generation)
VALUES (2, 1, 2, 1, 1, -1), --no parent yet
       (3, 2, 3, 3, 3, -1), --root node
       (4, 2, 4, 3, 3, -1), --depth 1
       (5, 2, 5, 4, 3, -1), --depth 2
       (6, 2, 6, 5, 3, -1), --depth 3
       (7, 1, 7, 7, 7, -1), --root node
       (8, 1, 8, 7, 7, -1), --depth 1
       (9, 1, 9, 8, 7, -1); --depth 2
```

Note that `object_id` is not unique, but the combination `(customer_id, object_id)` is unique.
Running a query like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants(id, customer_id, object_id, parent_id, ancestor_id, depth) AS (
  SELECT id, customer_id, object_id, parent_id, ancestor_id, 0
  FROM objects
  WHERE object_id = parent_id

  UNION

  SELECT o.id, o.customer_id, o.object_id, o.parent_id, o.ancestor_id, d.depth + 1
  FROM objects o
  INNER JOIN descendants d ON d.parent_id = o.object_id
  WHERE
    d.id <> o.id
  AND
    d.customer_id = o.customer_id
) SELECT * FROM descendants d;
```

I would like the `generation` column to be set as the depth that was calculated.  When a new record is added, the generation column is set as -1. There are some cases where a `parent_id` may not have been pulled yet.  If the `parent_id` does not exist, it should leave the generation column set to -1.

The final data should look like:

```
id | customer_id | object_id | parent_id | ancestor_id | generation
2    1             2           1           1            -1
3    2             3           3           3             0
4    2             4           3           3             1
5    2             5           4           3             2
6    2             6           5           3             3
7    1             7           7           7             0
8    1             8           7           7             1
9    1             9           8           7             2
```

The result of the query should be to update the generation column to the correct depth.

I started working from the [answers to this related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957917/how-does-one-print-depth-level-in-a-postgres-query-that-uses-recursive-to-select).

Comment: So you want to `update` the table with the result of your recursive CTE?

Comment: Yes, I would like the generation column to be UPDATE'd to what it's depth is.  If there is no parent (objects.parent_id doesn't match any objects.object_id) the generation would remain as -1.

Comment: So the `ancestor_id` is already set, so you only need to assign the generation from the CTE.depth ?

Comment: Yes, object_id, parent_id, and ancestor_id are already set from the data we get from the API.  I'd like to set the generation column to whatever the depth is.  One other note, the object_id is not unique, as customer_id 1 could have object_id 1, and customer_id 2 could have object_id 1.  The primary id on the table is unique.

Comment: Is this a one-time update or are you continuously adding to a growing table? Seems like the latter case. Makes a *big* difference. And can only root nodes be missing (yet) or any node in the tree?

Comment: This is a continuously growing table.  Right now it is growing about 30k records per day.  Any node in the tree can be missing and they will be pulled from an external source at some point.  They are usually pulled in created_at DESC order but the data is pulled with asynchronous background jobs.

Comment: I took the liberty to add this information to the question. All important info should be there. It's hard for a reader to collect it from comments all over the place.

Comment: ok, thank you.  As I implement the suggestions made, I'll update the question as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The query you have is basically correct. The only mistake is in the second (recursive) part of the CTE where you have:

```
INNER JOIN descendants d ON d.parent_id = o.object_id
```

It should be the other way around:

```
INNER JOIN descendants d ON d.object_id = o.parent_id
```

You want to join the objects with their parents (that have already been found).

So the query that calculates depth can be written (nothing else changed, only formatting):

```
-- calculate generation / depth, no updates
WITH RECURSIVE descendants
  (id, customer_id, object_id, parent_id, ancestor_id, depth) AS
 AS ( SELECT id, customer_id, object_id, parent_id, ancestor_id, 0
      FROM objects
      WHERE object_id = parent_id

      UNION ALL

      SELECT o.id, o.customer_id, o.object_id, o.parent_id, o.ancestor_id, d.depth + 1
      FROM objects o
      INNER JOIN descendants d ON  d.customer_id = o.customer_id
                               AND d.object_id = o.parent_id  
      WHERE d.id <> o.id
    ) 
SELECT * 
FROM descendants d
ORDER BY id ;
```

For the update, you simply replace the last `SELECT`, with the `UPDATE`, joining the result of the cte, back to the table:

```
-- update nodes
WITH RECURSIVE descendants
    -- nothing changes here except
    -- ancestor_id and parent_id 
    -- which can be omitted form the select lists
    ) 
UPDATE objects o 
SET generation = d.depth 
FROM descendants d
WHERE o.id = d.id 
  AND o.generation = -1 ;          -- skip unnecessary updates
```

Tested on **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/59593/10)**

Additional comments:

- the `ancestor_id` and the `parent_id` are not needed to be in the select list (ancestor is obvious, parent a bit tricky to figure out why), so you can keep them in the `SELECT` query if you want but you can safely remove them from the `UPDATE`.
- the `(customer_id, object_id)` seems like a candidate for a `UNIQUE` constraint. If your data comply with this, add such a constraint. The joins performed in the recursive CTE would not make sense if it wasn't unique (a node could have 2 parents otherwise).
- if you add that constraint, the `(customer_id, parent_id)` would be a candidate for a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint that `REFERENCES` the (unique) `(customer_id, object_id)`. You most probably do **not** want to add that FK constraint though, since by your description, you are adding new rows and some rows can reference others that haven't been yet added.
- There are certainly problems with the efficiency of the query, if it's going to be performed in a big table. Not in the first run, as almost the whole table will be updated anyway. But the second time, you'll want only new rows (and those that were not touched by the 1st run) to be considered for update. The CTE as it is will have to build a big result.
  The `AND o.generation = -1` in the final update will make sure that the rows that were updated in the 1st run will not be updated again but the CTE is still an expensive part.

The following is an attempt to address these issues: improve the CTE as to consider as few rows as possible and use `(customer_id, obejct_id)` instead of `(id)` to identify rows (so `id` is completely removed from the query. 
It can be used as the 1st update or a subsequent:

```
WITH RECURSIVE descendants 
  (customer_id, object_id, depth) 
 AS ( SELECT customer_id, object_id, 0
      FROM objects
      WHERE object_id = parent_id
        AND generation = -1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT o.customer_id, o.object_id, p.generation + 1
      FROM objects o
        JOIN objects p ON  p.customer_id = o.customer_id
                       AND p.object_id = o.parent_id
                       AND p.generation > -1
      WHERE o.generation = -1

      UNION ALL

      SELECT o.customer_id, o.object_id, d.depth + 1
      FROM objects o
      INNER JOIN descendants d ON  o.customer_id = d.customer_id
                               AND o.parent_id = d.object_id
      WHERE o.parent_id <> o.object_id
        AND o.generation = -1
    )
UPDATE objects o 
SET generation = d.depth 
FROM descendants d
WHERE o.customer_id = d.customer_id
  AND o.object_id = d.object_id
  AND o.generation = -1        -- this is not really needed
```

Note how the CTE has 3 parts. The first two are the stable parts. The 1st part find the root nodes that haven't been updated before and have still `generation=-1` so they must be newly added nodes. The 2nd part finds children (with `generation=-1`) of parent nodes that have previously been updated.
The 3rd, recursive part, finds all the descendants of the first two parts, as before.

Tested on **[SQLfiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/703b3/4)**

Answer (score 3):

[@ypercube already](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/126182/3684) provides ample explanation, so I'll cut to the chase what I have to add.

> If the `parent_id` does not exist, it should leave the generation column set to -1.

I assume this is supposed to apply recursively, i.e. the rest of the tree *always* has `generation = -1` after any missing node.

If any node in the tree can be missing (yet) we need to find rows with `generation = -1` that ...
... are root nodes
... or have a parent with `generation > -1`.
And traverse the tree from there. Child nodes of this selection must have `generation = -1` as well.

Take the `generation` of the parent incremented by one or fall back to 0 for root nodes:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
   SELECT c.customer_id, c.object_id, COALESCE(p.generation + 1, 0) AS depth
   FROM   objects      c
   LEFT   JOIN objects p ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
                        AND c.parent_id   = p.object_id
                        AND p.generation > -1
   WHERE  c.generation = -1
   AND   (c.parent_id = c.object_id OR p.generation > -1)
       -- root node ... or parent with generation > -1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT customer_id, c.object_id, p.depth + 1
   FROM   objects c
   JOIN   tree    p USING (customer_id)
   WHERE  c.parent_id  = p.object_id
   AND    c.parent_id <> c.object_id  -- exclude root nodes
   AND    c.generation = -1           -- logically redundant, but see below!
   )
UPDATE objects o 
SET    generation = t.depth
FROM   tree t
WHERE  o.customer_id = t.customer_id
AND    o.object_id   = t.object_id;
```

The non-recursive part is a single `SELECT` this way, but logically equivalent to @ypercube's two union'ed `SELECT`. Not sure which is faster, you'll have to test.
The much more important point for performance is:

#### Index!

If you repeatedly add rows to a *big* table this way, add a [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX objects_your_name_idx ON objects (customer_id, parent_id, object_id)
WHERE  generation = -1;
```

This will achieve more for performance than all other improvements discussed so far - for repeated small additions to a big table.

I added the index condition to the recursive part of the CTE (even though logically redundant) to help the query planner understand that the partial index is applicable.

In addition you should probably also have the `UNIQUE` constraint on `(object_id, customer_id)` that @ypercube already mentioned. Or, if you cannot impose uniqueness for some reason (why?) add a plain index instead. The order of index columns matters, btw:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Comment: I will add the indexes and constraints suggested by you and @ypercube.  Looking through the data, I don't see any reason that they couldn't happen (other than the foreign key as sometimes the parent_id is not set yet).  I will also set the generation column be nullable and the default set as NULL instead of -1.  Then I won't have a lot of "-1" filters and the partial indexes can be WHERE generation IS NULL, etc.

Comment: @Diggity: NULL should work just fine if you adapt the rest, yes.

Comment: @Erwin nice. I originally thought similar as you. An index `ON objects (customer_id, parent_id, object_id) WHERE  generation = -1;` and perhaps another `ON objects (customer_id, object_id) WHERE  generation > -1;`. The update will also have to "switch" all updated rows from one index to another, so not sure if this is a good idea for the initial run of the UPDATE.

Comment: Indexing for recursive queries can be really hard.