# Get members of a given group from N:M relationship

Tags: postgresql, join, many-to-many

I have this N:M relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_user (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username character varying(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE auth_group (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name character varying(80) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE auth_user_groups (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id integer REFERENCES auth_user(id) NOT NULL,
    group_id integer REFERENCES auth_group(id) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_groups UNIQUE(user_id, group_id)
);

INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (1, 'user1');
INSERT INTO auth_user VALUES (2, 'user2');
INSERT INTO auth_group VALUES (1, 'group1');
INSERT INTO auth_group VALUES (2, 'group2');
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (2, 2, 1);
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (3, 2, 2);
```

How to select all usernames which are in the group 'group1'?

I use PostgreSQL, but SQL which works everywhere is preferred.

Comment: Be aware that columns included in a `UNIQUE` constraint can still be NULL. You'd typically want `user_id` and `group_id` in `auth_user_groups` to be `NOT NULL` as well.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes, you are right. Thank you. I updated the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This `EXISTS` query returns unique users, regardless of whether there can be duplicate entries in `auth_user_groups`.

```
SELECT *
FROM   auth_user u
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   auth_user_groups
   WHERE  user_id = u.id
   AND    group_id = (SELECT id FROM auth_group WHERE name = 'group1')
   );
```

Typically fast, too.

#### Notes

For Postgres - which you seem to be using.

The sequence of **index** columns matters. You defined `UNIQUE(user_id, group_id)`, which is implemented with a corresponding unique index. For your particular query, an index on `(group_id, user_id)` would be preferable.

You can either switch the columns of the `UNIQUE` constraint, or create an additional (optionally unique) index with the columns reversed if you need both (which is the common case). Related:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Also be aware that columns included in a **`UNIQUE` constraint** can still be **`NULL`**. (Unlike a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint which makes all member columns `NOT NULL` automatically!) You'd typically want `user_id` and `group_id` in `auth_user_groups` to be `NOT NULL` as well. Related:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I updated the question and added not-null to the columns of the n-to-m table

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
select *
from auth_user
where id in (select aug.user_id
             from auth_group ag
               join auth_user_groups aug on aug.group_id = ag.id
             where ag.name = 'group1');
```

Answer (score 2):

A_horse_with_no_name posted a good answer, in fact this was my primary option (deserved an upvote =))

You can also just do it the usual way:

```
select au.*
from dbo.auth_user au
join dbo.auth_user_groups aug on aug.[user_id] = au.id
join dbo.auth_group ag on ag.id = aug.group_id
where ag.[name] = 'group1'
```

But note, if you have more than one group with the same name and users in homonymous groups, you will get duplicate rows:

```
INSERT INTO auth_group VALUES (3, 'group1');
INSERT INTO auth_user_groups VALUES (1, 1, 3);
```

In this case you should use a distinct:

```
select distinct au.*
from dbo.auth_user au
join dbo.auth_user_groups aug on aug.[user_id] = au.id
join dbo.auth_group ag on ag.id = aug.group_id
where ag.[name] = 'group1'
```

Note A_Horse answer still works in this case.

Comment: Jean Another variation of distinct 
`select au.username
from dbo.auth_user au
join dbo.auth_user_groups aug on aug.[user_id] = au.id
join dbo.auth_group ag on ag.id = aug.group_id
where ag.[name] = 'group1'
group by username
having count(*)>0`

Answer (score 2):

From SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL DB you can use the [new graph database capabilities](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2017/04/20/graph-data-processing-with-sql-server-2017/) and the new MATCH clause to answer queries like this, eg

```
SELECT FORMATMESSAGE ( 'User %s (%i) is in group %s.', [user].userName, [user].userId, [group].groupName ) msg
FROM dbo.users [user], dbo.hasGroup hasGroup, dbo.groups [group]
WHERE [group].groupName = 'group1'
  AND MATCH ( [user]-(hasGroup)->[group] );
```

My results:

[image: My results]

Full script available [here](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/9e1daf290b35ff7d3f6bed717117e820).

Comment: Does this work on PostgreSQL?

Comment: No, as mentioned in my post this applies to SQL Server from 2017 onwards and Azure SQL DB.  Please update the tags in your post to indicate your preferred database platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
select username from auth_user, auth_user_groups, auth_group where 
  auth_group.name='group1' and 
  auth_user_groups.group_id=auth_group.id and
  auth_user.id=auth_user_groups.user_id;
```