# Filter table lookup by array value, but returning groupby unfiltered

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, many-to-many, postgresql-13

I have multiple lookup tables and each need to be filtered by an array of values:

```sql
select 
array_agg(joined_properties.name) as properties,
items.name
from items
left join (
  select properties.name, item_property.item_id, item_property.property_id
  from item_property
  join properties on properties.id = item_property.property_id) as joined_properties on joined_properties.item_id = items.id
group by items.name;
```

| properties | name |
| --- | --- |
| property1 | item2 |
| property1,property2,property4 | item1 |
| property2,property3 | item3 |
| property2 | item5 |
| property3,property4 | item4 |

---

I would like to filter each item by an array of properties, but return the unfiltered properties (just like above) in the same query.
What is the **performant/correct way** of doing it without needing to re-run the joins once I found matching rows? Whenever I filter inside the `join` or outside it before grouping it only returns the matching rows of course:

```sql
select 
array_agg(joined_properties.name) as properties,
items.name
from items
inner join (
  select properties.name, item_property.item_id, item_property.property_id
  from item_property
  join properties on properties.id = item_property.property_id
  where properties.name = ANY('{"property1","property2"}')
) as joined_properties on joined_properties.item_id = items.id
group by items.name;
```

| properties | name |
| --- | --- |
| property1,property2 | item1 |
| property1 | item2 |
| property2 | item3 |
| property2 | item5 |

---

Expected output:

| properties | name |
| --- | --- |
| property1 | item2 |
| property1,property2,property4 | item1 |
| property2,property3 | item3 |
| property2 | item5 |

Fiddle below:

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ur2oadEhiJ1H1CRAHJWn1D/2)

**Edit 1:**

- Approximate hardware specs: 4-core Xeon Gold VM, 16GB RAM, SSD
- Relevant DB cardinalities:

  - ~100k records in `items`,
  - 6 `properties_i` text tables with their respective intermediary tables,
  - most `properties_i` tables range from 10-30 records,
  - largest `properties_i` will have 200 records indexed,
  - each item in `items` has 0-10 associated properties for any `property_i`

Comment: You presented your case clearly. However, to optimize performance additional information is needed - as outlined here: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3299/3684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution heavily depends on data distribution and cardinalities - and available indexes.

This query should be generally good:

```
SELECT sub.properties, i.name AS item
FROM  (
   SELECT item_id, array_agg(p.name) AS properties
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT item_id
      FROM   item_property
      WHERE  property_id = ANY (
         SELECT id FROM properties
         WHERE  name = ANY ('{"property1","property2"}')
         )
      ) ip0
   JOIN   item_property ip USING (item_id)
   JOIN   properties    p  ON p.id = ip.property_id
   GROUP  BY item_id
   ) sub
JOIN   items i ON i.id = sub.item_id
ORDER  BY i.name;  -- my optional addition
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2427a47000ff7b9095b7376021e505bc)*

The innermost subquery `ip0` identifies items (or rather: `item_id`'s) that have one of the filtered properties.
The next subquery `sub` joins to all properties and aggregates per item - not involving table `items`, yet!
The outer query replaces `item_id` with actual item name to arrive at your desired result. If item names are not defined `UNIQUE NOT NULL`, I would still return `item_id` additionally to avoid ambiguities.

Other query styles may be faster for particular data distributions / search arguments. Thee are *many* ways. I added one alternative with `IN` to the fiddle.

#### Indexes

For big tables and selective filters, matching indexes make all the difference. For your given data distribution:

- You don't need any indexes on `properties` as it's tiny.
- You'll already have a UNIQUE or PK constraint on `item_property (item_id, property_id)`. Add another index on the same two columns in reversed order, so `(property_id, item_id)` in my example. Why? See:

  - [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

  If `item_property` is vacuumed enough, you'll even see [index-only scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-index-only-scans.html).
- Obviously an index on `items(id)` - that will already be covered by the PK.

Comment: I've added some table info and specs. At this point, I don't know what index(es) I should go for for `items`'s properties, haven't figured that out. `items.name` are `UNIQUE NOT NULL`. I'll try both solutions you linked next week and checkout the query plan, do you think there is any query preference now given the table info?

Comment: @LittleFoxyFox: I elaborated a bit upon the index topic.